# Why am I not allowed to post a comment explaining my downvote?

Tags: discussion

It seems there is a rule preventing me commenting if my comment start with `"-1:"`.

The validation error is something along the lines of `"Comments can't contain that content"` (which by the way is not very helpful when trying to work out which part of the comment I am not allowed to write)

Anyway, why am I being discouraged from explaining my down-vote?

Surely it is helpful for me to explain why I am down-voting, so the OP can improve their question/answer.

For added context, this is the comment I attempt to write:

> -1: OP didn't mention the use of JQuery. You haven't explained that you are using it. You have invalid code: ("#hasil")

Comment: -1: I just added this comment ;) (work on Meta not SO) Voting is anonymous so you shouldn't really say that you are the downvoter. Leave a constructive comment explaining what is wrong with an answer but don't necessarily expose your identity as the downvoter.

Comment: @vba4all: So it is still accepted in meta, but not in SO

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments

Comment: @bummi: What a joke of a decision... if I am going to tell someone what's wrong with their post, then starting with '-1' or not is hardly going to change the fact they might not be able to handle criticism very well. And as for anonymity, surely that's my decision to make? Should we prevent "The reason I am downvoting this is because..," comments too?

Comment: I do personally like the `i^2` or `i²` notation ;)

Comment: Plus one, because this change was something really stupid. Just write it with letters instead of numbers.

Comment: Quoting Sho9 from the linked answer: "FWIW, this is the current pattern I'm matching: `^\s*[+-]1\D`"

Comment: `+1` If you wrap it in code, it still works!