# Comments can't contain that content - "+1" - why not?

Tags: discussion

I tried to add the following comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108518/create-an-apex-form-with-multiple-pages):

> "+1 for the wizard idea. Note however, ... etc. etc."

But this was not allowed with the error "Comments can't contain that content". I ended up adding the following, semantically identical, comment:

> "Another vote for the wizard idea. Note however, ... etc."

Why is this error such a wonderful idea?

I could understand if it was just "+1" comments that were disallowed, but in this case I wanted to make it plain that I liked the idea, but that there is extra info that the OP should consider if they decide to go that way.

Comment: `+1` is another way I've seen several times already

Comment: i thought we didn't vote this "feature" in, not sure why they pushed it anyway. too easy to bypass this blockade

Comment: @Coffee, Our votes aren't binding. They're just suggestive. In any case, filters, that are easy to bypass, can still be good. They can reduce some of the noise of +1s in comments from some users, without frustrating the users who are really adamant about starting their comments with +1.

Comment: +1 because this is not actually a duplicate: The other feature request doesn't appear to have been accepted (with all of the downvotes too).

Comment: @Coffee The feature was actually implemented when Shog posted that question - it is a place to discuss the implementation and whether the community (presumably those users hitting the comment block caused by it) thought it was necessary.

Comment: @animuson after that was implemented I got the impression that discussing new features will just lead to more frustration since our feedback won't necessarily be taken into account anyway.

Comment: @Renan To be fair (if you look at my first answer on Shog's post, I was decently against a full block myself), Shog did post the results of running it for a couple of days, and when you break down the data, as I did with a second answer on the question, it's actually a bit amazing to see how many commenters did remove their +/-1 and how many of the comments were flat out noise as it was.

Comment: @Kendra I also noticed a lot of people writing variations of +1 or -1. And when you do remove the +1/-1 from the comment, you take out the piece of information that the comment is tied to a vote. If on my posts I see comments with "+1 for this or that", it helps me reinforce whatever was positive about the post. If I see "-1 because of this or that", it makes me want to correct it. If I just see "this or that" without that important bit of information, I will either ignore the comment, or that won't help me reinforce positive behavior or correct wrong behavior :(

Comment: @Renan [If you look at my second answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277759/2607247) I did actually count variations of "+/-1" as keeping the "+/-1", such as "Thumbs up", "Upvoted", and "Downvoted" just to name a few. I can completely understand where you're coming from, but at the same time a good majority of the comments that were completely abandoned were utter noise, and of the rest, the ones without the "+/-1" tended to be more constructive. It's really hard for me to argue with that kind of a stat. On that note, if you hadn't checked my answer, feel free, and let me know (cont.)

Comment: @Renan (cont.) if there is something else I should judge the comments on. I still have the data I worked from yesterday, so it wouldn't be too hard to look at another metric. Provided my spreadsheet I was using continues to cooperate. (It was changing some of the "+" symbols in the attempted field into "=" instead. What a nightmare.)

Comment: ⁺¹, never knew that. Probably because I did always use superscript letters.