# Users working around the +1 comment block

Tags: discussion, comments

So the [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments) has been implemented, even though it's not a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), where the following image appears if you attempt to put "+1" in a comment:

[image: comment block]

And already, there's comments like [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220074/how-does-initializing-an-integer-as-a-1-compile/27220435#comment42919879_27220435) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221221/assignement-operator-requirement-for-key-type-in-stdmap#comment42921371_27221221) which contain multiple plusses to get around the block. I thought the first one was just the poster being eccentric but now it appears to me that it's to get around the comment block.

One:

> +++1 Great answer to this question not some other question.

Two:

> ++1 I can think of little practical reason for it to be needed. That assignment should be easily done with copy construct, for example.
>   Hmm.

[Jason C](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277319/3920237)'s answer already predicted how users would work around it, but this escapes his list.

Since the linked question is not [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I don't think the implemented change is "official". Should I flag the comments? There is strong opposition and lots of good arguments against the block, so I don't want to be a negative nancy.

Comment: @cVplZ Just looks like boxes to me :)

Comment: @cVplZ And now we run into the issue of displaying workarounds portably.

Comment: Well, this proves the original idea was a huge waste of time. Minus one to you, dear sir.

Comment: _"Since the linked question is not status-completed, I don't think the implemented change is "official"."_ Uh.... It's official. Shog's the one that posted the "suggestion" and implemented it then and there. (and does not seem to plan to remove it, or has not stated such.) He's also posted the results of if the block did anything or not. I doubt this really changes how you should be flagging comments.

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion, it was an announcement that the change had already been made.

Answer (score 9):

> Should I flag the comments?

Just because you see a comment that is working around the +1/-1 block, does not mean that you should auto-flag it because it's breaking the new "rule".

Treat it like any other comment. Is it helpful? constructive? obsolete?

For example, these should be flagged as not constructive or even too chatty

> ++1 thanks so much!!
>
> +one you saved my day
>
> +++++++++++++1

These types of comments should not be flagged

> ++1 Your answer worked for me for the most part, except I had to also make sure the variable wasn't equal to 0 for it to work like I needed
>
> plus+1 since this seems to work exactly right for users using python 3.0, but if you're using python 2.7 this won't work

So in conclusion, it looks like that first example comment you posted could be flagged as too chatty/not constructive, but the second one shouldn't be flagged since it seems helpful.

Comment: +++++++1 Hm to be fair, I don't agree with your counter example. Only the second comment has useful information (in your example).

Comment: +1 comments are not really useful, but as long as they don't get out of hand on many questions/answers, I see no harm. Sometimes people want to verbally say thanks rather than just an *anonymous* upvote (as long as it's a bit more than just "thanks"). Plus, it gives others the ability to upvote that comment, which in conjunction with all their upvotes on the Q or A, shows a high level of appreciation. I agree it's not useful and could be flagged "not constructive", but it's also nice, and not being a social network doesn't mean not being social from time to time ;)

Comment: @James Being social is fine. It doesn't have to be shoehorned into "+1", though. Imagine how SO would turn out if "This." or "Literally this." were allowed.

Comment: I agree, the third one is taking the proverbial. As I said, *as long as it's a bit more than just "thanks"*