# Improve "that content" in validation error message

Tags: feature-request, comments, error-message

I put in `-1` in a comment and got validated with this message (emphasis mine):

> Comments can't contain **that content**.
>
> Stating how you voted may distract the author from the important parts
>   of your comment. Please focus on what you found useful or unhelpful
>   about the post.

Can we improve the "that content" part? I found it unclear at first at why it was being rejected.

Comment: +1, just because I am free to say so *in Meta only*.

Comment: -1, just remove that rule completely instead IMHO

Comment: The same goes for comments like " http://whathaveyoutried.com ", which are misleading for another reason--you get the "Comments **can't contain** that content" message, but in fact it's perfectly okay to link to that site (as you can see), as long as it's not the *only* thing in your post.

Comment: People will use workarounds like -2 or +4 or +infinity

Comment: The specific content is used in the error message for *posts*, but **why not for comments**?

Comment: `Just put your whole comment in backticks, then you won't receive that message`

Comment: @ivarni: See [Should we discourage leading +/-1 on comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/1048572) for that.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, and that question sits at -52 at the moment. Why should the SO devs spend time on improving a feature that the community doesn't seem to want in the first place? Hence -1 on this. If the feature was worth improving then I'd +1 this but I don't think it should be improved. I think it should go away.

Answer (score 3):

Outside of the discussion on whether allowing `-1` in a comment or not is a good idea, I do agree that the message could be improved. Rather than giving the explicit reasons though, perhaps just add a link to a help page explaining what the rules are. For example:

> Comments can't contain **that content**.
>
> See the help page for reasons why this content is not allowed:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/help/allowed-content

I suppose it could link to a wiki question instead?

Comment: Adding a link to this page isn't going to help when the filter gets is completely wrong; I was just prevented from posting a comment regarding the mathematical expression `-1.0^(1/3)` and had to trial-and-error it to figure out what on earth the filter was complaining about.

Comment: @kaya3 This is a 6 year old answer, how on earth did you dig this up?