# Why are we allowing usernames such as "stackoverflow", "stack overflow" and "moderator"?

Tags: discussion, users

Today I encountered a user named "StackOverflow"; and when doing a quick user search see that 32 other users have also chosen that same name.  (21 users have "stack overflow").

I've been here long enough to know that this was just another user without any special affiliations.  However, I think many users, especially new users, would be confused when encountering postings and comments that are signed by an entity called "StackOverflow" or "Stack Overflow".

- Do we have any restrictions at all on usernames?
- Perhaps any username that is simply "stackoverflow" or "stack overflow" should not be allowed or be restricted to appending something else.
- Related:  there are actually two users named "moderator" and one named "community".  For the same reasons, maybe these names are a bad idea too?

**EDIT**:  Added cases of "stack overflow" to the mix because some have made this about the spelling of the site.  Although the site name is spelled with a space between the two words, the logo is missing the space.

Comment: Stack Overflow, I don't really see any issue with.  Moderator, on the other hand, I guess could be a source of confusion.

Comment: AFAIK, the diamond character used to indicate moderators is not allowed in usernames. If it was, it would be bad.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, I've been here a really long time and when I saw a comment signed by "StackOverflow", I had to look twice.  It almost got me so I certainly think it would be very confusing to newbies.

Comment: While you're at it, remove the user Community as well. And everyone with the name *rene*, can't imagine someone wants to impersonate me.

Comment: Because there is no point in disallowing it.  It doesn't confuse anybody, a user is not a web site.

Comment: logos never have correct spellings, they allow creative flexibility http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: @Sunshine, yeah, no argument from me, but that's not the point of this question.  People will see the name spelled one way in one place (text) and another way in another place (graphic or logo).  Sometimes that's called inconsistent branding.

Comment: Is `Administrator` and its variants allowed? Perhaps this could be added to your question.

Comment: @cybermonkey, just [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/users) to check for any name you wish.  There are several users named "administrator".

Comment: @Sparky Interesting, one would think it's one of the names that definitely *wouldn't* be allowed. Another think: *all* those accounts seem to be deactivated; the reputation for them shows up as 0 in Search, which suggests this (or maybe simply a bug).

Comment: Maybe this would have gotten some more traction if you'd changed your own name to "Moderator"

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker,  yes!  lol!  I'm sure I would have promptly been accused of impersonation and banned.

Comment: @Sparky: There's always [one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3994394/cunt). :D

Comment: @TheBlueDog, wow... that won't last for too much longer.  lol.

Comment: @Sparky: Dunno, maybe it means something else in Arabic? ;)

Comment: See the username `Stack Exchange CEO`? Just ignore it :)

Comment: And what about (potential) names: "admin", "administrator", "master", "CEO", "manager", "bot", "meta", "community", "enforcer", "stack overflow chairman", "JoelS", "Joel", "user", "controller", "control", "dbadmin", "archive", "banned", ... Should we disallow them too?

Comment: @Spook, I don't know, should we?   You forgot "Bossman" and "The Godfather".   ;)

Comment: My instinct would be to explicitly ban only enough such names as necessary to make it clear that circumventing such a ban to falsely claim official status with the site is, in fact, a policy violation. Someone who's willing to violate policy will do so regardless, to be sure, but having some minimal level of automated enforcement makes it clear that a policy does, in fact, exist.

Comment: I just wanted to say - the coolest username I have seen on SO yet - meet: [Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ](http://stackexchange.com/users/253331/%D0%A0%CC%80%D0%A1%D0%A2%C8%A2%D1%B8%CC%81%D0%A4%D0%A5%D1%BE%D0%A6%D0%A7%D0%A8%D0%A9%D0%AA%D0%AB%D0%AC%D1%A2%D1%A4%D0%AE%D1%A6%D1%AA%D1%A8%D1%AC%D1%A0%D1%BA%D1%AE%D1%B0%D1%B2%D1%B4). Something to be said about minimum length rules.

Answer (score 53):

There are no *technical* measures preventing users from picking potentially confusing names.

I don't think *StackOverflow* is a name that confuses, not much. The term was in use before this site was invented, even. :-) I'm a little more concerned about *Moderator* here, but it depends on how the user is behaving.

If a person uses the name to *impersonate* or otherwise deliberately tries to claim a position of authority, then a moderator can reset the user name to the default `userxxxxxx`. If you see such behaviour, please flag a post or comment by that user (use *other*) and explain the situation.

Note that a technical solution could never sufficiently cover all the various ways you can spell 'names of authority'; block *Moderator* and they'll use *Community Moderator* or *Diamond Moderator* or use cyrillic look-alike letters, etc.

Comment: I can see the following needing to be disallowed: System, Tester, Support, CommunityTeam, Community Moderator, Moderator, (diamond) moderator, Admin, SysOp, etc.

Comment: And "George Stocker" for all those imposter @GeorgeStocker types

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I'm fine with a moderator resetting any such account if they are indeed impersonating moderators with that. But I don't think a technical solution is going to stop anyone acting with intent.

Comment: To be clear, I did not necessarily have nefarious users in mind when I posted, as there are other mechanisms in place to deal with abuse.  I am merely questioning why such are allowed in the first place.

Comment: @Bart Don't forget my original screen name: "Gortok".

Comment: What if the person posting was named Moderator by their parents? I've heard stranger names...

Comment: You're not able to use a  ♦ in your display name btw; you get the error 'Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit'

Comment: I've written mod messages for impersonation before. Not putting up with that nonsense. :-)

Comment: Can I be !moderator?

Comment: @dav_i: My clone batch is named Mod-R-ATR, but my friend the Computer would never allow that to confuse anyone, despite what happened to my infrared friend Ultravio-LET-1.

Answer (score 40):

I agree that there's no feasible technical way to disallow this.

I dispute, however, that mods should only step in if the user is actively impersonating moderators.

It seems to me he has done so simply by picking the name "moderator" as his or her username. How anyone can see this as anything other than impersonating moderators (be it as an obvious joke, a pitiful serious attempt, or something else) is beyond me!

**I would like to see moderators reset the usernames of such accounts.**

Comment: I can see this as "anything other than impersonating moderators" as long as they are not actually impersonating moderators. I also don't think it's a problem that warrants any kind of actual moderator interaction _given the name choice is the only thing wrong here_. It's just a waste of time. I do believe we should just let those users be until they actually do something like trying to impersonate a mod or SE employee - and if they do so, a mod should simply nuke their whole account instead of bothering with small measures such as resetting their name.

Comment: @l4mpi: My point is that advertising yourself by the name "moderator" _is_ impersonating moderators, regardless of what you go on to do in Qs, As and comments. I frequently come across users — some even have quite a lot of rep — who do not understand the distinction between 10k+ users and moderators. God only knows what authority they'd think these "moderator" users have.

Comment: Or, maybe, they want to express they are a material slowing the speed of neutrons. Or are german and host a radio / tv show. Or they're some christian religious figure. Or they simply think it makes their profile look cooler. But the reason for choosing that name actually doesn't matter, I simply disagree that this is a problem _unless the user is actively trying to be disruptive_.

Comment: @l4mpi: The crux of my argument that you evidently disagree with is that it does not matter one bit whether the user is actively trying to be disruptive: all the matters is whether they _are_ being disruptive! And I posit that they probably are. Oh well.

Comment: Well, I believe in darwinism here. I too have seen way too many users "who do not understand the distinction between 10k+ users and moderators", and yes, some of them had far too much rep for being this ignorant. If they fall on their face because they believe anything posted by a 1-rep user whose only authority stems from the fact that their username is "moderator", I postulate it's their own fault - and maybe they'll take this as an opportunity to learn more about SO and SE. TL;DR it's not disruptive for anybody who has a minimal knowledge of SO, so I'd let them be.

Comment: @l4mpi: Meh, perhaps

Comment: I'm hearing a lot of this "it's not really an issue" and Darwinism stuff, and I actually agree with these points to an extent.  Yet not no-one has explained a legitimate reason for somebody *needing* a username like "stack overflow", "stackoverflow" or "moderator" besides the wholly unbelievable reason that maybe it's their real name. (We even have one named "Community" with 900 rep.)  While I agree that *maybe* it's not worth the trouble, I still don't understand the fervent defense of these names.  We already automatically restrict certain content; so why are the usernames sacrosanct?

Comment: @Sparky: There's an underlying dislike on Meta of introducing filters that by their very nature are be ineffective in the general case, and I can certainly get behind that argument. The problem is that you have to go out of your way to deny these usernames; it's not like there's someone at SE HQ hand-approving each new user account. So it has to really be worth it. This, incidentally, is just one of many reasons that Shog's "+1/-1" ban is so unpopular. :)

Comment: I realize that... however I was surprised there wasn't a simple blacklist in place for the most common cases.

Comment: What is Shog's +1/-1 ban?

Comment: @Sparky: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/560648 And yes I'd like to see such a blacklist, too, I think.

Comment: Well that kinda goes against the popup _"you down-voted, please consider leaving a comment explaining how this post can be improved"_.

Comment: Look for the little diamond ♦ after their name.  If they don't have one... Well, then.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think it's fair to say that anyone who is consciously aware that the lack of a diamond guarantees lack of any powers or authorities.. is not in the set of people that anyone's proposing could be harmed by this.

Comment: @Sparky: [Yes, it does. :)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments#comment119709_277314)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , Someone named admin or moderator could still be the admin or the moderator of another site. An ambiguous name is not the definitive proof of impersonation. It could just be proof that someone tried to find a clever name. If anyone could understand, I thought that especially someone with your first name would understand.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: I don't think someone reading "Lightness Races in Orbit" is likely to confuse me for someone with a role of authority at Stack Exchange ...