# Force members to leave comments when they upvote

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, upvotes

This question is related to but different from [Why not to force members to leave comments when they downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281350/why-not-to-force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-downvote) and its duplicates.

I see bad, repetitive, off-topic questions showing no research effort either explicitly or implicitly because any research effort at all would have lead the asker or anyone interested in the answer to it.

These questions sometimes (often, considering) have been upvoted, and I wonder what the upvoter could possibly see in the question that I am missing. I feel left out!

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501763/how-do-i-use-vectors-in-c#comment47161869_29501763), courtesy of πάντα ῥεῖ.

---

**Why this website does not force people to comment when they upvote ? I can upvote as much as I want during several months without leaving a comment and I won't be suspended for this.**

Comment: Technically, this is a comment. Yes, I posted a stupid comment just because the site required me to do so.

Comment: This proposal makes at least as much sense as forcing people to leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: Anyone want to complete the set and open *"Force members to leave comments when they neither upvote nor downvote"*? Whenever I see questions where `upvotes + downvotes != views` I find myself wishing every single person had explained why they did(n't do) what they did(n't do).

Comment: Forcing people to comment is just going to either attract a lot of garbage comments (like vaultah's comment above) or discourage upvoting.  Neither of those are good things for the site.

Comment: Seriously though - yes, I'd often like to know the motivation for a vote, too. But if users aren't willing to reveal it, there's nothing you can do to force them.

Comment: Sometimes this could be considered being a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501763/how-do-i-use-vectors-in-c#comment47161869_29501763 But in general it's the same story as with downvotes. You don need to disclose any reasonings, period.

Comment: And unicorns, of course.

Comment: You are normally a pretty level-headed guy, what is this all about?  Does somebody need to throw you a life-preserver?  Tell you to take a break for a while?

Comment: @HansPassant I admit that I erred. I should have posted this on a Friday. Also if I came here more often I would have know what tag to use to subtly suggest the presence of some sort of meta-meta-commentary.

Comment: @PascalCuoq _"... and I won't be suspended for this."_ There aren't any reasons for suspension of an account, just because up-/downvoting, unless uncommon/abusive behavior is detected.

Comment: I upvoted and left this comment (quite a pity that [nobody else but me and SE developers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285253/839601) can really tell if this is true)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That part is paraphrased from the other meta question this one links to. But yes, that was the original writer's surprise that a history of downvoting without leaving comments is not punished, and it is mine that the same is true of a history of upvoting without leaving comments.

Comment: @PascalCuoq _"Example, courtesy of πάντα ῥεῖ."_ LOL. I'm seeing loads of these all day long, but well.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Going to upvote this now: asdfasddfasfsadsfsadsfaadsfsad! _@will_??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have to admit that while my attempt to get more posts with score ≥2 on meta and eventually become nominable has largely backfired with this question, I do encounter a lot of “Who upvoted this? What did they see?” moments on StackOverflow. More of them on questions than on answers.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Come along here, participating from the _good stuff_. You're welcome. ;-) .... I'm rarely leaving such comments as I've linked above, but when I'm doing so, I'm serious. That question doesn't make sense, because it's not asking about any particular problem. I well know there are sentiments for new users, and unconscious upvotes given for such _newbie questions_ to comfort and encourage new users to ask questions. But we agree it's the wrong action.

Comment: it would be funny to make _this_ question a canonical duplicate target for those [requesting comments for downvoting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/250177?lq=1)

Comment: @PascalCuoq What you would say about marking as favourite? Like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) you can see 775+ people marked it as their favourite question. Would you like to ask users to give reasons for that too?

Comment: No worries for me on this question.

Comment: It's been my experience that users who demand explanations for why you voted this way and that way are just looking for an argument. It's almost always a discussion that leads to nonsense. I express this out of personal experience as both being the person that someone is demanding an explanation from and from being the one demanding an explanation (when I used to give a rip).

Comment: @johnrsharpe Force comment after reading question?

Comment: I'm only leaving this comment because my phone told me that I can't not vote on this question unless I do or don't leave a comment. So here's a comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because frankly it's a troll question, and Shog's answer is a troll answer, too (albeit in good humor).

Comment: @TylerH I posted this question in good faith at the time, but frankly, you and the community can do what you want with it now.

Comment: @PascalCuoq we already did, 6 days ago.

Comment: @TylerH yeah you see what I'm saying

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is indeed a much bigger problem than comment-free downvotes, and I'm glad someone has finally decided to break the silence.

For reference, here are stats for the past 90 days on comments when voting:

```
Name    PctCommented 
------- ------------ 
UpMod   11.28 %      
DownMod 27.90 %
```

That's the % of votes coupled with comments *from the voter*. Clearly, we have a problem.

...But there's an *even bigger* problem. [As jonrsharpe notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289607/force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-upvote#comment173751_289607),

> Whenever I see questions where `upvotes + downvotes != views` I find myself wishing every single person had explained why they did(n't do) what they did(n't do).

For the same 90 day period, a whopping **99.95%** of views were recorded with no corresponding votes *or* comments.

Yeah. Kinda makes all these meta questions complaining about comment-free *votes* look pretty pathetic, eh? Here we have noticeable percentages of both up- and down-voters taking time out of their busy lives to leave comments, only to get criticized here for not doing **more**... while the biggest slackers of them all, the readers, get off scot-free.

I hereby declare a moratorium on all further discussion of voter comment encouragement, until such a time as we can solve the lazy reader problem. Open to any and all suggestions, particularly those technical solutions involving forged iron restraints.

Comment: Sure they can. They just need to log in and earn 50 reputation points. Something which anyone downvoting and a good many folks upvoting have already done. See what I mean? Just *lazy!*

Comment: -1 Let me rephrase: people who don't *want* to log in can read but can't comment. Did I really need to spell that out for you?

Comment: Oh, and maybe I don't *want* to leave comments when I upvote either? Maybe *you* don't **want** to be leaving all these comments when you downvote? But we are. Because we *care*. About something or other.

Comment: -1 and maybe I want to start my comments with either a "+1" or a "-1". Maybe one day *you*'ll realize that a feature suggestion (really a forced feature) that has a net vote count of -141 (as of this writing) isn't at all "controversial".

Comment: Please try to stay focused here: we're discussing the impossible task of forcing people to do things they *don't* want to do and shouldn't have to. Wishing and hoping isn't a viable solution.

Comment: -1 Well, forcing users to do things should be easy for you, right? Just make a modal pop-up appear whenever any answer or question is viewed, forcing the user to input a comment before continuing. Post the comment under an omnibus `anon` user if the actual user is not logged in. It's been awhile since you've made an arbitrary and disastrous change like that. Go for it.

Comment: "Clearly, we have a problem." It was not really clear to me though. What was the problem? I was under the impression comments are second-class content, to be issued sparingly as opposed to issued to every single post visited. Recently there has been discussion of increasing comment moderation with a path for easier deletion indicating even stricter rules for comment posting. What problem does excessive comment posting solve?

Comment: @JackManey - I think you made your point. These comments are getting more rude than objective in my opinion.

Comment: Wait a minute. What about those people who are coding right now and not even **reading**. I can't even _begin_ to estimate how many views we aren't getting due to them.

Comment: Well, that's what email is for!

Comment: None, @Travis - mandatory comments when voting, reading, or outside enjoying the beautiful day are all patently ridiculous. So if we were ever going to start doing such a thing, it would only make sense to target the biggest population of users first - look forward to a future feature-request outlining a system for extracting commentary from people who have never used or heard of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please. No one with any sense does *that*. You gotta think **bigger!**

Comment: Remember what? I haven't seen anyone using "-1" in *ages*...

Comment: It's ok, I don't hold it against you.

Comment: -1 Well, at least you weren't completely alone in your efforts, this time. @TravisJ made an attempt to help you.

Comment: best thing you did to encourage comments (when downvoting) was to [trigger grace period reset](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773). The more I see how it works, the more I like it (by the way, many thanks for that feature)

Comment: This answer does not appear to be serious. I have never downvoted on any SE site except for this answer.

Answer (score 17):

As to contribute for the particular example you have left from *"my courtesy"* I'm putting the relevant screenshot (as the actual question is likely to be deleted, and cannot longer be seen by < 10K rep users):

[image]

And repeating from my comment:

I'm rarely leaving such comments as I've linked above, but when I'm doing so, I'm serious. That question doesn't make sense, because it's not asking about any particular problem.
I well know there are sentiments for new users, and unconscious upvotes given for such newbie questions to comfort and encourage new users to ask questions. But we agree it's the wrong action.

My usual action is to (counter) downvote, and applying an appropriate close reason for the question (*"unclear what you're asking"* for the actual case).

---

To expand about my personal observations regarding *"sentiments for new users"*:
I have observed weird up-/downvote behaviors along low rep users all the way.

- Invalid and obscure questions might be upvoted
- Valid and clear questions might be downvoted

just because the OP comes along with low rep (and probably along an initial trigger in the one or the other direction was given).

Comment: "Which idiots upvoted this question, and for which particular reasons" Haha. I feel that pain (albeit in PHP).

Comment: some of these idiots could be voting badge hunters lacking rep to unlock downvote privilege

Comment: Your comment in the screenshot was rude and offensive, and should have been edited to read something like "Will upvoters care to explain the reasons for their vote?"

Answer (score 7):

Comments and votes are decoupled because they solve different problems.

Problem #1 is, which answer do you read/try first?

Pretend you're an average, unregistered reader, coming here from Google. You see a question and some number of answers. Your time is valuable; where do you begin? Ideally, with the answer that best solves your problem.

**Voting addresses this problem by quantifying the general reaction of past readers to the answers, giving you something to sort on**. That's what voting is for, not providing feedback to content authors.

Everything else that results from a vote—reputation effects, styling effects, implications for community moderation options—is a side effect that the average reader doesn't care about.

Most comments are superfluous at best to most readers; at worst, they're a distraction from the real content, which needs to be ranked and accessible.

Answer (score 5):

There would be a significant amount of ramifications to this that in my opinion are not ideal. As clearly indicated above, users could simply leave non constructive comments to bypass the requirement.

However, there is a true problem with forcing users to leave comments, which is that there would be too many comments. Some answers have literally thousands of votes, and if each one of those answers had thousands of comments what purpose would that serve? In my opinion it would only detract from the actual content of the answer itself which is where all the value was supposed to be located. The unfortunate issue would be that the thousands of comments, many of which could be non constructive, would outweigh the answer itself.

Furthermore, no one would have time to read thousands of comments which are all in support of a single answer. More than likely it is clear the answer was correct (which is presumably the reason for upvoting it).

All in all, forcing users to comment would more than likely cause a lot of harm to the site in my opinion. After all, comments are supposed to be transient, second-class content. They do not show up in search, and they are not even vetted fully by the community.

tl;dr; In my opinion forcing users to leave comments when they upvote (or vote in general) would cause damage to the site's content.

Comment: You made your point as I was thinking the same while I was reading "shoq9" and "Jack Maney" controversy above.

Comment: For example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) has more than 1500+ upvotes, 750+ marked as favorite and more then 60+ answers with some huge number of votes on some answers. If every users goes to give a comment then the post will lost it meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Members should not be forced to leave comments when they upvote, at the very least due to the culture of no-upvoting of reasonable, meaningful, fair questions here on SO. Burdening potential upvoters with some extra duty could turn SO into [a website of mostly negative-voted questions](http://www.evacommentary.org/episode-01/01_C168_big.jpg).

[image: Tokyo-3]

Ok, maybe not as bad as Tokyo-3 and the GeoFront but you get the idea.