# Why was I down voted for this question?

Tags: feature-request, moderation

I experienced that I got immediate -5 after this [conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24248512#24248512).

Moderator, Can I get the reason for receiving -5?

Can we think of the feature that actually provides the information about the people who down voted?

Comment: How can moderator read other people's mind why they downvote? No-for 2nd question.

Comment: No, voting is and always should be anonymous

Comment: Is moderator not suppose to understand, what is wrong with the question? If question is right, why down vote? There should be some kind of regulation on such mischief by voters.

Comment: No mischief involved - 7 people feel your question is not up to standards. Moderators literally can not reverse these

Comment: @santiago How do you prove that, 7 people genuinely felt my question is not up to standards? you say, not upto standard. Below slugster say that -7 is because of promoting question.

Comment: I can't and don't want to anticipate why 6 others thought question was not up to standards - I am simply not that interested.

Comment: @santiago don't want to anticipate? but you said above: "7 people feel your question is not up to standards". I have no issue with the negative votes, but I have an issue with the double standard culture in SO.

Comment: I stated that 7 people thought it was not up to standards, as 7 have downvoted it.  Posting something like this will probably attract more downvotes.

Comment: @santiago who cares? am not here to see my numbers

Comment: Obviously you do - or else you would not be having this tantrum here and in the chat room you linked. - it is very possible you got downvoted due to your attitude in the chat conversation.

Comment: @santiago am here because, I know the reason why I got down votes. and am concerned with that reason.

Comment: Interesting, it's not the reason I downvoted your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289607/force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-upvote#comment173902_289607)

Answer (score 11):

> Moderator, Can I get the reason for receiving -5?

The down votes have nothing to do with moderator actions, nor can they be undone by moderators. 
Quite simply you got 5+ down votes because you promoted your question in a chat room, and people there didn't like it. You didn't help at all by retorting. If you are going to play in the sandpit with other kids, then play nice. Don't be surprised if they retaliate after you let loose with a few sharply worded comments.

> Can we think of the feature that actually provides the information about the people who down voted

If you had bothered to search first you might have found some of the literally thousands of prior requests here on Meta to provide a mechanism to identify down voters - and you would have also seen why the request has been denied every time.

Comment: what is the meaning of promoting a question? I went for an answer, because by then I did not get an answer. But now, I have a perfect answer to this question posted by Holger

Comment: Getting an answer doesn't negate the down votes on a question, and it also doesn't validate the question as a good one (note that I'm not proficient in Java and I'm not judging your question in any way). If people feel you didn't put enough effort in or asked something that is basic and you should have known they will down vote. Holger now has a chance at a rare reversal gold badge if his answer gets to +20 up votes - which is a great result for him helping you.

Comment: In the chat, you said `
people who try to offend think that someone got offended. your limit is, you can give -2 nothing more than that. Be in..` - know that this is a red flag to a bull - people are not going to do as you demand

Comment: @santiago I did not demand anything except seeking an answer to my question.

Comment: Your attitude in the chat room was overly defensive, either way, the votes are there, deal with it.

Comment: @overexchange Everyone always feels that their question is perfect and that they were down voted unjustifiably. Persistently arguing the case doesn't help. That aside, people are not required to give a reason for up or down voting, end of story.

Comment: @overexchange if you think that disagreeing with you, or your questions, is offensive, you're gonna have a really rough life in this industry.

Comment: I still can see this issue or improving quality or whatever you call it still persists. it's like someone says you're bad without telling why. Without a proper feedback the improvement of anything takes time. I see most of the people asked these type of questions is looking for a "Why the downvote ?" and not daring anyone. it'll be better if there's something like a floating tip made available on hovering over the downvote.

Comment: @Rajesh2389 If you think you've got a good suggestion for how it can be implemented then propose it in a question and see what people think. Feedback for negative votes has been an oft requested feature, so if you have a way then don't hold back :)