# Is it inappropriate to explain why I upvoted?

Tags: discussion, comments

The [policy on commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) says one should avoid compliments such as "+1 great answer"; but - what about "+1 because [explanation of why a point which was made in the answer is particularly useful.]"?

If I follow the letter of the policy, that's not part of what I should add as a comment; but is that really discouraged?

**Note:** This question is not about whether comments should/n't be able to start with +1 or -1.

Comment: I don't often find a good reason for upvoting posts. When I do, I let the OP know. I don't do it for the OP, I do it to emphasize what a good post (imo) looks like. Those comments are typically like your second example.

Comment: If you need to add an explanation why something was useful, why don't you edit the answer to make it clearer so no explanation is needed anymore?

Comment: It's useful to signal why you think that is a good post _in particular_. It serves to encourage others to up their game a little.

Comment: related: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601) :)

Comment: Use a unicode plus `＋`. The +/-1 comment filter is probably the dumbest and most counter-productive comment feature ever. Everyone works around it, even moderators.

Comment: @gnat: oh no. The humanity...

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Well, because 1. The answer may have it's own narrative flow. 2. Other people might not agree with me about what's more significant in the answer 3. it's not my answer; I'd edit an answer if it was lacking or obscurely-phrased, not for failure to self-aggrandize...

Comment: I'm hesitant to vote to reopen but I'm not sure this is really a dupe of the posted target, especially with a little rephrasing.

Comment: @codeMagic: If you're unsure, then you are sure :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you have read, thanking someone or saying "+1 nice answer" and the like are really just noise and should be avoided. However, it happens and really isn't a huge deal in the grand scheme of things.

Now, what you are asking is about pointing out a particular piece of the answer which was *really* useful. That being the case, **it may be helpful to others if they might miss it or not realize how significant it can be**. In this case, I wouldn't consider it noise at all and would go ahead and comment.

Comment: +1 for the fact that the comment "_can be helpful to others if they might miss it or not realize how significant it can be_".  But seriously, this is the heart of the answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Good point. I should highlight that

Comment: now I'm torn whether to delete the now obsolete comment or leave it in a sort of meta demonstration.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Leave it for meta awesomeness!

Comment: I was about to suggest mentioning this in the commenting guidelines, but then realized it might be gratuitous. On the other hand, I have been told off for making this kind of comment once.

Answer (score 15):

I'd say that the "+1" part of the comment is still pretty pointless. Are you really voting just for one tiny piece of the answer? Or are you voting because the answer is good overall? Ideally, it's the latter, and if you want to highlight some feature of the post, just do it without tying it to your vote.

A comment mentioning your vote

> +1 because you mention the distinction between `Oswald` and `Griswald`. Not everyone realizes that they don't both blah blah blah.

doesn't really convey more useful information than

> The distinction you've made between `Oswald` and `Griswald` is an important one. Not everyone realizes that they don't both blah blah blah.

In its extreme form, I find this sort of comment a bit embarrassing, to both the poster and the commenter. I've occasionally gotten comments along the lines of "+1 for $OBSCURE_WORD_USED_CORRECTLY", and all I can think is "Really? That's the most valuable part of my post?"

Comment: I'll agree that it's not the most meaningful part of the comment, but I don't think you'd complain if some other kind of praise was used.

Comment: I would like to agree that it's meaningless. I think it should be. However, on another SE site, I found that not indicating "I agree with you" in a comment to an answer can cause certain people to get unreasonably angry, turning a productive conversation into a non-productive one. Unfortunately, some people understand a comment to implicitly start with the words "I think you're wrong because".

Comment: Don't have a conversation, then, @DanGetz; make your comment and then ignore or flag anything unproductive that is generated in response.

Comment: Most of the "+1 for $OBSCURE_WORD_USED_CORRECTLY" comments I've seen were on Metas, where things are generally sloppier anyway.