# What is Stack Overflow Meta and how is it different from Stack Exchange and Stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

I am looking for a place to ask a question about posting a question on Stack Overflow.

I thought that this would be the place but it appears to be a bunch of people complaining about things.

So my question is what is Stack Overflow Meta used for and can I ask a question regarding SO here?

Comment: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: You're in the right place. It just happens to be that complaining is a more popular topic.

Comment: @Mysticial to be fair, questions tagged [meta-tag:bug] are basically an official complaint/suggestion box.  Some of the other stuff though (like "Why was I downvoted?  My question is not bad") can get old though.

Comment: You know what is funny? I spend a lot of time answering other people's coding related questions and I try to be good with SO, then I come here to find out what I can and cannot do and I get down voted lol People are funny. I was right, just a bunch of complainers. However thank you @Mysticial :)

Comment: We only complain here now. To ask questions about posting questions you need to go to the main [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith my downvote is for "lack of research"

Comment: @BilltheLizard thank you lol, its like pulling teeth to get the info I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @ryanyuyu "Lack" would not be the correct word, mis-understaning would be more appropriate.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith my initial reaction to your question was that your were being sarcastic, and even that you yourself were complaining.  I apologize.  But the help center does _clearly_ spell out your exact question.  If there were a way to mark this question as a duplicate of something in the help center, I'd do that.  NathanOliver's link is basically the answer to your question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu So what is the difference between Stack Overflow Meta, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange? I get what Stack Overflow is however when I read the help center stuff I am confused with the naming of all the sites.

Comment: I think you should just go ahead and ask your "question about posting a question **on** Stack Overflow" here. That's one level up from "a question on Stack Overflow". Meta Stack Exchange is more for, uh (getting lost in meta) *meta* questions, for all of the sites under the SE Umbrella Corporation. It's another tumble down the rabbit's hole. But then upwards.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith ah, that's a legitimately more interesting question.      Basically, meta stack exchange is for _network-wide_ concerns, such as bugs that appear on every site.  Meta Stack Overflow is just for discussion the culture/workings of this site, like what is on-topic on this specific site, Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jongware Thank You :) I think I might be a little more confused now lol

Comment: @ryanyuyu So stack overflow meta is like the congressmen in the white house? sit around and find new ways of improving the site? If so, I gotcha now. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I think a slightly better analogy is that Stack Overflow is a state, Meta Stack Overflow is the state legislature, and Meta Stack Exchange is the U.S. Congress.  Except we don't have to elect anyone to voice our concerns for us.  We just post directly to either the state legislature (MSO), or the national Congress (MSE).

Comment: Almost. Every subsidary site in Stack Exchange has its own Meta, and its primary purpose is to *only* manage its own sub-site. So questions on, say, Graphics Design Questions, are off-topic *on MSO* (but on-topic for MGD, naturally). So it's more a state senate (? - is that correct?), and occasionally Big Decisions trickle down from higher up, or the other way around.

Comment: Side note, where are all my down votes going? on SO you get notified, here they seem to just be there, I don't really care about the actual votes, just curious how it works here.

Comment: There's no rep on any meta except MSE. Instead, the rep you see on meta is just a reflection of your rep on the main site. Since this is the case, downvotes and upvotes on meta don't affect your rep. (If I understood your last comment correctly.)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith they mean almost nothing for a personal user. Often they mean agreement for [meta-tag:feature-request].  There's no reputation gain/loss.  But upvotes day can get you meta badges.  Like [meta-mortarboard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) or [meta great answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer)

Comment: @Kendra so then what's the point of the votes? To discourage or to help others find good questions in the future?

Comment: So wait. Can we complain here or not? Because, boy, do I have some things to complain about

Comment: To show support for the various ideas posted here- They're especially useful for feature-requests. Upvotes and downvotes can also signal how well users agree with a post- This is supposed to just be for features, but it tends to flood over to other tags as well. The downvotes on this post are likely due to "lack of research" as there's both a help center topic and a FAQ post to answer this question.

Comment: @Mureinik High five! take it down, don't care. I already got the help I needed, your just a little too late :)

Comment: @codeMagic I'll listen to your complaints.  I might just downvote them that's all.

Comment: @Kendra I agree with that, upvote :) lol

Comment: @ryanyuyu your attention and willingness to listen to my bitching is more than worth the downvotes. It's much cheaper than professional therapy

Comment: So this is pretty darn funny!!!! Without a voting and rep scale its just a free for all here huh? lol. My new favorite place for sure!

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith if you want more quirks, I retracted my downvote now that your question is better titled.

Comment: @codeMagic that's what I'm here for.  And as it happens, [I tend to agree with you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300958/4320665).  I'm glad you consider my attention more valuable that fake internet points you don't even lose.

Comment: @Adam we certainly have a lot of fun on meta! But it is still where a lot of features and whatnot are born. It's also a place to hash out differences in opinions on how things should be handled on the main site. Come and have fun but also contribute useful posts when you can, if you so wish

Comment: @codeMagic for sure! It's a relaxing environment for sure. 3 more votes to close, can we see if we can atleast hit a new record on downvotes first!?!?!

Comment: But Adam, votes on Meta mean very little. It could be that someone lost his keys ((a running Meta joke). It could be too many people think you should have read the Help. If you hang around a bit, you'll find the overall composure of Meta much more relaxed than SO itself. After all, this is the place we gather to have a good bit o' laff on them account.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith you have a long way to go.  Here's [the most downvoted feature-request existing on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments) at (currently) -162.

Comment: I had fun thanks to the people that help clarify this for me, I am going back to the dark side, I will see all you weird quirky meta guys later!

Comment: @ryanyuyu aww damn :(

Comment: I might have gotten lost but, *"So my question is what is Stack Overflow Meta used for and can I ask a question regarding SO here?"* did he ever ask his question about SO?

Comment: @codeMagic No i did not lol!!!! I wanted to see if this was the right place first ;)

Comment: I just came here for the free food and wine... still waiting...

Comment: This is literally the first thing that shows up when I google “meta stack overflow”.. and it’s downvoted

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On **Stack Overflow** you can ask about how to do your **programming**.
On **Meta Stack Overflow** you can ask about how to do your **Stack Overflow**.

This is basically what **meta** means:
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)

> Meta (from the Greek preposition and prefix meta- (μετά-) meaning "after", or "beyond") is a prefix used in English to indicate a concept which is an abstraction from another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.

For example, talking about how to react in a certain type of situation (even if most people link to a specific case for more clarity).