# Is this answer really NAA?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, upvotes, not-an-answer

Today I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32033432/2422013), downvoted it, & flagged as NAA (Not An Answer):

[image]

In my eyes, the answer is seeking clarification from the OP, and (at the time of posting), the user who answered only had 1 reputation (boosted by the two upvotes on their answer), suggesting that it was posted as an answer as the user was unable to post comments.

Due to the two upvotes, I'm interested in whether this answer is actually an answer or not. Maybe I've interpreted it incorrectly- if I did, starting an answer with '*Did you use*' and phasing it as a question isn't such a good idea.

Is this an answer, or something that's better suited to a comment?

Comment: What was the response to your flag?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The flag's still pending.

Comment: It's been deleted now.

Comment: Nobody in his right mind upvotes this of course.  So this isn't real, this is typically a sock puppet account of a user that's question-banned.  They post crap like this and use their banned accounts to upvote it.

Comment: related: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601). :) First upvote could have been cast by a grateful inexperienced asker. But who could cast a second one, that's really fishy

Comment: @HansPassant The moderators could probably answer that, typical sock-puppet accounts often use the same IP/ISP.

Comment: Grey area TBH - If the tone was somewhat more assertive `One possible explanation for this behaviour would be if you use a JS framework or plugin that applies the editable rule on the specific class you use for this button` would you still have flagged it?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What was/would be the effect if 1 rep users would be allowed to comment? Doesn't seem very harmful to me, asking poor questions or posting answers which are comments seems a lot worse than poor comments.

Comment: @MeanGreen see [50 reputation points to make comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252133/839601) over here and [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/165773) at MSE

Comment: @HansPassant: Not everything is a conspiracy.  Many people who aren't looking carefully might upvote this because it's a good point/request for clarification, disregarding the fact that it's not really an answer.  Barring any evidence of the behavior you describe, it seems to me you're breaking both Hanlon's and Occam's razors.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You've answered the question yourself, actually.

> In my eyes, the answer is seeking clarification from the OP...

Anything that's seeking clarification about the question is a comment, *not* an answer.  The number of upvotes on it are irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is he can't comment.

Comment: @Joshua:  No, that's not a problem.  If one doesn't have enough reputation to comment, that doesn't permit them to use answers as comments.  They have to earn the 50 rep like the rest of us.

Comment: @Joshua: that is by design. So is the clarification that the appropriate flag shows: "*As soon as you reach 50 rep* ..."

Comment: You should be able to comment if you do not have enough reputation not sure why there is a limit of 50 you need to reach before commenting silly.

Comment: If you find the comment really useful, you can post the comment yourself, stating the original poster had not enough rep and giving credit to him. Then you flag it as NAA without any risk of losing relevant information.

Comment: @Makoto once in a blue moon I see a driveby user with 1 rep leaving a comment-as-an-answer that's important and insightful and provides a vital but non-obvious criticism of the accepted answer; I edit the answer they're commenting on or comment on it with whatever they had to say before flagging, and I'm glad in those cases that they broke the rules and said what they had to say instead of remaining silent. Of course, the answer being discussed in this question does not fall into that category.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 The threshold is to prevent spam and noise.

Comment: Someone can answer the OP's question, *and* seek clarification, and be an answer, no?  Adding a question doesn't make an otherwise good answer into a comment methinks.

Comment: "We purposefully designed a problem into the system, so it's not a problem" - yep, we are definitely on meta

Comment: @MarkAmery:  Naturally there are some very rare exceptions to this, but by and large the comment-as-answer posts I've seen haven't been that good.  It's good to cast a critical eye on all content, but in all honesty, an answer that acts like a comment just doesn't belong.

Comment: @Kik:  I'm not sure I follow.  What specifically was the problem?

Comment: I see a lot of questions that are marked as 0 answers, but the second to last comment is Have you tried X? and the last comment is from the asker "Yeah X solved my problem." It wastes time of people looking for questions to answer that these things end up labelled as unanswerered. If it might provide an answer encourage people to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I will play devil's advocate here. Pay attention to this comment:

> Grey area TBH - If the tone was somewhat more assertive `One possible
>   explanation for this behaviour would be if you use a JS framework or
>   plugin that applies the editable rule on the specific class you use
>   for this button` would you still have flagged it? – [Martin Smith](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith)
>   [yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302612/is-this-answer-really-naa#comment234421_302612)

It's the same answer, just worded differently. Pedants will still say "well, if you're unsure it shouldn't be an answer" but we're just circling around the same problem. The comment left by the OP:

> actually if i remove the "buttonlikelink" class it solves the problem ...

Easily, the author of the answer could reword this to:

> Removing the "buttonlikelink" class will solve the issue, which is most likely caused by a JS framework or plugin.

On the other side of the fence, if this was a comment instead and the same exchanged occurred, somebody might complain "this is an answer, not a comment!"

While you could certainly argue that questions and speculation don't belong in answers, you should edit or leave a comment instead of wiping the answer altogether. This avoids drama and deletion of a potentially useful answer.

Comment: So it seems you have found out that the question mark only occurs after questions. Mayhaps that is why it is called question mark and not answer mark? The plot thickens...

Comment: You're certainly welcome to suggest an edit that clarifies an answer that follows this pattern. That would also avoid "drama and deletion of a potentially useful answer". That said, I'm not seeing the problem with deleting the answer if no one's edited it into shape.

Answer (score -4):

I think it's an answer that is misleadingly phrased as a question, agreeing with Martin Smith and user5237770. On [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), it states:

> It's perfectly fine to post an answer saying, for example, "I'm not
>   sure what the cause of your problem is, but if it's X, you can solve
>   it by doing Y. If that doesn't help, try Z and let me know what it
>   says."

I believe this is what the answerer tried to do, and, as commented by user5237770, his answer should have been phrased as

> I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but if you are using any kind of JS framework that may apply the editable rule on this specific class, then that could be the cause. In that case the solution is obvious.

He didn't state the solution if he's right, but I think it's obvious that in that case you can either remove the framework or override whatever rule the framework brings.

All in all I would still consider this gray zone, as it has a high chance of leading you to the solution, without spelling it out (enough).