# Stack Overflow question bans. Questions and Ideas

Tags: support, feature-request, post-ban

Before I continue, I just want to say, that I am not mad for my ban. I completely understand it. I just don't understand what was wrong with my questions in the first place and would like to know.

I am writing this because there are some things that I do not understand when it comes to the question bans on the main site.

- How long will it take for my account to be restored after editing my questions?
- What did I do wrong when writing my questions?
- Are my questions now good enough?
- Is this a good question?

Ways to make the ban system better:

- One month after the ban has been issued, give the user a test on what they have learned from this experience. Make them answer a few questions on how to write a good question. If they pass, allow them to write a question with what they have learned and if they pass, release the ban and make the system keep a close eye on that user until the 6 months have passed. If another ban is issued in that time period, there is no way to remove the restriction, except to edit existing questions or wait 6 months.

Problems with the ban system:

- Once a user has been banned, they can only get unbanned by editing their questions or serving their time. When it comes to me, I tried my best to edit them to comply with the guidelines. I even went ahead and restored my old questions, fixed them and answered some of mine ond other's questions. This gave me a lot of reputation, but nothing happened, even if I have earned as much reputation as I lost from downvotes. Once you downvote a question or answer, you SHOULD HAVE TO SPECIFY WHY you have decided to downvote. This feedback should then be sent to the writer, to fix the question/answer.

Comment: When you've asked multiple poorly received questions, the next time you ask the system does *warn you* that your prior questions were poorly received and you should ensure to make the question you're posting better™. As for asking again, you still can but you need to wait 6 months since the last question you posted.

Comment: *"Once you downvote a question or answer, you SHOULD HAVE TO SPECIFY WHY"* *why* is already in the tooltip; why repeat what's already there? There is no benefit to multiple people commenting "This question lacks research effort; it is unclear or not helpful."

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen the Q&A linked here: As to getting our of the question ban, we *can't* tell you exactly what's necessary. Even moderators don't know the exact algorithm the system uses to impose question and answer bans. *The best information and advice we have* is in [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](/q/255583/3773011).

Comment: Voting on any of the child meta sites, such as here on Meta Stack Overflow, is different than on main sites. On child meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. Voting on child meta sites doesn't affect reputation. So, while there are some tangible effects for the post author of voting on answers on child meta sites (some badges), most people don't care all that much about those tangible effects.

Comment: Even though there's very little tangible effect from voting on child meta sites, it's still not pleasant to get downvotes for most people. We're social creatures by both nature and nurture. Just having people express disapproval of us or our works is something which most people find unpleasant to varying degrees. That, however, shouldn't prevent other people from voting, as voting is a *critical* part of how the sites work. Without voting, we'd have no way to gauge how good/useful a post is (main and meta sites) or how much agreement/disagreement there is with a position (meta sites).

Comment: Note: suggesting that people be required to explain downvotes is something that's been covered many, many times on Meta Stack Overflow (MSO) and Meta Stack Exchange (MSE). Suggesting it here will almost certainly result in a number of people responding negatively (i.e. downvoting).

Comment: You get a chance to prove yourself after 6 months. The system allows you to ask one good question. If you can prove that you know how to ask useful questions then this should help you get out of ban.

Comment: "*Are my questions now good enough?*" This can only be answered by the post score. Are your questions receiving upvotes now?

Comment: “I just don't understand what was wrong with my questions in the first place and would like to know.” - You don’t have enough questions that re not deleted to warrant a question ban, so how many questions have you ask, that are now deleted? Asking a question and then deleting it counts heavily towards question bans. “How long will it take for my account to be restored after editing my questions?” - If you have more than a handful of questions deleted, editing your questions, won’t be enough.  You will have to ask 1 high quality question every 6 months until you reach the threshold

Comment: 'give the user a test on what they have learned from this experience' - I suspect that there would be little demand for such a test - it would be very expensive to hire an experienced developer/SO member to invigilate/mark, never mind air fares and hotel fees.  No, such a test could not be reliably performed online.

Comment: “Once you downvote a question or answer, you SHOULD HAVE TO SPECIFY WHY you have decided to downvote.” - When I did routinely the only thing that would happen, is the author would go searching for my contributions in a SE community they were active in, and downvote every question I had asked. Which is the reason that policy can never happen.

Comment: You have the following 3 deleted questions: [Q1](//stackoverflow.com/q/74642615), [Q2](//stackoverflow.com/q/74218175), and [Q3](//stackoverflow.com/q/74180507).

Comment: To add to what @SecurityHound says, sometimes you get people "revenge vote" you even when you *haven't* downvoted because you had the audacity to suggest to a user how they could improve the question and they assume you were the "evil" individual who downvoted them.

Comment: Plus, in my and many other people's opinions, not enough people downvote content and they are *incredibly* important to the community; there is *a lot* of **bad** and ***dangerous*** content out there that has been greatly upvoted but because comparatively so few user use their downvotes the answer looks "good". *Forcing* those of us that do downvote to *explain* that vote would make that never of users even smaller, making quality control impossible. Plus, upvoted are worth *give times* the value of a downvote: if a downvote needs a comment on why, then an upvote needs a full answer on why.

Comment: I also don’t see anyone asking for mandatory commentary for upvotes.

Comment: another duplicate: [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/839601)

Comment: @SecurityHound there is a feature request for that: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601)

Comment: *"How long will it take for my account to be restored after editing my questions?"* - Editing your questions does not in any way guarantee that anything will happen at all. It is not the editing that does it, the questions would have to receive upvotes to counter the downvotes. It is the score going into the positive that makes all the difference. The chance of that happening are not great, your questions are competing for attention with thousands of other questions daily. New questions look  more interesting than downvoted questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been banned automatically by the system from asking any more questions.

This means that you have asked several questions that were not well-received (score of 0 or less), and continued to do so after receiving automatic warnings from the system about the quality of your questions.

The exact metrics used to implement and lift a question ban are restricted, so that users can't try game the process and evade a question ban. But, here are some general points to consider:

1. It will usually take some **years** to get out from under a question ban. You are given the opportunity to ask a new question every six months (that's 2 a year), and the likelihood that both of those questions will be *so* well received as to lift the question ban immediately is pretty small, generally speaking.
2. Deleted questions count against you for a question ban. The site guidance suggests editing and improving deleted questions to try and make them better-received. Realistically, most new user's deleted questions are deleted for good reason, and there is not much (read no) hope of rendering them useful. They should never have been asked in the first place.
3. You are not banned (I presume) from answering questions or editing posts. Assuming your answers are well-received (score > 0) and your accepted/rejected edit rate is not too low, those activities will *probably* help a little bit, but most likely not enough to substantially reduce the length of the question ban. The problem, after all, is questions, not other site activities.
4. Spend the next 6 months studying closed questions daily in your tags of interest. Make sure you understand why they were closed. Read the comments, if any, of other users that try to get the OP to clarify the question or otherwise bring it in bounds. This will hopefully prepare you to not repeat common mistakes.
5. Work on your search skills. Don't try and use the search portal on Stack Overflow; it's borked. Instead, use "site:stackoverflow.com {search terms}". As your search skills improve, you will find that most of the time, you don't even *need* to ask a new question. Which is good, because if the answer is fairly easy to find, then your question would likely not be well-received anyway.
6. Work on your debugging skills. Learn how to use a debugger in your programming environment. If it doesn't have one, learn how to use what's called "printf debugging." Find out about and practice what's called "rubber duck debugging". Again, once your debugging skills improve (even just a little bit), it's odds on that you won't have to ask a question that will be poorly-received, because you will have figured out the problem yourself.
7. In 6 months, if you think you have another question to ask, consider whether or not it might be better asked on Quora, or Reddit, or someplace like that. It's common for novice programmers to need advice, or reassurance, or mentoring/tutoring, but that is not what Stack Overflow is for. You may have already learned that questions like that are not well-received. Keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I can relate to what you're going through. I was really close to getting a question ban (probably still am given my low reputation on SO), but I want to emphasize what the other answer(s) mentioned, although they're pretty good already.

Using SO as a new user is tough because the rules don't entirely portray the mindset of what you end up learning along the way, which is more useful than anything I think:

1. critical/logical thinking
2. independence
3. reading documentation
4. putting the project on the back-burner/shelf
5. searching skills
6. trying (and failing)

I might miss one or two things, but this is what I ended up picking along the way. I didn't master any of these but, I think I got a feeling that I do have those in some form now.
Everyone can have those, it's easy.

1.
As the other answer mentioned, asking ***yourself*** questions is far more critical (1) than anything else. Do you ***really*** need to ask X,Y,Z questions? but if you do, which we all need to, do you really need to do it, the way you're doing right now?

TLDR, you need to look up other good answers/questions and see what they all have in common. Are they related to the OP problem, or more general? Do they have multiple ways of answering the same or related questions? Are they accurate in the present time? etc

2.
By not getting your answers/questions viewed in a good light, you can change the way you look at things. I ended up being much more independent when it comes to solving my own problems because of that. Even if they take more time, it became much more fun, and valuable (as a learning opportunity) but also, helpful to do so (both for valuing other people's time by only asking for help when it was ***really*** needed and for valuing my own time as well, since it wouldn't make sense if all of my woes are always solved by someone else)

3.
I'm the first person to complain about a lack or non-existing documentation for certain things, or specific features in certain domains/contexts. I do so while knowing full well how hard it is to write good documentation and the work that people give for those, but I think a lot people can admit it can be frustrating nonetheless when those are the main reasons you can't find an immediate answer or use it to "Do Your Own Research".

That said, it's still relatively there, so use it anyway. Make use of every little piece of information for your related question/problem, and pull through.

4.
If you don't have immediate answers, it's fine. Time is the deciding factor here. Call me an optimist, but I like to think that I'll find answers ***eventually*** or at least an alternative for what I want to do, so putting things on the side/back-burner/shelf is fine too.

5.
It sounds easy when people say it, but it's more finicky and complex than it sounds. You see, search engines are weird. They are all relatively similar, but their result differs, for various technical reasons I'm not gonna go over here. But they are still (immensely) useful. Just by switching a word here, or a meaning there, or using a synonym, you get closer and closer to your potential "clue" or answer for your problem. Even if you don't, you can still pick up good habits for creating good queries to find things.

6.
Trying things related to your problem, even if they will likely fail is a good thing too (provided you take into account the cons of it). If the only cons for you is "Time", then go for it. Otherwise, if there are other deciding factors (eg: responsibility, etc), maybe just depending on this alone is not that good of an idea. But it's still a potential option.

I think I missed a lot of key points here, but I think I managed to put my point across. Whether it was done in a good way or not, that's probably up to whoever is gonna upvote/downvote or comment.

I said what I said, so make what you can/want of it, and good luck.