# How to deal with posts that ask us to answer another question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I have a question about this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719668/video-counter-updating-all-video-on-my-website

How are we supposed to handle questions such as these (Posts linking to an older question they asked)? Should these be flagged to be closed, tagged for moderator intervention, one person mentioned duplicate, or just ignored?

Edit: It appears that the question was removed, so can I get some clarification from the mods on how to handle this? Lots of many comments that contradict each other, and would like to get an [O] answer.

Comment: Flag it as unclear what they are asking?

Comment: Yes flag it. Choose the one you think right.Like unclear,duplicate,low quality.I think this question should be delete so I flagged it as low quality(so that it goes to review task of low quality posts and people can recommend it to delete).

Comment: In all honesty though - there is no way to 'bump' an old question. Opening a new question is much more likely to be 'seen' unless you want to add a bounty. But rather than this approach, redrafting and re-asking might be more appropriate.

Comment: Actually, in this case they're linking to an old question they didn't ask (the OPs on the two questions are different). If they had linked to their own old question, it would be much easier to resolve -- you can always close as a duplicate if the OP on both questions is the same (the accepted/upvoted answer criterion does not apply).

Comment: The canned messages for the "Low Quality" queue even suggest (for answers that are actually questions) to the poster to create a new question, and link to the old question to provide context. There's nothing wrong with what's described above (linking to an older question). Maybe there was something wrong with this specific post, but it has been deleted since so I can't see it. And this question here doesn't describe what was so bad about it.

Comment: Here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731616/oracle-count-consecutive-days-meeting-the-same-given-criteria).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this particular case, IMO that should be closed, because OP is only trying to draw the attention for a question that no other user answered before.

The reason for closing the question in this case could be:

> "OFF-Topic Because.. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this
>   code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem
>   or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the
>   question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not
>   useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and
>   Verifiable example.

If OP has a doubt/problem/error, should create his/her own question by explaining the problem giving the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Which OP didn't do in this case.

Comment: But in my experience, I ask a question that's duplicated in the past because the older post has answers that I am not satisfied with and there's no way to bump the question (if there were, that's what I'd be doing... and most likely, I did not ask the older question).  Also, asking a duplicated question that was not answer well in the past often get my question voted down, which I think is unjustified, because there's no other way to get the qustion answered.

Comment: @Novina as I said, if you are not satisfied with answers that you found for a question, then you should ask your own question being more specific, giving all the needed details, and I'm pretty sure that if you do that you won't get downvoted (at least so easily). Another good thing you can do is mention that previous question in your new question, but saying that you couldn't find your answer there, therefore a more specific question you're asking. Was I clear?

Comment: you're clear, but it's contradicting to what other people do.  If you read the answer here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296240/help-a-fella-understand-a-downvote  the top answer actually said, the OP was downvoted because he said "i can't seem to find the answer"... and in my experience, that actually gets more downvote for whatever emotional reasons I cannot explain.  The rules are unreasonably strict and people downvote more often than reasonable and necessary.

Comment: hey you didn't finish the whole sentence which is "*I can't seem to find an existing answer to why this isn't working.*". And I agree with him. When I say to mention (by linking it) a previous question where none of the answers were helpful to you is very different that saying  "*I can't seem to find an existing answer to why this isn't working.*" . Even more because OP isn't referring to previous questions at all.
And that's not mandatory, it is just my opinion. because as I said before if you post a question well structured and with details you won't get downvoted easily