# Why is it possible to downvote an answer that is marked as accepted?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, accepted-answer

I'm fairly new to being active on Stack Overflow and this has been bugging for some time.

I answered a question, formatted it properly, got several upvotes and a green check. The next day I got a downvote for... no idea!

Doesn't having the answer accepted mean it's useful? So why would someone downvote such an answer? Or why is it even allowed?

If someone wants to downvote for a legitimate reason, why not just leave a comment that the formatting is wrong.

Downvoting as it is doesn't feel like "constructive criticism" unless it comes with a comment.   Even if the accepted answer is wrong, there are plenty of other ways to handle such a situation.

So basically what I'm asking is to maybe introduce a feature which requires an explanation by a downvoter for downvoting after the answer was accepted.

Comment: LOL!  Usually because it's totally wrong!   Yes, that happens occasionally.  More than occasionally on 'multithreading'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423221/alternate-between-2-threads

Comment: 'Even if the accepted answer is wrong, there are plenty of other ways to handle such a situtation.' - like what?  The answer is totally wrong, and there's that big 'Downvote' arrow.  Clicking it sounds perfectly reasonable?

Comment: possibly someone wants to [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316564/839601)

Comment: Only if you have to comment for upvotes as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That an answer got the check mark doesn't mean it's necessarily *correct*. It is awarded by the person who by definition isn't an expert on the question -  they had to ask, after all.

Because of this, being able to downvote accepted answers is *vital* to the system - it's the only way for the community to correct mistakes, like accepted answers that are outdated or grossly wrong. It happens all the time.

> So basicly what I'm asking is to maybe introduce a feature which requires an explanation by a downvoter for downvoting after answer was accepted

That  has literally been requested thousands of times before, pretty much once per day, mostly by people who just had something downvoted. A recent example is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316393/downvote-questions-without-explanation).

There are important reasons against it - mainly the fact that SO now gets around 12,000 new questions every day.

Requiring comments for downvotes would not automatically make things clearer (imagine comments like `ccasfyx lödksfsd`) and it would seriously impede voters' ability to vote quickly.

Also, a lot of the downvote-worthy content - not all of it, but a lot - shows a serious lack of effort to understand even the basics of the system for ten seconds.

Why should we force our faithful, engaged users to waste their time and energy to explain what those askers were shown when they signed up, but didn't bother to read?

Comment: I do tend to comment when I downvote if nobody else took the time - but I still want to strategically choose to not comment when I can predict that will only trigger a hate response.

Comment: @Gimby yeah, that's another very good reason why *forcing* comments would be a bad idea

Comment: @Gimby: I think that a downvote for something stupid and unproductive like an honest spelling error or something of this sort would rightfully get a hate response.
I understand all the reasons why not. but doesn't it kind of leave an opening for trolls who serially downvote for no reason?

Comment: @IlanKutsman yep. You can't prevent it, so don't even try as it is at the expense of the people who want to do good. That's why you can flag.

Comment: Do 'trolls who serially downvote for no reason' actually exist?  IMHO, they're some kind of mythical creature, like griffins, dragons and bigfoot.  Why would anyone waste rep on downvoting without a reason?

Comment: @MartinJames true enough, its more about petty humans who like to take revenge rather than mythical creatures.

Comment: @MartinJames: I don't imagine they're a majority in this community but I don't think there's absolutely none of them...there's gotta be a small marginal group who sacrifice reputation point for the devil. thinking otherwise is somewhat naiive IMO.

Comment: @IlanKutsman - I don't see ANY upside to such behaviour?  You have to earn the rep first, (and even if you get it via repPersonalServicesWorking, sockpuppeting  or ring-voting, it's still effort), then just blow it away on serial questions?   Why?

Comment: @IlanKutsman A small cabal of people downvoting perfect answers "for the devil" may very well exist (hey, stranger things have happened). However, I think you'll find that in the extreme majority of cases downvotes are perfectly justified.

Comment: @MartinJames :True, there is no upside for normal people. However, some people are plain a-holes and get a kick out of it,I don't know. And you gotta build a proper infrastructure to do evil.

Comment: @Yannis: Off Course.

Comment: @Yannis Join me and my brethren in the Church of Perpetual Downvoting

Comment: @IlanKutsman as long as we keep flagging, the a-holes will keep getting dealt with. There isn't much to gain for an extended period of time for such people on SO when they can just go rampant on say Youtube or Reddit.

Comment: @Gimby: The only problem is, you can't flag a downvoter because it's anonymous. you can flag a comment

Comment: @Ilan if you're really experiencing serial downvoting, you can flag for moderator attention e.g. on a post that got downvoted, and explain the situation. (Do *not* do that for small numbers of downvotes though.)

Answer (score 9):

> Why is it possible to downvote an answer marked as accepted?

Having an accepted answer merely means that the OP of the question found your answer to be the most useful one of the lot.

Downvotes indicate that the anonymous downvoter found that it is not so.

It may in deed be possible that someone disagrees with OPs perception of the best (or even a good) answer.

> So basicly what I'm asking is to maybe introduce a feature which
>   requires an explanation by a downvoter for downvoting after answer was
>   accepted

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316393/downvote-questions-without-explanation?lq=1) [has](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) [been](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments/278195) [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316393/downvote-questions-without-explanation?lq=1) [hundreds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296240/help-a-fella-understand-a-downvote?lq=1) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289607/force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-upvote?lq=1) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299725/why-do-people-often-downvote-questions-without-any-comment-or-reason-explained?lq=1) [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281350/why-not-to-force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-downvote?lq=1)

Comment: It's also possible that the answer is totally shagged, but still got accepted.

Comment: @MartinJames That falls under "someone disagrees with OPs perception of the best (_or even a good_) answer."

Comment: I suppose so, barely:)

Comment: There could be a case under the same category of someone who's a narcissistic newbie who downvotes someone knowledgeable with a perfect answer,(with 500k reputation and a zillion gold badges) just because he doesn't understand the solution.

Comment: @IlanKutsman That may happen, and its not against site rules. As long as you're not targeting a particular user, you're free to spend your downvotes as you like.