# Do you have statistics over "revenge-downvoters"?

Tags: support

Every time I downvote a post (and when I do, I always explain it!), "suddenly" various other of my posts get downvoted ;)

==> Do you have a kind of log or statistics which analyzes the "motivation" of downvotes and find the amount of "revenge downvotes" ?

Comment: What use of it would it be to you.  There's nothing you could do about it, and if the behavior is egregious, a script is supposed to go back and reverse voting fraud.

Comment: It would undermine my opinion that votes should be made public. Then there would be more transparance and also more discussion.

Comment: It isn't like you can directly contact anyone about votes anyway; you'd be burning energy for no gain.  [You should've heard about the time Tim lost his keys.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248)  Imagine having to explain *that*.  Sheesh.

Comment: 1. Analysing "motivation" would be difficult, if not impossible. 2. "Revenge downvotes" that *are* detected are removed, so the current answer is ~0.

Comment: That kind of "transparency" would mainly bring voting to a standstill, becase no one would downvote any more. Even politely *commenting* on bad posts can easily lead to pointless fights and all sorts of harassment... unthinkable what a public *voting* record would lead to. Stick around for a while and be active and you'll realize this wouldn't work and "more discussion" isn't necessarily a good thing at all.

Comment: As @Pekka웃 mentioned: Often enough, when you comment explaining a downvote, or suggesting improvements, one's met with a hostile or stubborn response. I don't thing this kind of "Transparency" is a good idea.

Comment: "Do you have a kind of log or statistics which analyzes the "motivation" of downvotes" If we did, people would be offering Stack Exchange billions for our mind-reading technology.

Comment: @BoltClock I knew you were going to say that.

Comment: @BoltClock Good idea for a new project then! I am sure you can find interesting patterns if you just analyze all the time/action paths of users. BTW Facebook / google / amazon are doing this pretty well already now.

Comment: We are not Facebook, Google or Amazon, nor strive to be

Comment: @santiago Then you miss the opportunity to become billionairs.

Comment: Who says I am not a billionaire?  and you are missing the point of this site

Comment: I prefer a site that  stays true to its goals to one run by people aiming at becoming billionaires, thank you very much.

Comment: _my opinion that votes should be made public_ - If you're getting revenge down votes it's because you're basically making your vote public: _Every time I downvote a post (and when I do, I always explain it!)_

Comment: @BSMP Then the system goes ad absurdum.

Answer (score 8):

> Every time I downvote a post

Kudos for downvoting posts deserving it

> (and when I do, I always explain it!),

*What exactly* are you explaining?
Why you downvoted, or what could be done to improve it (and not so marginally it is still bad)?
If there is no way to bring it up to par, or it's really obvious, no need to bother.

> Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?
>
> [Shog9♦: **No.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777)
>
> > Please consider adding a comment *if you think this post can be improved*.

> ==> Do you have a kind of log or statistics which analyzes the "motivation" of downvotes and find the amount of "revenge downvotes" ?

SE might have the raw data of abnormal voting-patterns the serial-voting detector reversed.
How good they would fit your request after thoroughly analyzing with all the confidential comment/close/vote-information they have, I don't know. And I'm not sure publicizing them, at least with any detail and without having thoroughly cooked them before, including anonymization, would be all that smart of them. Or maybe even legal.

Comment: "What exactly are you explaining?" --> e.g.: Someone asks for a sql statement and gives a sample table and sample result. Someone then posts a "solution" which works ONLY with the sample data ;) ==> Downvote + Explanation "works not in general case, please write a solution which works also in case xxxx "

Comment: That's a good comment. So, depending on the circumstances, put it down to coincidence, or having met one of the bad apples and shrug it off. If you got multiple downvotes (especially those hard to explain on your posts merits ones), wait at least a day for automatic mitigation and only then consider raising a mod-flag with the details as you see them for further investigation.