# How do I let an answerer know I downvoted but am amenable to remove it if answer is improved?

Tags: support, comments, downvotes

1. Someone posts a nearly link-only answer.
2. Someone *else* comments saying how it should be improved.
3. I upvote that comment.
4. I downvote.
5. I want answerer to know (and preferably to ping me at myusername@) I will remove it if answer is fixed.
6. I can't say "-1," "downvote" etc. and apparently SO doesn't want me to do this.

End result: this answer will sit at -1 even if it becomes a good answer.

This is somewhat a complaint (or you know "feedback") more than anything. I'm not a fan of barring "-1 because..." comments and this may be an important case TPTB did not think of, *because I really do want to convey that I have downvoted.* The only "workaround" is to subvert the check entirely or not workaround and just go with the "end result," which are both pretty undesirable.

Love it or hate it, [this is apparently what I went with today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209690/c-random-number-from-1-to-25-million?noredirect=1#comment56164258_34209782).

**Concluding remarks**: From the accepted answer I learned we're creating a culture of *not* explaining DVs now, and the red popup is actually trying to stop the commenting entirely *with an exception* for good constructive criticism, not make me explain my DV longhand. There's a slight feature gap in exactly the case I mention in this post where I would like notification on edits to certain answers but it's less of a big deal in the context that wanting to comment or put effort into a DV is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Hmm, if it turned into a good answer then the next 10 years will be kind to it.  If you absolutely want to take care of it all by yourself then just click the star on the question so you can find it back later.

Comment: @HansPassant starring's OK. star + "notify me on change" would be wonderful [does it do that?]

Comment: You will get a notification in your "favorites" tab for certain things on a question you star- I don't recall if an answer being edited is one of those things, however. You won't get a notification in your inbox, either way. Edit: According to [this answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/266735) yes, an edited answer will alert you in the "favorites" tab of your profile.

Comment: In an ideal world, the answer would receive upvotes after it is significantly improved, and you won't *need* to undo your downvote. You could undo it, and even make it an upvote, but it shouldn't been necessary, the upvotes that the answer would receive if it is improved to become a good answer should outweigh the initial downvotes it received. I rarely go back and undo downvotes in situations like this, unless I was the one who left the constructive criticism comment and was @replied to. In very special occasions though, i use the favorites tool and just manually check up on it.

Comment: Well, can't you just write a comment with something like *"I don't think this answer is a good one, because the link could go stale. If the license is compatible, please copy the relevant information from that link to this answer. I am amenable to removing my negative vote if you can do this. Please add a further comment to that effect and @ reply my user name."*? That's not a workaround, that's just using sentences instead of numbers.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan previous comment says exactly that. Not sure if the word "negative vote" is allowed -- I would certainly prefer to say "downvote" since that's what it is, and that's why it's a workaround.

Comment: Not exactly that. I read @KevinB's comment as saying "you don't need to go back and undo the downvote. Sometimes I use the favorites tool.", whereas mine says "just write a comment in English instead of things like '-1'". But if you don't want to take the time to do that, that's cool too.

Comment: idownvotedyoubecause.com

Comment: @djechlin Ok, so the author edited the post to quote relevant parts. Then the author pings you to ask you to remove the vote, but you discover that the solution was a *bad one*. What then? I wouldn't be keen on leaving a comment that implies I'm going to vote in a certain way if the OP does something and this something does not *guarantee* that changing my vote is warranted. (I don't actually talk about my votes in comments, generally.)

Comment: @Louis in that case I would follow through and explain why. I don't feel a need to be that literal. I could also un-dv, then re-dv, to fulfill my bargain, and re-explain my new reason for a dv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't comment on your vote, suggest what should be improved.

That way, it isn't about the vote (there's little else you can say to derail the comments faster), but about an identified weak point in the post.
And most people who react positively to constructive criticism will ping you to a) thank you for your feedback and b) make sure they fixed it completely and correctly.

See [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/3204551)

If you don't have a constructive comment, you can favorite a question, which means your favorite-tab in the profile will show when it is changed.

Comment: But I'd just be repeating the previous comment.

Comment: Interesting that we've come full circle on commenting on DVs. Shog9 has a good writeup on it.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can only favorite the question, or camp on the post.

Comment: I do wish we could favorite an answer and see only edits to that specific answer show up. Is that too dreamy? Most of the time at least, I'm favoriting stuff based on a favorite answer to a question -- the question recedes in the background, what I'm so impressed by and want to keep track of and bookmark is the answer.

Comment: @Ike you can do something like [this query in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407107?UserId=4842163)