# Enter at least 15 characters - why would the @userwhohasverylongname be included in the calculation?

Tags: discussion, comments

In Stack Overflow, we have a prevention against short and not-so-meaningful comments like:

```
"+1", "-1", "huh?", "nononono", "blabla"
```

And so on by having a minimum number of comment characters (which, as of now, is 15) and I see this as something that do more good than harm though this obviously cannot prevent all possible cases for such comments.

We can still do something like this:

```
"blablablablablanotsomeaningful"
```

Or by any other methods to bypass the filters just as what [Alexander O`Mara](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara) has demonstrated in the comments for this question.

This may also prevent some rarely-short-but-fit-comment like in the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq):

```
Yet. (oh why 10 chars...)
```

And that's OK, and we can live with that (though sometimes we might be a little restricted when we want to post a short *and* good comment - at least to our eyes).

However, I am curious to know why the name of a specific target audience would be included in this minimum character calculation?

```
@userwhohasverylongname +1
```

The above comment is OK.

But, though limited to the targeted user, by allowing the username as part of the calculated characters, does this not seem like defeating the purpose of putting in any minimum-number-of-characters rule in the first place?

**Edit:**

And just to clarify. I am simply curious to know what the reason is behind that.

This is because, while we actually already have such filter when we target a solo user comment (that is, to remove the @targetuser), we do not apply it to the user comment length.

I do *not* intend to ask why the comment filters are not made so strongly or to suggest that they must be made much stricter. No, that is not only involving too much works, but also may do more harm than good. And that is *not* my intention at all.

I only ask int the scope of *the text of the comment length for a targeted user*.

I hope that it clarifies my intention.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​+1

Comment: Meh, bypassing filters is easy.

Comment: Zero-width spaces in this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: I'm guessing it's just to educate the worst offenders, and accepting there are infinite ways to bypass.

Comment: Maybe, but we do have some filter to eliminate the target user @something if he is the only user in the comment/post for instance. I am just wondering why the same filter is not applied in this case.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara +1

Comment: @Gimby Obviously that is not what I intend to ask (My apologize if it is perceived as so). You extend my question to greater possibility actually. ;) I was merely asking why the name of the targetted user is not one among the filters for this 15 characters limit (while we actually already have such filter when we target a solo user comment) - not that to suggest we should have all filters we could possible have...

Comment: The reason is probably because the filter is very dumb and only checks the `textarea` content length without any kind of filtering. Not sure if it'd be any worth to "fix".

Comment: @Kyll I see... and are you suggesting that this filter may probably have no connection with the filter for solo target user removal? I do not know how easy/hard would that be to implement filter like that...

Comment: !!‮ kc̠̬u̲̖̤s͇ s̼̬͚̬ͅn̜̘̘̞̩̻o͎͈i͇̖̣̥t͓͍͖ci̯̬̪̟̖͔r̯t͉̪s͕e̦̣̖͇r͕̯͔͈̳̘̗ ͍̼͇ͅyr̩̻͍̼̤̘a͙͈̙̗͕r̮͔̟̦̹̣̳t̯̲̺i̦̗̮̼b̜̦̻̻̞ͅr̘̯̦̯̬a̪ ,̤͍͈͎h͔͔̪̩͇̗a̖͚̝͎e̤͇Y̟

Comment: Okay.. I hope my previous comment isn't _too_ obnoxious. But I don't think this is something which really needs fixing, even though some sort of basic check (maybe in JavaScript) would not be too hard. Is this kind of thing actually a common problem ?

Comment: @JonasCz no, it definitely isn't. ;) apart from the code / feature adding easiness/difficulty I was originally expecting that there might be some sort of reasoning between targeting private and public audience which somehow be considered by the SO. But maybe that is just my expectation... That might not be the case. It might simply be not thought of too...

Comment: @JonasCz I really want to know how you did that reverse text thing.

Comment: @JonasCz If you want to prevent people from doing this, JavaScript is certainly not enough.

Comment: @Dennis van Gils Here is the explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179941/how-do-i-make-text-reverse-direction-in-html

Comment: @Dennis, Here is the real answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox, 10th answer down or so..

Comment: @idmean, JS check would be sufficient in most cases, as most people will probably not be bothered to bypass is for something like this.

Comment: That’s especially funny when `@userwhohasverylongname` has the effect getting the comment accepted but is then silently removed because `userwhohasverylongname` is the OP.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what's the longest username in Stack Exchange?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I want to know that... if someone has access to the answer, kindly post... ;)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm and OP, If you know SQL, you can use the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), aka SEDE, for this kind of thing.

Comment: [100 longest user names](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/440085/get-100-longest-usernames) – the longest name is actually a GUID, and it’s being used multiple times…

Comment: @poke because [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118256/linking-creating-account-on-other-sites-adds-2-recent-names-to-your-profile/118649#118649)

Comment: @JonasCz You need to register `zCsanoJ` to make that work properly:-)

Comment: I͔̬ ̟̼̼̜d̩̲i̪̜̩̘̤d͕̺͇͚̩͎̹n̝'̦̟̞̝͙͍t̺̥̖̦͖ ̤̣͈̟͉̹̺kn̫̗͔o̹̞̘ͅw͉̞ ̦y̗̖͙͇̻o̺͎̣̗̣ͅu͓͇̣̙̱ ̱͖̯͚̟̩c̘̗͎̼͚̲̗o̻ul͍̗͔̬͔̘d̘͔̰̻ͅ ̩̩̜̠̱Z̼͈̰͉̺̜̱a͚l̝̬̰̜͔̗g̯̰͇̺̺͔͍o̘̗͇ ͅt͖̬̟̱͓̜̹e̙͚̖͈̫xt̠̥͖̤̱̤ ͍̺̤͈̝h̟͔͔͙̤̟e͎r͇͙̞͚̱e̥͍͍͈̠͉̪ ͙̪̖̗̼̫:O̘̟̣

Comment: @Kritner http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/344286

Comment: ส็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็

Comment: [‫‫](http://google.com)‫‫

Answer (score 34):

Why is something not more complex than it is?  Because simplicity is a virtue.

Complex systems have *more* bugs by virtue of their complexity.  Spotting relatively innocuous bugs and saying "why don't we fix this bug by adding complexity" implies that the inevitable bugs and maintenance cost caused by complexity is *worth* fixing that bug.  To justify adding complexity, you must first put forward a strong case for it.  Your case, as written, is "why not", which is not a strong case.

If you have some simple, clean solution that fixes 99.99% of an issue, and the goal is to reduce (and not eliminate) the issue, you are probably at an optimal point.  Adding complexity to mitigate the 0.01% that leak through is not a practical approach.

A failure of this filter is not catastrophic.  The goal is to make the thing being blocked *less common*.  Once it becomes rare enough, social norms will probably take over and make it even less common.

I mean, you might get lucky and be the one person in the history of computer programming who adds complexity to solutions and they never come back and bite them.

Let me know how that plan goes.

Comment: You see, there's this new thing called "testing".

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, testing solves all software quality issues caused by complex software at reasonable cost levels.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm getting a kind of "tongue-in-cheek"y vibe from your post. Yes, building software is hard, and defect rate raises with added complexity. Do you really need six paragraphs explaining just that, to get the message _"Doesn't the current approach work just fine?"_ across? I've seen plenty of `@longusername thanks` or `@longusername +1` comments which we apparently don't want on the site, so _maybe_ it is a viable approach to ignore usernames in checking the minimum comment length.

Comment: His handle is Yakk @CodeCaster...might explain the six paragraph thing ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster But do those comments *hurt*? I don’t think so. They are redundant, not needed, but it’s not a problem. So if you are bothered by them: flag them. Same with any other kind of “abusing” comments.

Comment: @poke they're not hurting or bothering _me_. They're bothering someone else, why the restriction was put in place.

Comment: 'testing solves all software quality issues caused by complex software at reasonable cost levels' This is exactly what testing does, isn't it?

Comment: Obligatory reading: [How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a lightbulb?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/) Oded mentioned this too, at some point..

Comment: @Jwg, If only that were true.. Unfortunately, it doesen't solve all software quality issues, and, well implementing and testing a new feature costs more than not doing so :-)

Comment: Oh wow. This particular bug could be fixed with a simple one-liner. But that, alas, adds additional complexity, potential new bugs and maintenance costs. Who would have thought?... It's a lovely argument though. Will keep it in mind the next time I have to implement something trivial but I'm in a too lazy mood. Thanks Yakk.

Comment: Just as more complexity adds more bugs, more text adds more reasons to not agree :) The first sentence was probably already enough. Simplicity is a virtue - amen.

Comment: @karo good!  Next time you are tempted to double or triple the length of some logic for a 0.1% case, where failure is not critical, please don't do it.  If everyone whose code I had to work with had the fortitude to say "no", things would be better.

Comment: @Yakk: That's a good argument. But as I was implying, I find the rest just ridiculous.

Comment: @jwg It only solves the quality issues you test for.

Comment: @Yakk I'd say that's a bit of an oversimplification. I agree that you need to take a good hard look in such a 0.1% case whether solving the problem is worth the additional complexity the solution introduces, but to say that it's never worth it seems a bit extreme. I'd also venture that the exact point of testing is to find issues in a cost effective manner rather than discovering them at a point in the development process where fixing them is costly, although edge cases can probably be thought up where this isn't the case, and admittedly it's impossible to test *everything* cost-effectively.

Answer (score 28):

Consider that `@something` is *not necessarily* a username/mention.  In the Java tag, and depending on the context, the following comment could be considered useful:

> Use @Deprecated

That's 15 characters; if what looks like a @mention were not considered, I'd have to pad it with 11 more junk characters.

Comment: Re: "I'd have to pad it with 11 more junk characters": Or, horror of horrors, you might be inspired to link to some useful documentation about `@Deprecated` . . .

Comment: Yes, a link would make it more useful, but that misses the point. Besides, inspiration doesn't always come before posting a first draft, nor does it often visit after an annoying system message due to an arbitrary limit.

Comment: Yes, but that's also true of the general 15-character limit. The site owners have made it very clear that they're willing to make tradeoffs that sacrifice some high-quality content, or even a *lot* of high-quality content, as long as the end result of these tradeoffs is that a higher proportion of the site's content is high-quality. (To be sure, I think they often get the tradeoffs wrong, and err on the side of deleting or preventing too much useful stuff. That's basically Shog's entire MO. But they're trying.)

Comment: Sure, but I wasn't intending to argue for or against the limit itself.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpfull to write `@Deprecated` in backticks and to ignore the @mention in backticks since you don't need monospace font for usernames

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK when the rule appeared, there are so many new users approaching with the forum/board culture. Users tend to post `i like it` messages in forms of `+1` or `wow` etc.  The solution is simple as preventing messages shorter that 15 character limit.

Because many users having the forum culture  do not consider finding ways of overcoming this, they simply learn that posting `thanks` or `great answer` comments are only producing garbage and they are not welcome in this community.

It still do its job on preventing garbage comments most of the time. Any user that learns how to overcome this also (probably) already learned what the comments are and what they are not for.

Comment: I like this answer ........................

Comment: In fact, `I like this answer` is longer than 15 chars, so no need for following periods (:

@Trilarion your answer proves that anyone who wants to show his **like** would find a way to do it against all strong checks (: