# Should comments that explain voting be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

Someone asked a slightly broad simple question, which read like

> So i don't have an example of code because I don't know how to do this yet but basically I am making a solver for a puzzle game called keep talking and nobody explodes. In my code there is a raw input where the user enters a serial number and later in the code I need to check if the last letter in the serial number is a vowel whether it be upper case or lowercase. Thanks!

It was answered by 2 users.

As it usually happens with answers to lazy questions, they got several downvotes and some meta-commentary, after which a moderator swiftly locked one of them. After a few minutes the moderator came back, unlocked the answer, edited it, and removed all meta comments except for the only approving comment:

> I upvoted because you have the right idea. Not sure why anyone else
>   would downvote

I thought the moderator simply missed that comment, so I flagged it. After a few minutes my flag was declined.

---

The placeholder in the comment field says

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.
>   Avoid comments like '+1' or 'thanks'.

It seems to me that the comment I flagged is essentially "+1", only longer. I also found this:

> Explaining votes is almost pure noise, meta-conversation and punditry. Your votes are your own to do with as you please; you owe no one an explanation, nor is a discussion of your voting habits likely to be helpful. - [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/2301450)

Furthermore, most of Meta.* Q/As I've read seem to suggest that flagging comments that are just noise helps SE.

Is my perception of the usefulness of that comment flawed? Are such comments allowed/encouraged? What should I do when I see comments like that?

Comment: In my opinion comments are just places that aren't vetted by the community; they were not designed to hold critical information. Let's just clear em all out and drop the table :)

Comment: There's no value whatsoever in that comment so it should be deleted. What kind of flag did you raise?

Comment: @Louis: the only reason that I thought was more or less suitable was "not constructive".

Comment: @vaultah Yes, "not constructive" is what I would have used too.

Comment: I could never be a moderator - life's too short for this kind of discussion :-)

Comment: Shouldn't Servy's comment "I upvoted because you have the right idea." be deleted as its not adding any value to this question, instead its adding humour. And if you are allowing humour, then why not motivation.

Comment: @HishamMuneer The value it adds is that everyone gets a chance to see just how useless the comment is. Your comment shows that it's working :)

Comment: Thank's for that pointer... on my comment. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: This was a mistake by a mod as mentioned in Undo's answer above, but in rare cases, you might even get your comment flag declined for double flagging. Once I had got a declined flag on a very obvious not constructive comment, because some other user flagged it as rude. I know that's a bit unfair, but that's how it is

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yep, brainfart on that one. Not entirely sure what the thought process was, but it probably made complete sense at the time. Someone else has deleted it now.

I don't have an excuse. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: How does it make you feel knowing you'll never be able to Undo your mistake?

Comment: TIL what a [brainfart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfart) is. thx

Comment: don't give up too soon: such comments are useful because they communicate to future visitors that the answer is downvoted due to (misguided) notion of what questions should be answered instead of the correctness or the usefulness of the answer itself. Otherwise a person who knows nothing about the internal squabbles on Meta may conclude wrongly that there is something wrong with the answer itself.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian so any "answer" which may be useful to someone, somewhere, sometime in some unknown context, is OK to leave drossing the place up? The answer is "write some code to do it, here's an example of some code". If the question was magical (in which case we'd not be here) and the answer magical, fair enough. But...

Comment: @BillWoodger: My comment is about the usefulness of the comment. I assume the comment OP provided is correct and that it is removed due to the blind mindless rule following. If the comment is not correct (the answer is not useful) then it would be another discussion. The commenter thinks, the answer is useful (you may disagree--you can vote, leave a comment, etc) To remind you the topic is: *"Should comments that explain voting be flagged?"* if we allow to vote on answers using whatever personal reasons then we should allow others to explain them, to make the site useful for ordinary people.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian you have enough rep to see the answer. Is it really worth a comment, and will anyone, anywhere, miss that other than the some here, it is not longer seen? I only went to the answer because of your comment above, and I was disappointed. No-one'll miss that, surely? Or do you just make the general point at every opportunity?

Comment: @BillWoodger: the specific answer is irrelevant (and OP hasn't provided the link as far as I can see--I respect it and don't snoop) . Again, the title of the discussion is not: *"should we remove comments I disagree with"* or even *"should we remove comments on useless answers"* (if the comment is incorrect). Please, read back the title to me (it starts with "Should comments..."), I want to make sure we are on the same page (literally).

Comment: @törzsmókus: Today, I learned what [TIL](http://acronymfinder.com/TIL.html) is — thanks.

Answer (score 66):

> Should comments that explain voting be flagged?

Not if they provide something else of value. For example, a vote-explaining comment like

> -1 because this answer doesn't work; it crashes if the input contains capital letters.

should not be flagged. Its role is primarily to inform people of problems with the answer, and the fact that it explains a user's vote is tangential.

In your particular case, the comment you flagged provides no useful information, either to the questioner or anyone else reading it. It serves primarily to encourage the questioner. Flagging this comment is fine.

Comment: I agree that when the comment on a vote (up/down) provides information which could be useful to the community, it shouldn't necessarily be flagged, especially in the instance where a provided answer doesn't work.  Such a comment would save others valuable time by avoiding rabbit holes in their quest for an answer.

Comment: If you add a comment saying the answer doesn't work, it should go without saying that you also downvoted the answer.  Saying that you voted, even as part of a substantive comment, is noise and should be discouraged.

Comment: I usually just ignore the frequent "thank you"s new users often leave — it's not much of an issue as far as I'm concerned — but will respond with a "you're welcome" if there's something useful I can add (as turns out is often the case). The thank you's are just folks being polite, and there nothing wrong with a little more of than in the world nowadays in my opinion.