# Do we reward good downvoters?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I saw Johnsyweb's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78845/johnsyweb), where he mentions:

> **On Down-voting**
>
> About two percent of my votes are down-votes, which I think is quite
>   low. Down-voting is an important part of StackExchange and helps
>   separate the good answers (and questions) from the not-so-good. If I
>   have down-voted one of your posts, I will have left you a comment as
>   to why. If you down-vote one of my posts, I ask that you, too, leave a
>   comment as to why so that I can either improve my post or remove it.
>   Thank you.

What a nice paragraph, really, I mean I am in the quest of finding what is happening when I want to [read just the first elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710018/towards-limiting-the-big-rdd) and I read this and despite that I am in a rush on solving this, decided to post.

As always, when you go to the top, awfully written (bad) questions are going to bomb you every day. As a result, downvoters will fire their guns, cast a close vote and just leave for the next bad question. I mean, I have done that too.

When I see the question with a bunch of downvoted questions of my favorite tags, I rush into them to check and some times I don't leave a comment (well most of the times there already advising comments).

However, the people that do take the time to leave a comment should be rewarded, how do we do that?

---

<sub>I remember myself advising authors of bad questions and even ending up listening to some bad words (?!), but I don't remember any reward ( except of the self/internal one :) ). While I agree that a guy like me should not be rewarded, a guy like him should!</sub>

Comment: It will be good way to encourage people to help improve the content and those who succumb to their sheer laziness and don't comment. A good question indeed

Comment: How would such a reward look like? Who would decide that a comment is worthy of a reward?

Comment: We do prompt people below a certain rep to consider commenting when they downvote.

Comment: By *"good downvoter"* do you mean *"person who comments when they downvote"*? Because that's a terrible definition.

Comment: Related: [The problem with extrinsic motivation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation)

Comment: Being able to downvote is enough reward for me.

Comment: Used to be a pretty active contributor with over a 1000 answers.  But he posted only 6 in the past two years.  That happens, one just runs flat out of constructive things to say after a while when none of it ever seems to make any difference.

Comment: @ModusTollens good comment. A -4 score was not expected though...Anyway!

Comment: I think it is not practical at all, consider what is "good" mean? Who to define? And how to prevent someone drops chatty comments everywhere to get the rewards?

Comment: @amuse yeah I got it, that's why I asked. I searched for dupes, couldn't find, asked here, got so many downvotes.. :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can earn hundreds of thousands of reputation points by churning out trivial regular expressions, date/time formatting strings and map/reduce/LINQ queries by the dozens a day. I won't blame you if you do, but it's not my cup of tea.

Why would one still bother trying to uphold some standard of quality, while in the time you type a comment explaining the problems with a post tens of people are undoing that work by posting answers to the most atrocious questions, even upvoting them to undo your downvote?

We don't need even more gamification. Just downvote and comment if you want to, don't expect yet another reward.

The only reward I need for commenting on bad posts is the delightful drama that follows without exception, at the off-chance that I *maybe* enlighten a soul about their bad practices.

Comment: Agreed. What's the point of casting that 3rd close vote on a bad question that already has two answers with one of them having a "thank you" comment of the OP and no up-votes/acceptance. And why should I invest 1 rep in this question? What will downvoting teach them? Sure, moderation is striving against the stream, but I ain't no swimming up that waterfall or even trying it.

Comment: @null *"And why should I invest 1 rep in this question?"* Either you mean "answer" not "question" or you mean "0 rep" not "1 rep" ;P.

Comment: *"The only reward I need for commenting on bad posts is the delightful drama that follows without exception"* The best drama is, when someone answers how bad SO is for new users and how arrogant we all are. Well and it is pretty annoying, too.

Comment: @Tom yes, my bad.

Comment: @null Which of the things was it? And no worries, typo happen :). Btw you can repost your first comment if you like, I'll delete my comment then.

Comment: @Tom both really (thinking and writing got mixed up): I doubt that a down-vote on either one will teach anything and on the answers, that comes at the additional cost of 1 rep. And down voting answers for "feeding the trolls" is very questionable to begin with, but I think it is happening. The bottom line is that it's often too late to apply any moderation actions for them to have a meaningful effect.

Comment: @null said closevote/downvote theoretically helps the system identify the quality of the posts said user is creating, possibly leading to stricter rate-limiting. Unfortunately this doesn't do anything about users *answering* bad questions.

Comment: [feature-request] ability to favourite an answer

Answer (score 33):

Let me tell you a tale. Long time ago, at a Q&A site far away...

...There was a user who observed that the vast majority of [poorly received questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mHqM.jpg) fall into few categories.

So that user made an effort and wrote several meta posts (that *Faraway Site* had a meta part just like here) explaining in much details what specifically is wrong with each of the identified categories of poor questions and how to improve these to make them a better fit for the site.

Meanwhile, another user noticed that meta posts written by the first one make a great match to many of the poor questions.

So that another user started posting comments referring askers of poor questions to the respective meta posts, explaining what's specifically wrong with the question and how to improve. And so it went for a while until it turned out that this makes some unhappy...

- Help vampires were unhappy because they discovered that their questions got quickly voted down and closed by readers who saw the comments (that *Faraway Site* had the notion of voting and closing, just like here). And they couldn't get the answers they were hoping for.
- Rep farmers were unhappy because they discovered that questions they wanted to dump their answers to get quickly voted down and closed by readers who saw the comments.

So these unhappy folks started complaining. "This user posted 100 comments telling that “Is it possible to…” is a poorly worded question; that's so rude!". "This user posted 200 comments telling that “Where to start” is not answerable; that's so snarky!"

- <sup>And there's one more thing you better know about this *Faraway Site*; they had a CEO. And that CEO had a belief that the more questions and answers the better, no matter what the quality. And CEO instructed the site team to keep askers and answerers happy no matter what, and the site team instructed moderators accordingly (that *Faraway Site* had moderators, just like here).</sup>

So complaints from help vampires and rep farmers piled on and on until one day moderators sent commenter users a *notice* asking them to abstain from doing what they do.

And there's one more thing you better know about this *Faraway Site*. The typical approach over there was that if a user doesn't comply with the notice they get suspended.

The End.

---

### Happy commenting!

Comment: So you _didn't_ like the Summer of Love?

Comment: @CodeCaster I _did_ like it... until I realised that [it doesn't work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore/281807#comment915375_281807), "how come that after years of plugging user's mouths and twisting their arms with summers of love and hunting the snark the second top question at MSO is 'Why is Stack Overflow so _negative_ of late?'"

Comment: @gnat well I've been trying to give some attention to it lately, and I _do_ still see an awful lot of snarky comments. I understand it is _hard_ to stay polite when you're shoving the fiftieth question of the day towards the close vote review queue, but that doesn't warrant calling the OP lazy or dumping comments like _"How is this even a real question?"_. We can (and I'd love to) get rid of such comments, but it won't solve much, because it's not just the language in them, but the fact that questions get closed that we get called negative...

Comment: @CodeCaster at that _Faraway Site_ (not here of course!) it was so that no matter how you wrap it, if you post many comments explaining the same thing over and over again, no matter how politely, there would be respectively many complaints and accusations of snark and rudeness, and these many complaints will be heard by powers that be. You seem to be taking this seriously, why, that's just a tale after all

Comment: I hear that, I've had several accusations thrown at me for just providing a link with more background information in a comment :/ If downvotes happen at the same time, you might as well not comment anything.

Comment: When users write **polite** comments telling what **specifically** is wrong with a question and how to improve I find it pretty unlikely they will get such a kind of notices by mods (at least, I cannot remember I got such one in the past, though I have written such comments pretty often over the years - not always polite at the beginning, but I tried to improve over the years)....

Comment: .. however, when I imagine I would have posted a lot of *precanned* comments, several of  them not specific enough to give askers the impression I had really read their question, I would not be astonished to get a notice from the mods sooner or later.

Comment: ... that does not mean precanned comments are useless or generally unhelful, however, I think one has to be very careful when using them. And when I have issue to find a polite tone for a comment which accompanies a close-vote like "needs details or clarity", I would probably refrain from voting until someone else adds such a comment to an unclear question, or until I have an idea for a better worded comment, or until I find a better close reason.

Comment: .. to give you an example: when a question is off-topic on an SE site, and the OP asks where they could post elseewhere, just using a precanned comment pointing them to one of those meta post listing >30 other sites with a lot of detail about each of the sites can be perceived as pretty unhelpful. Giving them a **specific** recommendation about one or two sites which may be a better fit for their specific question (together with that former link, as a "further reading" notice), will usually perceived way much friendlier.

Comment: @DocBrown this discussion is about folks who vote without any commenting at all. I am very well aware that voting this way is [less efficient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285253/839601 "'To ensure substantial impact of downvotes, one has to invest respectively substantial effort into explaining what's wrong with the post...'"), however I somehow don't feel an urge to convince them to write parsonalised 500-chars essays to every lazy asker who post off-topic stuff without even bothering to have a glance on positively received questions or on guidance in help center

Answer (score -13):

The system does not reward "good" downvoters. It actually discourages them to help the OP to improve.

It is because making it known (or even likely), that you voted a post down, can make you a target of revenge downvotes. It is particularly problematic in the case of questions, what you mostly can't delete, and the downvoter must not pay with his/her own rep for the downvote.

Furthermore, giving a comment to the OP requires extra effort, resulting that you can give lesser downs. **A fair solution would be to give a higher strength to the explained downs.** Considering the till-the-death resistance of the system against any improvements, it is unlikely that it will ever happen.

Thus, most of the given downvotes are unexplained and is coming from "bad" downvoters.

My personal experience is that in the ordinary usage of the site, I simply don't find so many bad posts which would deserve a downvote. My downvote ratio is about 1:6, i.e. I have about 6 times more ups than downs. If I give a downvote to an answer, the -1 rep loss is a no-issue to me.

*However, I don't search the site for downvotable posts.* Well, rarely, for particularly annoying things, but it is not a habit for me.

There are tags, mostly the first "language" of beginner programmers today, which attract the bad posts. If someone is active (specialized to) one of them, it is believable that (s)he needs to meet an above average ratio of downvotable content even with ordinary site usage.

But if not, then imho the only reason to have a high down/up ratio, if someone looks for posts to vote them down.

**This is obviously not someone who wants to find answers to his/her questions. This is someone who wants to vote posts down. The system embraces this attitude, particularly if they never give a feedback and focus for questions.**

Comment: In that last paragraph, are you trying to set yourself as an example? LOL.

Comment: @rene I try to argument that the ordinary usage of the site simply does not lead to so many downvotable posts. I think a better argument would be to say, that it is because you have already eliminated them.

Comment: Pointing out the obvious: Especially that last paragraph here is utter nonsense. Get active in JavaScript and you'll find a metric tonne of bad, hastily written, or plain _wrong_ answers. They typically outnumber the good ones. (You also might wanna change your username. [That user _left_ SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/203057)).

Comment: @Cerbrus Our tag distribution hugely differs, and I think it is quite possible that crap focuses to specific technologies popular in very newbie circles. I rethink my this view and tune the post. But, although you give far more downs than ups, you vote more to answers (4500) than questions (3800). And you vote little, compared to your reputation. I've seen here users who voted 1/7 of a whole site down, with lesser than 200 rep. I think you are not so bad guy.

Comment: I used to explain every vote I issued and at some point people started to call those responses rude.  In an effort not to be seen as rude, I then started to copy canned responses, but eventually somebody ended up calling those responses rude.  At some point in the process, people with reputation at Stack Overflow would serially downvote my own contributions, whenever I submitted a response on a specific community.  I had to hide all my other communities to avoid that behavior.  *Turns out the only way not to be rude in the eyes of these users is to upvote their low quality submissions.*

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica - I am sure this is a language problem, but referring to anyone as a "bad guy", is not nice.  *Best to keep cultural references like "you are not such a bad guy" to a minimum.*

Comment: @SecurityHound I wanted to edit it out from the post, but it was unfortunately in a comment. Btw, imho searching posts to vote them down is worser.

Comment: @Cerbrus I reformulated the post. Not because I would hope a score signature change :-), but because I believe you are right.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica - I personally think the ratio of upvotes to downvotes only provides a snapshot into what actually happens.  There are review queues with extremely bad contributions.  For instance my ratio of downvotes to upvotes might suggest I downvote a lot of content, but most of the contributions I vote on, end up being deleted.

Comment: @SecurityHound I admit that someone might focus to technologies with a huge amount of crap content. These are the technologies most used by beginner programmers today, whose large part has problems to ask correctly, or they are not accustomed to the not always very meaningful rules of the system, or they in general problem with the communication is written form.

Comment: @SecurityHound I believe, today these techs are python, javascript and php. In these cases, I admit that these people wanting high-quality content, even with these technologies, might experience a strongly below average site quality. But the first-posts queue is not to vote everybody down. It is to help newbies. Giving daily 40 silent downs in the FPQ is imho destructive.

Comment: @peterh - But those votes are followed by close votes normally

Comment: @SecurityHound FPQ (and late answers) are for edits, comments, flags. Contrary the other queues, you can also vote in them, if you wish to. But, if you only vote in the FPQ, it is allowed but officially discouraged. I could dig out a link for it.