# Should we ban link only comments to idownvotedbecau.se?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes

I've seen 2 link-only comments that point to different pages on idownvotedbecau.se in the last day. These aren't helpful/constructive. I know comments are supposed to be treated temporarily, but the links could go dead. We should have enough onsite information.

We already ban LMGTFY links, so why not ban idownvotedbecau.se as well?

Comment: I'm not quite in favor of idownvotedbecau.se, but I also don't see any particular harm done by adding such comments. The comment should just help op to improve the question and should then be deleted, so the link rotting argument doesn't really count here (imho).

Comment: "but the links could go dead" ... That's surely a big issue when OP wants to visit their question after 5 years to check for feedback for the first time.

Comment: Related: [Is idownvotedbecau.se recommended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended)

Comment: Suppressing speech is certainly one of the most pointless endeavors that any web site owner can get involved in.  People will always, always find a workaround.  Do it over and over again and it *will* end badly, forcing the application of ever bigger weapons.  Get used to it, be happy with one that does as little damage as can reasonably be expected.

Comment: idownvotedbecau.se was registered last May and it was discussed at the end of August (probably leading to greater exposure and therefore heavier usage). I'd be interested to see if the CMs have a more fine-tuned understanding now.

Comment: @HansPassant So you're saying that we should just get rid of every single rule on the site, and turn SO into Yahoo Answers because enforcing rules about what is and is not appropriate is pointless and harmful?  That's obviously absurd.  SO is built on the premise of having high quality standards for content, and having lots of moderation tools to enforce them.  Yes, they're imperfect, and not all content that violates the rules is always removed, but much of it is, and the site is better as a result of what *can* be done.

Comment: I will point out that these kinds of comments are generating a large number of comment flags (I just handled two in the last few minutes). The content is much less insulting than LMGTFY, but many people aren't seeing these as being polite. I like [Jon's take on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356051/19679), where he recommends providing more than just a link, but I'm not sure if this is getting to ban-worthy levels yet.

Comment: ^^^ comment flags:(    Users who don't get immediate responses and total servitude WILL flag you as rude and abusive, (even if their question is far worse).  Just downvote them and leave no comment - it's safer.

Comment: Considering the vote spread along this question and its answers, I'd say that the use of these links is _divisive_ at least. One could imagine that reception of these comments will be similarly divided, if not worse (since the comment is accompanied with a downvote, and bit more personal than it is here).

Comment: this reminds me an [old tale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335707/839601), "Help vampires were unhappy because they discovered that their questions get quickly voted down and closed by readers who saw the comments... And they couldn't get the answers they were hoping for. Rep whores were unhappy because they discovered that questions they wanted to dump their answers to get quickly voted down and closed by readers who saw the comments..."

Comment: @AndrewMyers it has been around for years, the name was just recently changed from "idownvotedyoubecause" to "idownvotedbecause" because Will didn't want to spread the idea that we are downvoting people, but rather content. It wasnt until that change that everyone started having a problem, which is honestly hilarious.

Comment: @TinyGiant It wasn't until after that change that people started using the site more frequently, which is when people started having a problem with it.  The blowback to the site is a direct result of its increased use, not that name change.  People don't complain about sites and comments that they've never seen or heard of.

Comment: The data disagrees with you Tiny. In a search of the comments available in SEDE, there are only 7 undeleted comments with "idownvotedyoubecause": [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/777433/old-idownvotedyoubecause?CommentLength=100&CreationDate=6000) Compare that to the 300+ from the query in my [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361377/189134) from just the last 30 days which contain the new shortened version.

Comment: @Andy something is off there, I know for that I've seen more than 7, so something else must be affecting the result.

Comment: @AndrewMyers It's a dupe.

Answer (score 17):

[I completely agree with you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357717/189134). I hate seeing these links. I hate seeing them as I browse Stack Overflow and I hate them even more when they are flagged. I *especially* hate the comments that are [just a link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/747700/downvoted-because). In the past 30 days(ish), there have been 300+ comments that were not flagged that consist of

```
http://idownvotedbecau.se/<LINK>
```

Except for that one that managed to sneak in a "what stops you from trying?" at the end.

Another [50ish comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/774508/downvoted-because-anywhere-in-comment) managed to add a small amount of text around the link. Most of those consist of wrapping the link in text and summarizing the slug of the URL.

---

These links are useful for an extremely short period of time. After the asker reads them, there isn't any use left. The asker can either take the advice or not. In either case, what purpose does it serve to any other user on the site?

A link to a full page or more of text is condescending. There are much better ways to say a user needs to use a debugger or they shouldn't post an image of code. I've mentioned this before:

> Most users don't read the assistance they are given when asking their first question, they don't read the yellow or red warnings they are presented with, they don't read anything more than they need to to find the button to post a question. Why would presenting them with a full page of text on why you downvoted be any different?

I mentioned that [I delete these comments on sight](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357717/189134). If I have time to find them while browsing or via the flag queue, there has been enough time for the original poster to see them.

Comment: *ᴺᵉᵉᵈˢ ᶜˡᵃʳᶦᶠᶦᶜᵃᵗᶦᵒⁿ* "A link to a full page or more of text is condescending." Does that go for the official Help pages as well? There are even official shortcuts to a few frequently asked (which I always forget, they are not *that* intuitive – and they *all* insert the unhelpful text "the help center").

Comment: @usr2564301 I reckon that if you use links to the help center to explain your down-votes, and little else, it can also be perceived as condescending.

Comment: [Short links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) each have different text. One of them expands to "help center". If all you are providing in your comment is a short link, then yes it is condescending. If, however, you are providing context around your link (either the short link or to why you downvoted) then it is more helpful.

Comment: I think that more of those users would read (even if you only read one line) the external page cause it doesn't look official and it starts interesting. I love to put the idownvotedcou.se links like i said in this thread: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361475/7571526 and for me its no effort to write those comments, I got the autoreviewcomments plugin.

Answer (score 15):

I think idownvotedbecau.se is good as a supplemental resource, but I don't think it's very effective as a link-only comment.

*idownvotedbecau.se is not a suitable substitute for actual communication because:*

- **The OP might not understand why his post matches the downvote criteria:**  Some of them are subjective, and not all of them necessarily apply to all questions(especially questions that are not asking you to fix a bug in their code).  Furthermore, many question askers are beginner programmers, and you can't necessarily expect them to intuitively understand all the things you intuitively understand.
- **It may actually be *You* who is wrong:**  Maybe you misread something, or maybe you misunderstood the context, and the down vote reason you thought applied really doesn't.  If that's the case, the OP won't be able to suitably reply to you because they don't know which reason you downvoted for, because that reason doesn't actually apply to their post.
- **Lazy people will use it incorrectly:**  This use to be the problem with "what have you tried"-only comments.  People would just post "what have you tried" without understanding the context and often in times where knowing what the OP has tried isn't useful.  I expect idownvotedbecau.se to be no different.  Trendy one-liners like that, and "What have you tried" give lazy commenters the ability to be even lazier.

Because of this, I agree that link-only comments to idownvotedbecau.se are bad.

Comment: Do you have a personally preferred alternative? Giving a down-vote is *less* communicating. A close vote reason becomes only visible to the poster after a succesful close (IIRC), and only the most-voted reason is listed (again, if memory serves).

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, actual communication.  Tell the OP why you downvoted.

Comment: @usr2564301  Secondly, No communication at all is often better than bad communication.

Comment: I completely disagree with every point made here. Have you even read the site we're talking about?

Comment: @SamIam By "the site" Tiny means idownvotedbecau.se, not SO.

Comment: That seems like a deilberate misinterpretation of what I said. The site we are talking about is idownvotedbecau.se. So you've been there for 6 years eh?

Comment: @TinyGiant  In that case, yes, I've been to idownvotedbecau.se.  Again, tell me what you're taking about.

Comment: Im sorry I just dont see how you could possibly draw the conclusions you've drawn from the situation and site under discussion. It just doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: @TinyGiant Again, why not?  I've read the site, and it hasn't changed my opinion.  I've explained why I thought each point applies in the original post.

Comment: None of the reasons are on the same page as other reasons (an obvious indicator that you didnt read the target site), which invalidates the only real problem you identified (#1) the rest are people problems, and those can occur with pretty well any interaction whatsoever. I mean, should we remove close voting because people are closing reasonable questions like it is going out of style?

Comment: Hell, even close reasons aren't really all that helpful in specific cases, so we should just go ahead and remove those right? Just close everything, and not tell anyone why.

Comment: @TinyGiant  Okay, I do suppose that I got too fixated on link-only answers to "Idownvotedbecau.se", but I strongly disagree with you that use of it doesn't have an effect on the people-problems.  Some actual communication can go a long way toward alleviating these people problems.

Comment: @TinyGiant  On that note, did you know that the system automatically flags the moderators when a question is closed with no comments on it?

Comment: The more likely alternative is no communication at all. There are many reasonable reasons to not comment at all, and that is very unhelpful to the OP. Yeah, it would be nice if people left comments that were more helpful, but ultimately less helpful than what is happening now is not more helpful, ever.

Comment: Re: auto-flags, I'm fairly certain that I did know that, but they have little to no effect.

Comment: @TinyGiant The OP has *already* been presented with all of the information in that link, and if their question is closed, they're linked to that same information again in the close reason.  Repeating that same information *again* isn't helping the OP any more than doing nothing, as the system has already done that *multiple* times.  The people who are receptive to that information and would benefit from it, are given it, and have the tools to act accordingly.  Those that don't care, won't care just because you posted the same information *again*.

Comment: @TinyGiant. Is there any real, statistical evidence that shows that these links are significantly more effective than down/close voting and/or posting *specific* comments? In my experience, engaging directly with the OP is often the only effective way to get them to improve their question. If they won't do that, posting links to generic help pages is seems utterly pointless.

Comment: @ekhumoro I did not at any point assert that these links are more effective than any of those things. I said that they are more effective than doing nothing at all, which is fairly self-evident.

Comment: I'd say "What have you tried?" is a passive-aggressive way of saying "Don't ask a question before even trying to find a solution yourself"

Comment: @DavidStockinger: no, it is mostly perceived as such by askers who "just need the code, can u halp plz". Do you have an alternative wording for inquiring the specific amount of effort that has been spended prior to asking?

Comment: @usr2564301 I don't necessarily think it's a bad thing. Nothing pisses me off more than lazy people who don't even bother to google something, or who just write "I want to do X, code plz?"

Answer (score 7):

LMGTFY is a dig at the author. You're saying

> Here's a Google result, since you were too lazy to check here first

That's not helpful, and results are likely to change over time.

idownvotedbecau.se is meant to be helpful to the author. If the link goes dead, it's already done its work (in theory anyways). In some ways, just downvoting without any comment is far worse, as the author has no chance to improve.

Comment: _In some ways, just downvoting without any comment is far worse, as the author has no chance to improve._ Why not? By not having a comment detailing the perceived problem any possibility of critical thought is extinguished in the original poster?

Comment: @yivi: it is ever so more specific than "this question is not useful / not researched".

Comment: There's nothing in idownvotedbecau.se that's not already readily available in the help center.  Anyone *actually* trying to improve their post can already see everything that that link has to provide just by reading the help center and SO's FAQs.  It's not actually helping people improve their questions any, it's only there to make the person posting the comment feel better.

Comment: @yivi I'm not sure I understand. If I downvote, and I think the author can improve, a canned comment (which is all that link is really) can potentially help them improve. You're imparting some sinister motivation implying it's meant to "extinguish critical thought".

Comment: @usr2564301, yes; but I'm contesting to the line that says "_the author has no chance to improve"_

Comment: I see. Maybe change that wording to ".. has no *idea* on what to improve"? As idownvotedbecause/*reason* gives OP an idea for what to look at.

Comment: @usr2564301 Almost all of the reasons correspond to a close reason, which will already provide an even better explanation of what's wrong and how to fix it than that link does.  And if you *really* want to post a comment with the same information anyway, you can just link to the help center, which has the same information (which the OP already was shown, and chose to ignore before, hence why repeating the information again isn't really helping the author any more than the site already has).

Answer (score 4):

As a moderator, I have access to deleted/flagged comments and I think I can answer:

Check this flag:

```
https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/
No Longer Needed by: some_user - Helpful
Robot Says Unfriendly by: Community♦ - Helpful
Deleted: 1d ago by: some_user
```

As you see, "some_user" (real name hidden) has flagged this comment as "no longer needed", and the deletion was automatic (no moderator intervention). Also note that "Robot" detected that as unfriendly, which clearly means that this link is now in the same category as lmgfy-type links.

Okay, so maybe it's just noise, but some other user got two "rude/unwelcoming" flags in a row because of that, also with auto-deletion:

```
The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. Stack&nbsp;Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].
Rude Or Offensive by: zzzzzz - Helpful
Deleted: 6h ago by: zzzzzz
```

Twice a user flagged as "rude" or "unfriendly", and this same user triggered the autodeletion of the flag and auto-acceptance.

This comment is perfectly professional with standard links to the Stack Overflow help center. Only the link is "suspicious".

I have warned this user in a moderator private message (without penalty of course)

> Should we ban link only comments to idownvotedbecau.se?

So I'm not in the secret of the "offensive" word list (beside the obvious F-word like insults), but users should be aware that this link is no longer welcome *even if not alone in a helpful comment* as shown above (things have evolved since I had given a mixed opinion about that site in an earlier answer to this question: *[Is idownvotedbecau.se recommended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended)*)

Well, keep using it at your own risk. If someone flags those comments, the moderators don't even get to decline the flag.

Comment: It's likely after Tim Post's answer on the question you linked. I noticed I nuked one a while ago with a single flag, but I wasn't sure if it was Shog's Magic Regex™ or if there happened to be another flag on there. I'm guessing flagging as rude is the right action too if this is actually implemented.

Comment: Tim Post just states that the link only answer is rude. But there the regex for sure, as the long and polite comment was also auto-nuked.

Comment: @Zoe I think we need a Shog's Magic Reprex™ to debug why the long and polite comment was also auto-nuked ;)

Answer (score -5):

**The close reasons that we use are not as helpful as they could be**, and in many situations they are not helpful for the OP at all. They are regularly seen as condescending by OP's everywhere. They are misused on a regular basis by well meaning but uneducated users to close reasonable questions. This does not mean that we should remove the close reasons.

These links—even as bare links—*are* helpful, and they are not in any way condescending even though they may be seen that way by some people (that is not the fault of the link). In fact, they stand to be more helpful than the close reasons we use *even though they serve a different purpose* (close reasons are for close votes, downvote reasons are for downvotes). Why are they helpful? **Because they *are* communication.**

See we communicate through many different channels, whether that be through voting, editing, close voting, commenting, what have you. When someone leaves a comment containing a link to a downvote reason on idownvotedbecau.se, they are providing the OP with *their* reasoning; and it is *OK* if the commenter is wrong. We are all wrong every now and again; and if we leave a comment with our reasoning (even if that is just a link to our reasoning), it gives something for the OP (and others) to reason with. It gives the OP a point where they can explain why the commenter is wrong, or address the reason for the downvote if it is correct.

**The alternative usually tends towards less useful communication.** Due to the nature of communication on the internet, summarizing the information at the end of the link and putting it in a comment directly (or even just explaining in your own words why you're downvoting) often leads to arguments, flaming, and generally negative interactions. This means that the most likely alternative for communication in these situations if idownvotedbecau.se were to be banned would be no comment at all, and just a downvote (and possibly a close vote); all of which is highly unhelpful for the OP.

### Less useful is never more useful

In summary: This is not a problem that can be solved with less communication, and just because something isn't as useful as something else, does not mean the former should be banned outright.

Comment: [x] Agree [ ] Like [ ] Disagree [ ] Insightful [ ] Flag

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se