# Should we display a warning when users include images?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, ssl

I've spent some time in the *Triage* and *First Post* review queues and I keep seeing users who include or link to screenshots of their code and/or exceptions and error messages. This is generally considered **bad practice**.

As I see it, images are meant to be included when *visual aspects* of something adds value to the question. A question like "Why does this visual glitch appear on my Android phone, but not on the emulator?" would surely benefit from an image, given the visual nature of the question.

Other questions, where images are only added to display text, should **not** be included. Instead, the text itself should be copy/pasted by the author.

As such, I recommend the following warning to be displayed when the user attempts to upload an image:

> Please only include images in your question if the visual appearance of something is relevant. **Do not** use images to show text - instead use the *Code Sample* or *Snippet* tool to display code or error messages.

Comment: IMHO there's no point in doing this; users who post screenshots of their code without merit are unlikely to read any messages warning them about doing it.

Comment: If you are presented with a big, red message saying "Stop! What you are doing is wrong!" then I think people will listen. Likewise, if we subscribe to the idea that help messages are useless because users don't read them, why is there a help section anyways?

Comment: @cybermonkey: to add insult to injury, those questions **still** get answers; the OP is fully satisfied and doesn't bother to fix it.

Comment: related: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/839601)

Comment: Make the warning red, full-screen and blinking, and play a loud alarm siren sound below it. If we put the user in enough shock, then _maybe_ they won't click past the warning without thought. :P

Comment: @Siguza this would take 6-8 weeks...

Comment: I commented on a question recently asking the poster to please not post code as images and he's like "its only two lines of code, I don't see why I have to include it as text."

Comment: @Draco18s "Because if you want me to run this code, then I need to either type it from your image, or copy/paste it from your question. And you are the one asking me for a favour, not vice versa"

Comment: @DavidStockinger That's [exactly what I told him](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48102528/1663383). :P The post has since been updated (with actually helpful images!)

Comment: there is a problem with the word "text" in my opinion. Rather it should be source code. One such use case where images are very useful, although it has nothing to do with visual appearance, is when the user needs to paste a snippet of the log messages of the error, but the errors are not immediately available in the text form ( situations in run time error )

Comment: I usually DV or CV for "unclear what you're asking" and use this link: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: we could add a super OCR feature which looks in the text for common language keywords and prevents from posting. Well, that or downvote & vote to close :)

Comment: @infoclogged Images are fine if no better source of information is available. Although I would still encourage OP to transcribe it before posting.

Comment: @DavidStockinger hence -  "meant to be included if no better source of information in text form is available  or when visual aspects of something adds value to the existing text" is much clearer.

Comment: As @gnat noted, we [already implemented this two years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors/307500#307500)... Funny story though: turns out we completely broke it during the HTTPS migration, and so no one has seen it in well over a year.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Perhaps a more in your face "Don't do this" would work with the image upload dialog:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<sup>Ps this is only a semi-serious suggestion, as I doubt even something this drastic would make any difference if it could be done.</sup>

Comment: This, plus three different checkboxes that say "this is not an image of data/errors/code" that we'd need to check. The text could change between attempts so the requirement of checking/unchecking would be different each time... :P

Comment: Oh look, an image that adds value to an answer due to its visuals and not code, data or errors.

Comment: -1. You *seriously* think this will work? there are **ZERO** Free Hand circles here

Comment: +1 there's THREE free hand circles

Comment: I am fairly certain that the offenders in question will assume that these are examples of the types of images which we would like them to post.

Comment: cant even count anymore, dangerous picture. there are actually five free hand circles...

Comment: @SampoSarrala 3? I count 5. (N**o** err**o**rs plz, N**o** c**o**de plz, and N**o** data plz)

Comment: Tanner you made my day. Funny _and_ extremely useful at the same time, with minor changes for the site (so expect the change in 6 or 8 weeks as usual)

Comment: Also no tables plz. And if a table is input or output then per MCVE it should be formatted as code & a table.

Comment: @JF If you count the `d`s, there's seven. The `a`s might also count. `e`s are kind of "circle-adjacent."

Comment: Btw. I never noticed the editor image upload function xD

Comment: This has not yet been implemented. Why not? It seems such a little thing to change.

Comment: @usr2564301 just because this is marked as the answer doesn't mean it will be implemented. It's unlikely that the team would actually implement this in the way it's presented, but they could implement something that carries the same message. First they have to acknowledge the problem and actually consider making a change.

Comment: @Tanner: I only asked because I've seen about 15 to 20 hit-and-run questions posting code-images these last 4 days. They sure seem to take their time acknowledging the problem. Oh well, maybe it will take the usual 4-6 weeks.

Answer (score 25):

As gnat noted, [we already had a warning for this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors/307500#307500) - we just broke it a year ago and never noticed.

Adam Lear fixed this 10 days ago, and I'm happy to report that it's once again in the face of any user with <= 15 reputation attempting to upload an image:

[image: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.]

Comment: *any user with <= 15 reputation* Would it be worth it to have a feature request raising that number? I regularly see users with way more reputation making edits solely to add screenshots of text to questions in the suggested edit queue.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to propose, @bsmp

Comment: @Shog9 would a [visual hint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475) make it clearer for the folks that don't like to read help text?!

Comment: Honestly, @Tanner, this is probably one of those situations where if we want to do better than a text warning we have to dig into *why* anyone wants to do this to begin with. My gut feeling is that we both do not make it obvious how to paste in code *and* make it difficult to format code effectively - essentially the same reason you've probably had folks send you screenshots wrapped in a Word doc. You can throw up all the warnings you want but until we find a way to address the underlying cause, it's gonna keep happening.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think the users<sup>1</sup> would read this warning message because they **don't read** any of the **help pages** or the help text on the right side.

<sup>1</sup>*The users who are posting in wrong format etc.*

If a user is posting his code or error message as an image, I'm writing a comment with one of these two links which explain pretty good **why you shouldn't do this**:

http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

---

How to implement **idownvotedbecau.se** right:

> #### [Q] Not a good question
>
> Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask)"**

The Code:

```
Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask)"**
```

Comment: Be aware that these specific comment links are rather controversial, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361364/should-we-ban-link-only-comments-to-idownvotedbecau-se. I also find it rather ironic that given your low opinion on how well people read the help pages that you expect them to read the linked page instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The most time on SO I'm editing questions which are badly formatted and that's why I'm thinking so. And they will click on the link and read minimum the headline because its looking interesting (downvotecou.se).

Comment: @MartijnPieters and for the nice comments with only the link, please consider using a plugin to auto paste a nice sentence with the link included :)

Comment: Side note: I don’t disagree. Many people don’t read the help info. I doubt that they’ll read the linked info instead. At least, not when presented as a bare link like that. See the answer by Jon Ericson at the first link.

Comment: I already use a plugin *and* a text expander app for my comment management. Life as a moderator is so much easier that way.

Comment: @yivi It's more likely a metaphor for the developer's forum. And it looks nice ;) But i wouldn't do that in an edit

Comment: @MartijnPieters The most comment I'm using is the one I have inserted in the answer. I think it's a good way to implement the idownvotedbecou.se link.

Comment: I do think that *proactively* telling people that a screenshot of code is not a good idea will reduce the likelihood the  community is tasked with educating the OP with comments and downvotes. That is probably a better experience for the asker.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's exactly what I mean. I'd argue that a lot of people don't actively read the rules *and ignore them*, but rather are not really aware that what they are doing is problematic.

Comment: Because they **do** get answers. After that, then why bother? I'd rather see an immediate *[on hold]* as soon as someone spots this.

Comment: when I first started using SE sites it was not that easy to find help/faq pages (even if links were on some corner, lots of buttons for n00b), however I did read read all messages when posting stuff. I wont click on links when I'm writing post, all info must be there. On some sites you'll lose content when clicking links and this behavior has taught me not to do that, I believe many have similar habit.

Comment: I was passively browsing this post. I rarely click links on SO, since I generally come here for an answer. That said, the domain name was intriguing. I clicked it. I think it’s actually wayyyy more effective than the SO docs. When I was new, all I wanted to know was WHY I was being downvoted. I didn’t want to browse “how to” doc for posting questions, I’d rather learn based on feedback and results. The link provides the user feedback. Good stuff.

Comment: The text in the links of this answer are very poorly worded and hard to read. The idea has merit, but I couldn't even follow what was being said in the first one because the first person plural subject made no sense. The wording felt very passive aggressive to me.

Answer (score -20):

I completely agree with you. But what if there are certain circumstances that do not allow them to copy paste the text and it'll much much easier for them to just show us a screenshot, how will we allow for these exceptions? 
Maybe provide some sort of warning that tells them not to but not a rule that stops them from doing it.

Comment: How many programming IDE's have MsgBox with Ctrl+C disabled? I saw a guy this morning copy the HTML source of the error and use that. Its bad practice and so rare I'd expect people to type it out if Ctrl+C is disabled. **Its crazy to expect people to do Image Searches of Error Images.**

Comment: I don't see anyone proposing "make it impossible to attach images". The question specifically mentions some scenarios where images are welcome and even necessary. If we didn't want users to post images, it would be very easy to require a higher amount of reputation before allowing them to do that, but I think we all agree that this is too draconian and user-hostile.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Emacs has Ctrl+C disabled. Instead it uses Meta+W.