# Raise / Remove reputation limit for showing "Do not upload code screenshots" message

Tags: feature-request, images, tooltips

As a result from the feature request [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) about 2.67 years ago, a message has been added to the image uploader warning users not to use them as a means to add code to the post, see this [meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/5389131).

However, this feature is only active for users with **15 reputation and below**, while users below 10 rep simply cannot post images at all.

I have no stats on the result of this measure, but from personal experience the practice of **code screenshots** is still highly prevalent.

**Side note:** The feature was *temporarily broken* and only [reintroduced this February](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363442/5389131).
To my knowledge the reputation limit remains the same, though.

I propose to either **substantially raise** or **remove** this reputation limit entirely, as the message is currently displayed for hardly anybody and its effect thereby massively stifled.

Comment: Perhaps make it the same as the comment/answer limit - 50?

Comment: ["Hardly anybody" you say?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/851670)

Comment: @Paulie_D From my understanding the message is currently not even a [in-your-face popup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/5389131), as others want it to be. If it was, a limit of 50 reputation would do. Personally, I do not see any major drawback from removing the limit entirely if the message is just additional text displayed in the uploader.

Comment: @Makoto Shouldn't it be [between 10 and 15 reputation](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/851675/users-able-to-see-do-not-post-code-screenshots-message-in-image-uploader)? That would amount to 422k users. Arguably a lot, but as soon as you left this rep bracket you lost your chance to encounter the message **ever again**.

Comment: Correction: Users under 10 rep cannot embed images. They can still upload them and add them to the post, but it can't be embedded

Comment: This doesn't nearly go wrong as often as it could, at least in the tags I visit.  I find it kinda useful, saves me a lot of time.  One of the best question quality indicators I know.

Comment: @Zoe True. Unfortunately, users with more reputation will embed text images into the post for them. I used to try to Reject these when they were suggested edits but I gave up and started Skipping instead because the edit was always either Approved by other reviewers or the image(s) got added by a user with over 2K rep anyway.

Comment: @Makoto As users below 10 rep can't upload images at all, the number of users that actually see the message is (compared to the other numbers) "hardly anybody" as you can see in this [modified query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/851722/1051657)

Comment: Okay; I stand corrected.

Comment: @cryophoenix It absolutely does matter how the code is presented.  Screen readers can't read it, search engines can't read it, and potential answerers can't copy/paste it to easily test it, among other things.  And SO has built-in syntax highlighting anyway.

Comment: @Makoto Actually, you were correct first. Mischa is incorrect; all users can *upload* images, but only 10+ rep users can *embed* images (<10 rep users can just link the uploaded images, and I believe it counts as one of the 8 links).

Comment: @Mischa Please read the above comment.

Comment: @Makoto your query for the qualified number of users is correct, but I would filter it for users with at least one post: if you've never posted then you're not concerned by the visibility of this banner. And I would filter it for accounts active after the feature (Oct 6 '15). I tried to query it, but I'm not very good at SQL, so my query is likely wrong but here it is: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/851843/users-by-rep-lastaccessdate-and-posts

Comment: Also note that users that come from another SE site get 100 rep with their packet of corn flakes. Which doesn't necessarily mean that they are aware of SO-specific rules and culture.

Comment: @Makoto [Here is one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/852388/10-to-15-rep-users) **including 10 to 15 only**.

Comment: People with reputation <= 15 is approximate 4.5% of users. If the limit increase to 200 or 500 this grows to more than 91% of users. So I think something between 200 and 500 should be the limit.

Comment: FWIW, I saw a question in the Python tag less than an hour ago that was basically a code dump with "it doesn't work" as the accompanying text, and the code was an image (of just the code no error messages). The question received several comments telling the OP to fix their post, including a link to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) as well as a `idownvotedbecau.se` link. The post got a flurry of downvotes and was put on hold (no MCVE) before the OP had a chance to respond.

Comment: (cont) But amazingly, they _did_ post the actual code, although not in a code block, but that was easy to fix. And once I could load the code into my editor the typos that were the actual cause of their problem were easy to find. (Of course, there's no point voting to re-open a typo question).

Comment: On a related note, it annoys me when well-meaning editors convert code image links to embedded images, it's even more annoying when that's done by a low-rep user, so 3 reviewers have approved the edit. :( I sometimes comment to the editor saying, "I know you're trying to be helpful, but that doesn't actually help" and link them to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @Makoto - Perhaps the more relevant stat would be [how many questions posted by users < 15 vs. >= 15](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/852401/questions-in-last-year-by-users-below-15-vs-at-or-above). I limited that to the last year. It's about 1:2 (e.g., < 15s count for about half as many as the >= 15s). It's horribly skewed, of course, because the user's rep may have increased since posting the question...

Comment: I would like to see consideration of 100 limit - since that does have total  reputation context if they know how to do that likely they have also read some before posting..

Comment: It's not like the banner is even annoying for people who doesn't need them, so I don't really see the point of removing it for users with enough rep.

Answer (score 59):

To illustrate what we're talking about, it's the yellow banner visible on this capture, only for people with **less than 15 reputation**:
[image]

And yes, this banner has likely not been noticed enough when you get above 15 reputation, so the reputation limit to keep seeing it should be increased.

For a start, **I would at least raise it to a 200 reputation cap**, similar to the [Reduce Ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).

Comment: You could also change the color of the text to make it more visible.

Comment: Or change the backdrop to red, to make it even more in your face

Comment: Red background and white text would meet accessibility standards and be very much in your face.

Comment: We need to bring back `<blink>` and `<marquee>` for this one...

Comment: Well... that's misleading.  `If you post images of code...` - NO, this should say `Do not post images of code!`.

Comment: @J...: I broadly agree, but sometimes images of a error pop-up in an IDE can be useful.

Comment: @halfer You can always copy the text of any error message.  It's only useful as an image as a last resort - ie : OP was lazy and posted a picture and that's all you have to work with (which is how we got here in the first place).   If they have the presence of mind to understand that it is important to show the error then they can also just hit CTRL+C and paste the text directly.

Comment: @gparyani I disagree. Red should be reserved when we know there is an issue, not when it's possible there's an issue.

Comment: @Goose Didn't say it should be red, just said it should be a different color.

Comment: @J...: we are probably in more agreement than you think - I'm all in favour of combatting lazy screenshots `:-)`. However, there are some cases where the syntax error underlining means that sometimes an image does carry more useful information that the transcribed text.

Comment: @halfer If people are asking questions here with big red underlines showing them where their problem is, which they are ignoring, they can hand in their keyboards and go home. ;P

Comment: Another excuse that's sometimes offered is that the OP doesn't know how to copy & paste stuff from a Windows terminal. Ok, it might not be straight-forward, and I suppose most Windows users don't spend a lot of time in the terminal, but it's not that hard to find out how to do it.

Comment: Gold text on Yellow background? Blue or Black text would be better IMHO.

Comment: @gparyani ah, your right. I guess I was really trying to reply to the rest of the people in the comments that replied to you suggesting red.

Answer (score -19):

I disagree with this, because users with less than 10 rep can still upload images to the SE Imgur account; they just can't embed the images (they have to link them). So the rationale given in the question (that it's "only shown to users with 10-14 rep") isn't true.

In triage review, I frequently get questions where users have put in a link to a code screenshot, that are posted by <10 rep users. There just aren't really that many for users with 15+ reputation for me to support increasing the limit for it.

Comment: (ask for triage advice: what would you do with those?)

Comment: @user202729 Unsalvageable, close as off-topic