# Can the editor have a dialog for adding code?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

Regarding screenshots of code, [Shog9 said this back in February](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/363442#comment559604_363442):

> Honestly, @Tanner, this is probably one of those situations where if we want to do better than a text warning we have to dig into *why* anyone wants to do this to begin with. My gut feeling is that we both do not make it obvious how to paste in code and **make it difficult to format code effectively** - essentially the same reason you've probably had folks send you screenshots wrapped in a Word doc. You can throw up all the warnings you want but until we find a way to address the underlying cause, it's gonna keep happening.

But people using the Stack Snippets don't have this problem. They might still have weird indentation if they don't make use of the Tidy option, but it still gets formatted as code because the site is doing it for them.

Can we get a generic code formatter for the editor? It would be like the one for Stack Snippets except there's only one input area and the only options would be Reset, Cancel, and Save & Insert Into Post.

I think this would help reduce the frequency of screenshots of code as well as posts with broken code formatting.

Comment: I agree with this, but even adding support for [fenced code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks) would make code formatting much, much easier for everybody. New users and old hands alike. That is part of the newer markdown standards, has been proposed and is supposedly in the plans since forever; but its time never seems to come.

Comment: @yivi yup. I agree. I've always been in support of triple backtick code blocks, IMO the indent setup combined with SO's rather skinny page design (which doesn't take up my whole widescreen monitor) makes editing and pasting code rather difficult; I avoid making edits to code online, it feels like a very fragile system and I've learned to always copy all of the text into a text editor before messing with it. Also this might be a daydream but having some kind of rudimentary builtin online IDE with basic language knowledge might be interesting and might help askers with debugging/MVCEs?

Comment: I thought triple backtick is already implemented?

Comment: @justhalf no it just looks that way. The first two and the last two cancel each other out, leaving one on either side of the code block. This leaves you with the janky single line style comment split over multiple lines with little white gaps between the lines.

Comment: Can I upvote a question more than once? SO needs this feature, yesterday.

Comment: I agree. I always wondered why a few other sites I've been to and seen out there,  have a box to drop code into which gets automatically formatted and Stack doesn't. I've lost count as to how many times I (and others) had to indent code for those who don't know how the editor works; it's long overdue.

Comment: I frequently get into alignment error warnings. Code copy past from editors like VS Code, Brackets, or Notepad++ should be compatible. As adding spaces on every line seems laboriously time consuming. This helps not just answer seekers but also one who is providing answers as well.

Comment: @TinyGiant Actually, multiple consecutive backticks are treated as a delimiter (proof: you can use 2 backticks to format code) Still single-line code, however.

Comment: Anyway, I hope the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+ will still work the same way. It is also convenient to indent things (list, etc.)

Comment: People who use Stack Snippet are those who do look at either the "How to format" banner or the taskbar. This won't work if people don't do that at all (and just paste the code). If this is implemented, I'd like to see some statistics to see how efficient it is.

Comment: @user202729 exactly my point. If it worked it would produce a multi line code block, not a single line code block split over multiple lines.

Comment: I wonder if the "editor" tag should be added, or does it not make a difference or is irrelevant?

Comment: How will we get users to click said button rather than simply pasting their code into the existing box?

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, this feature request really only addresses the "make it difficult to format code effectively" part, not the "we...do not make it obvious how to paste in code" part so this is only going to help the users who are looking at how to enter their code that user202729 mentioned. I honestly don't know how to make it more obvious how to enter code other than to replace the symbolic button with one that just says "Code". If I come up with something I think it is good, I'll put up a new feature request but hopefully this helps users who are trying but running into trouble.

Comment: +1 for fenced code formatting because the number of edit suggestions you get in review where the only change is the indentation of code because of SO's weird indentation code blocks is not insignificant from my empirical experience.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it might help... a bit... although honestly, I don't get what's so hard about reading the formatting help (right at the top it tells you "select and hit Ctrl+K"). There's a preview as well, obviously many users don't even look at that (or if they do, they don't seem to give a hoot). For me (at least lately) the mis-formatted code is a good indicator of posts not even worth wasting your time on.