# Include "Don't post images of code" in the guide

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ask-question-wizard-2018

I was trying the [wizard mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard) of asking a question, and when I came to the "Show some code"-section it said "Don’t paste an entire file", and "Don't paste just one line".

My suggestion is to also add "Don't paste images of code". This is a fairly common mistake by beginners.

Comment: Users with less than 10 rep get the wizard, but can't upload images at all. Not sure if that's something to consider.

Comment: @yivi If I'm not mistaken, they can upload images but not inline them.

Comment: @Broman Yeah, Others and myself need to make them inline

Comment: @U9-Forward Noone should edit posts to make images of code inline. Those questions should be closed instead.

Comment: @Broman No no no, I only care about images of something other than code

Comment: @Broman I only edit those. :P

Comment: It is a "don't put the poodle in the microwave" warning.  Heaping on ever more directions like that has an averse affect, they'll just stop reading when it gets to be too much or too silly.  Microwave oven manufacturers do this to avoid getting sued, they don't expect anybody to read the manual.  We do need them to read it.

Comment: @HansPassant I read "don't put the noodle in the microwave" and was wondering if it is actually dangerous to microwave noodles. Good side effect: I have now learned that the whole "old lady microwaved her poodle and sued the microwave company" story is a legend.

Comment: Legends are pretty useful to make a point.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode . Include this content/link in it if possible

Comment: @ManoharReddy [Just remember what Tim Post said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379603/6296561).

Comment: @hansPassant what happens if you actually add an image? It could be useful if a popup appears then, showing some guidelines for images. With that, the site stays clean and information is shown on point.

Comment: @HansPassant I disagree.  Barely anyone puts poodles in microwaves.  ***LOTS*** of new users try to put images of their code in their questions.  I have txt files with boiler-plate comments of what not to do, including why images of code are bad.  I could be wrong, but I don't think anybody has txt files with comments dissuading users from putting poodles in microwaves.  I understand that we don't want to overwhelm users, but it needs to be as blatantly clear as possible that we want text if possible, images are supplementary.

Comment: @Zoe What Tim said is conterproductive to his own goals (both in terms of making new users feel welcome and in terms of having quality content). Read through the comments. I wouldn't take his advice on the matter seriously.

Comment: @jpmc26 meh, you only consider it counter-productive until you get suspended. Since the network owners have taken a stand against it, I still recommend reading through the post before using the links. SE will probably enforce it, regardless of what you, me, or anyone else thinks about it. Also, Tim's post (unlike the MCVE name change) is a statement, not a question asking whether that's fine or not.

Comment: @Zoe No, it will still be counterproductive if they suspend people over it. It's based on completely flawed reasoning and actively makes the site worse. You can refrain from posting them if you choose, but it's still complete nonsense.

Comment: @jpmc26 there's a lot of counter-productive things on the site. Off the top of my head, review audits based on wrong handling, not implementing feature requests to help scale i.e. review queues to the volume, and overall spending dev resources on a theme that's around for 2 days, to never get used again. Flawed reasoning or not, it's the new policy. Besides, it's my understanding it mainly applies to Link-only comments. Building it into a constructive comment is still allowed (but that requires typing, which is why I'm using a stock comment userscript instead)

Comment: @jpmc26 additionally, and I'm not aware of the full extent, but at least link-only comments to idownvotedbecau.se can be flagged and removed with a single flag now. So it's realistic, and actually highly likely repeated use will be brought to the mods' attention.

Comment: Yes, a thousand times over.  With an explanation of why images of code suck (you can't easily debug it, you have to type it out yourself to provide the solution, etc.).  I've never understood how taking a screenshot of code, uploading it to imgur or whatever, grabbing the link, and then putting it in a post is easer than just copy and pasting the code into the question.

Comment: This rule could itself appear as an inline image, rather than text, for irony. There could be wording added to encourage the reader to try to copy an excerpt from that rule into their clipboard.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481

Comment: This has been added in a recent version of the ask wizard.