# Will I get banned if I am correcting someone through comments?

Tags: discussion

I'm not that good, especially in coding, but there are times where the answers are pretty basic and the asker would just use maybe a message box to get his information required, or maybe the basic troubleshooting of your own computer.

The problem with me is I insist that they should know these at least. If statements are one of the basics in programming, and simple PC troubleshooting is a MUST (I think) for a programmer because it is our primary tool for our jobs, let's say for the near future, I insist on these (what I think), are basic knowledge through comments, will I get banned for it, because I am not being [nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)? I also would like to point out that what I am telling them is the most [honest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) I could give.

Edit: I would have to include my actions, because I think I might get in trouble in here.

- *[It is not executing the if part of the if-else statement. It might be the relational operator ? Instead is executing the else part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533694/it-is-not-executing-the-if-part-of-the-if-else-statement-it-might-be-the-relati#comment84065580_48533694)*
- *https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/how-to-tell-people-im-not-their-tech-support/9070#9070*

Comment: So I see the 'be nice' to be less about what you have to say and more with how you say it. Major difference between "this is a noob question. Go learn if statements and come back when you're ready to talk to grown ups" and "on stack you are expected to do some research and try to fix your issue before you ask. I would suggest looking at 'if statements' in your language of choice and reading up on that first. If you have trouble with some concepts come and ask clearly about these, instead of a generic question".

Comment: @Patrice I edited my question for my defence.

Comment: reading the Stack question, there is NO need for defense here :) everything is more than okay with these comments. You are helping a user improve, and being nice about it. Only the most flippant users would say you aren't 'being nice' here. Don't worry about it at all ^^. Not sure for the IPS one, as it may have different standards than stack overflow, but it also looks fine to me, if a little bit rougher than the Stack interactions.

Comment: The comment you link to is more than fine, you are easily within the boundaries of our policies. If you really crossed a line and are not being nice, we normally let you know with a moderator-only message; you generally won’t be suspended outright. We do sometimes suspend on first offence but that takes a whole different level of *not nice* than the kind you are alluding to here; otherwise, suspensions are only used after other avenues of correcting your behaviour have been exhausted.

Comment: [*The problem with me is I insist that they should know these at least*](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/duty_calls.png)

Comment: Explaning how to use a debugger, how to print variable, is tought. The more you try to be nice, the more rude you can become. Don't try to be nice,  just stay to the fact. See no evil in Op.

Comment: My process is : 1/. Use bullet point, Be clear and short. 2/. Once the point is made hit enter and stop writing. 3/. Really get out before the inner you try to ask Op if he did try to Google before asking about '[LinQ]How to Top 5?' 4/. Once the Characters left change to Orange. It's time to stop commenting.

Comment: probably related: [Do we reward good downvoters?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330371/839601)

Comment: You might not get banned for stuff like "Try again" or "I'll be spoon feeding you" but it's still unnecessary noise. You can always leave it out if you think it'll attract flags.

Comment: I will use every advice you guys gave me, thank you! I just dont get the downvotes though. (even on my questions)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you! Its a good thing a moderator has answered my question, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I understand your frustration with the lack of quality questions. However, lambasting people for asking questions that they 'should have known' doesn't really achieve anything.

If they're asking a question which is understandable, has an expected outcome, and illustrates exactly what they're trying to achieve, then I don't see the problem with keeping the question around for future visitors.

There isn't really a question *too simple* for Stack Overflow. In fact, one of the founders tried to argue this fact by asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo).

If the answer to a question really should be known to 'everyone', one would imagine that the question has been asked and answered before. So the best course of action here would be to flag the question as a duplicate. If there's no such duplicate, then it's a net positive for the wealth of knowledge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think "lambasting"  is way too deep for me sir, Here is one of my actions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533694/it-is-not-executing-the-if-part-of-the-if-else-statement-it-might-be-the-relati#comment84065580_48533694

Comment: @Mr.J I hadn't actually read any of your comments; my answer was addressing your concern of treading the line of not being nice when people ask simplistic answers. If you're providing constructive feedback trying to help them *improve*, you've got nothing to worry about.

Comment: One problem is that that dulicate questions on basic language syntax are difficult to find, not because they have not been asked before, but because they have, (rightly), been closed and deleted.   Another issue is that spending more effort on a question than the OP did is a waste of resources that could be spent on a question not about basic syntax and to which an answer cannot be found by reading a textbook or tutorial site.

Comment: You're right that there's no such thing as a question too simple, but there *is* such a think as a poorly researched question.  Questions *are* expected to do their research.  As for your example, notice how it's closed and had to have been locked to prevent it's deletion, as it's simply not an appropriate question for the site.  There are *multiple* messages there telling you that that's not an appropriate question to use as an example.

Comment: Just because a question doesn't have an exact duplicate *on Stack Overflow* doesn't mean it doesn't have a readily discoverable answer.  It just means that that answer isn't necessarily on SO.  Duplicating lots of readily available information isn't a net positive for the wealth of knowledge of the programming community.  It's just duplicating content.