# Why was I slapped on the wrist?

Tags: discussion, moderation, rude-or-abusive

Last week I received a private moderator message saying:

> ...We wanted to let you know that we've observed some rudeness in your
>   latest activity. We get it; anyone who's ever tried to engage with
>   others online has probably been tempted to lash out at someone else.
>   This is just a friendly reminder that we require all participants to
>   act in a professional and civil tone when using these sites. If
>   another user has wronged you in some way, please do not respond in
>   kind. Simply flag the content for moderator attention and move on...

This message gave me the chance to reply, which I did, asking what the offending activity was, adding that without any context this warning is useless. However, I have yet to receive a response from any of the mods, which left me wondering if this is the typical pattern with these warnings or if there's usually some reason or evidence provided. **How am I supposed to know what I've done wrong (and not do it again) if I don't know what precipitated the warning about my alleged action?**

I've been at SO for almost a decade and this is the first warning I've received, so I find it a little out of the blue. I'm pretty cognizant about my behavior and what I write, yet this ambiguous form warning doesn't give me anything to act on, so what's the point? As a parent, this is like disciplining my child but not telling them what they did wrong.

Comment: Well... are you fixing it? (jk jk, it is indeed pretty weak, and without any specific comment/context.... could very well be just a misinterpreted comment....)

Comment: Just make sure that you never *ever* do it again

Comment: As an active user in the same tags, I am surprised that *you* get such message. By the way I got such message one day and never know why ..

Comment: did you also get this part at the end *If this is a simple misunderstanding, no harm done. Sometimes it is helpful to remind ourselves on occasion that keeping things friendly and constructive doesn't have to be at odds with being right — so enjoy the site, bring your sense of humor, and please be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.* ? --> maybe it a *big* misunderstanding

Comment: What does a private moderator message look like? How is it presented?

Comment: @isherwood you get an email

Comment: And is that a noreply situation?

Comment: @isherwood you have a link that allow you to open a kind of private chat to reply on.

Comment: "*I've been at SO for almost a decade and this is the first warning I've received, which I find a little odd*" ...are you aware that, grammatically, this is an admission to finding your own past behavior worthy of admonishment?

Comment: @TylerH The problem is we don't know the line. Everyone active can probably can think of a few times in the past that may have been close to the line, maybe even past what they though was the line, not getting a warning naturally moves where you think the line is.

Comment: @isherwood Mine came to my SO inbox like a normal comment with a copy to my email

Comment: @TylerH What I meant what that I find it odd that after 10 years I get my first warning last week when nothing on my side changed.

Comment: It's a fair question, but I wonder if it was an anomaly (overly sensitive mod, mistaken action by a mod...) where a more common case would've had an obvious root. Frankly, after hearing your situation, I'm surprised that I haven't received many such notices. I'm fairly regularly not a patient person. :D

Comment: [Related discussion on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336485/). This is a boilerplate message mods send when we get an automatic flag about your account having had too many recent comments deleted as rude. I have my own feelings about how it should be handled, but mods vary in their approach. And most of us won’t bother citing details when we think the rudeness is blatantly obvious. (Not saying yours was; I haven’t reviewed any of your comments.)

Comment: @isherwood an "unfriendly" deleted comment once in a while doesn't trip the system.

Comment: related: [Do we reward good downvoters?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330398/839601)

Comment: How polite was your mod message response?  When I was a mod, most of these responses were fairly vile nonsense, and so I tended not to pay much attention to them.

Comment: @CodyGray I received one of these, too (over a year ago). But since there was no indication of what the alleged infraction might have been I shrugged it off as unactionable. So I'd agree with j08691 that these notifications are essentially useless.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Why did you shrug it off if it wasn't useless?

Comment: @j08691 Hm? I said I *did* consider it unactionable (and therefore useless). Not to mention that this kind of "friendly warning" does remind me a bit of Kafka's "The Process": you're being accused of something without being told what that something actually is.

Comment: The correct title is, of course, "The Trial", not "The Process". *\*slaps self\**

Answer (score 20):

The moderator dashboard reports users having made a certain given number of rude/unfriendly comments recently.

We usually check the comments, and decide to warn/suspend or just do nothing (because sometimes "unfriendly" flags are accepted by mods when they are "no longer needed" instead)

In your case, I issued the warning, without suspension, because the comments were unfriendly enough, but not up to the point that gets you suspended (also this is the first warning for you). Then you replied but I didn't came out with details because I was on a big road/plane trip with limited internet access, then got a little sick then … completely forgot about it, sorry! (and you cannot send multiple replies to moderator messages unless they reply themselves, you have no ideas of the "unpleasant" messages we get with just one reply)

Here's the full message, which is the template, without any changes:

> Hello,
>
> We're writing in reference to your Stack Overflow account:
>           https://stackoverflow.com/users/xxxx
>
> We wanted to let you know that we've observed some rudeness in your latest activity. We get it; anyone who's ever tried to engage with others online has probably been tempted to lash out at someone else. This is just a friendly reminder that we require all participants to act in a professional and civil tone when using these sites. If another user has wronged you in some way, please do not respond in kind. Simply flag the content for moderator attention and move on.
>
> If this is a simple misunderstanding, no harm done. Sometimes it is helpful to remind ourselves on occasion that keeping things friendly and constructive doesn't have to be at odds with being right — so enjoy the site, bring your sense of humor, and please be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.
>   Regards,
>   Stack Overflow Moderation Team

(note that the last paragraph is usually edited out when you get a suspension)

But you're right, how can you improve if no one shows you what's wrong? That behaviour honors you.

By the way:

> As a parent, this is like disciplining my child but not telling them what they did wrong.

We don't see you like a child that needs disciplining. You're not posting insulting answers or defacing posts or spamming. You got a friendly warning so you can improve your behaviour on the site.

I have provided details using the moderator message system (not posting the comments here obviously even if there's no NSW content in them). Note that I only do that on request (and I always comply on the request) because it means selecting the offending parts, removing the names of the person who flagged, etc... I *know* Sam has a script for this, I *know*...

If you want to ping the mods without creating a meta post, you can also flag one of your posts with a custom flag.

Comment: (I think you belong to the friendlier mods of the site, it is *not* a critic!) The user has no way to know, exactly what was considered rude. Particularly on the metas, comments are often on the border of the rudeness, but we have no way to know, exactly where did we step over the line. If you warn/suspend someone, please citate the recent, problematic activity on which you think, it already deserves suspension.

Comment: (note that I've never suspended anyone on meta because of comments). The tools made at our disposal are somehow basic. We have to check the link of the flagged comments, copy stuff in the message,etc ... if the person knows about it or doesn't care, I prefer sending the generic message and spending this time handling more flags :) (thank you from "friendlier" btw)

Comment: I have to wonder.... how many times that ***I*** have popped up on that dashboard... :o

Comment: .... on second thought, never mind. If I haven't been notified yet, best to not know

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I, OTOH, pop up rather frequently, because I often voice my frustration with poor questions, answers, and attitude--but almost never first. But that isn't part of the algorithm; we're not allowed to voice our frustration in a way that might trigger someone.

Comment: Dave, I don't remember deleting any of your comments, no. Rest assured!

Comment: @Dave: One neat trick to express your frustration with low-quality posts that is guaranteed to never get you in trouble with moderators: downvotes! Also, close/delete votes.

Comment: @CodyGray And I do. And I generally leave a comment as to why. That can escalate quickly, and when I take umbrage, I say so.

Comment: *"And I generally leave a comment as to why. That can escalate quickly..."* Don't we know it. Perhaps there's a lesson here? You are free to leave a comment criticizing or praising the answer, but such comments should never divulge any information about how you have voted. Votes are anonymous by design. If there starts to be speculations or accusations regarding voting, please flag such comments for moderator attention so that we can remove them.