# Another new user complaining about the site being unfriendly and elitist ... what to do differently?

Tags: discussion, scope, welcoming, behavior, rude-or-abusive

Screenshot:

[image: Question]
[image: Comments]

The fire-script of the 'MachineGun script (js)' does what he wants (from https://answers.unity.com/questions/207890/shoot-when-gui-is-pressed.html)

The answers of https://answers.unity.com/questions/153340/hold-button-shooting.html tell him what to do.

My 1st and 2nd comment tell him what he could do - the remaining back and forth resulted in him deleting the post and changing his users description:

[image: User]

Observations:

- new user
- no tour taken
- question well formatted
- knew how to edit his summary
- comment section of the deleted question was afterwards "refined" by him, he removed some of his comments

Should I stop commenting and reducing my interactions to downvoting and closevoting, only answering 100% quality questions?

Comment: Some people believe when they come to SO that it is a help desk, and get angry when people tell them it isn't. If you want to help an off-topic question (which some argue you shouldn't), you can engage in comments, but sometimes people just don't want to listen anyway if you don't post a full solution. IMO, the 5th comment would've been an indication to just walk away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we reward good downvoters?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330371/do-we-reward-good-downvoters)

Comment: 'New account' !='New user'.

Comment: *Should I stop commenting and reducing my interactions to downvoting and closevoting, only answering 100% quality questions?* --> Yes you should. I guess we all should.

Comment: The platform really does not handle "entitled" users well. A tough problem, but one that feels secondary to the welcoming movement, considering that some of the changes to the site done last year made the problem worse. Saving yourself from frustration by not commenting is a fair course of action here.

Comment: Human-interaction-wise, the problem seems to come from saying "a problem you did not even try to solve yourself", which is a strong accusation that doesn't seem justified in this case: they did research, they did try things, they just got stuck because as a beginner they didn't fully understand the resources they found. Maybe it was unintentional but "did not *even* try", with the intensifier "*even*", sounds like an unjustified accusation of *extreme* laziness: this person isn't lazy, just a beginner who also doesn't yet understand that SO demands a very narrow type of question.

Comment: It’s also another case of a user whose perception is that SO isn’t for new coders or that they got downvoted because they’re a new coder. We don’t care if you’ve been programming for a week or for twenty years—we don’t care about the person—we want well-researched, smart questions. This is also related to the help-desk perception. We really need to set expectations better, somehow.

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 'they did research, they did try things'.. how do you know that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why you *care* if they think you're being hostile/elitist.  In moderation, you have a role to fulfill, and if they don't like the fact that they posted an off-topic question *and* as a consequence, now have their question closed, that really isn't your obligation to address.

My gut tells me that you were in the right place at the right time, doing the right thing in regards to the moderation of this person's post.  From the comment chain, it reads as if they were insulted that you made the suggestion that this wasn't the platform to ask for collaborators.

Which, it ***isn't***.

Then they took their insult to a level of rage and insisted that you were the one at fault.

...

In all reality, I feel like you should do things differently next time.  The executive summary:  do *less* next time.

---

First and foremost - and I cannot stress this enough -

## don't comment on off-topic questions, at all.

Voting to close and downvoting if appropriate is *plenty*.  You should not feel obligated to engage with someone that doesn't take the time to figure out if this kind of question is appropriate here.

Second - if you do happen to engage in a comment thread with someone that posts a question like this,

## get your point across and *get out*.

You absolutely **should not** engage in any kind of lengthy back and forth with anyone that is taking umbrage with the topicality of their question on Stack Overflow proper.

(If they came to Meta, it'd be a different story.)

Answer (score 16):

You handled that nicely in the comments. Most that are new to the field certainly will not like what SO still is.  9 out of 10 probably end-up like this one. Keep trying to find that single new user that does appreciate what you are trying to achieve and are both open and able to reflect on their own post and adapt based on your guidance.
And then hope that single user will spread the positive word on their Twitstagram.

Your votes and comments should be and are appreciated by us. Well done.

What you better not do is come to meta and single out a user, no matter how hurt your feelings are. If we pretend to be elitist at least take it so far that we don't bother not being understood.

As for the about me of the user: as long as the insults, if any, can't be linked to a user I wouldn't bother. Once a user gets targeted it is time to raise a mod flag on one of your own posts and link to the user profile and explain what the context is. Then let mods handle it in private.

Comment: But does not **every** elitist don't understand their pears, if they come not from the same field of expertise?

Answer (score 0):

That comment thread looks to me like a classic example of an interaction in written English between two non-natives who misunderstand each others' intent because they use the language slightly differently to each other. I imagine if the two of you interacted face-to-face, or even with tone of voice audible, it would have been fine.

In particular there several points you use intensifiers. In general I (native, UK) have noticed that some German colleagues, friends and acquaintances use such intensifiers intending to convey *precision*, not realising that without other context or cues like tone of voice, it can appear like an escalation or an intentional insult:

> "a problem you did not **even** try to solve yourself"

- I would only add an intensifier like "even" here in a case where I am *angry and exasperated* that someone has *100% certainly* not done something so basic, their not doing it is a shameful failure. That appears to be how the user took it.
- I suspect your intent was to convey that it should be *precisely* and *clearly* the first thing they do - like "a problem *where it is not clear* you first tried to solve it yourself".

> "Nothing in your post shows **any hint of**..."

- Again, this looks like a rhetorical intensifier. You're not simply saying something was factually missing from the post, you're adding a rhetorical flourish that appears to mock its total, shameful absence. This might be appropriate for a complete "this is my homewrok give me teh codes" question, where the tone suggests a lazy person who made absolutely no effort whatsoever, but here, this user's question doesn't suggest exceptional laziness like that.
- I suspect what you meant was something like "I could not see clear indications of..."

---

And then, in the person's responses, they say:

> "I understand now this is not a site for people new to coding. Bye"

- This does look like "rage-quitting", and I can see why you might read it that way.
- Other things the person says don't fit that picture and it could have been simply an unfortunately phrased attempt to save face while backing out of a conversation.

> I'm not trying to be rude and maybe a breakdown in English. While I appreciate the response, you seem to respond in "elitist" way

- On SO, and in some circles elsewhere, "elitist" is of course a strong, loaded term which hits a lot of raw nerves. I understand why you took it the way you did - but it was in a sentence couched in softeners and expressions of appreciation. Perhaps you saw these as "polite fluff" and skipped them - but I suspect they were genuine
- We don't know anything about this user's background, but it looks to me like someone making an effort to give constructive feedback - probably not realising they are using a word which has a lot hanging on it in this community