# Why am I always seeing "Please consider a comment if you think this post can be improved" when I downvote a post?

Tags: support, downvotes

I always see this message when I downvote a post:

[image]

Shouldn't it be displayed only when I downvote a post for the first time?

Comment: It's a trap anyway. When you comment asking for improvements when you downvote, it sometimes leads to revenge downvoting or [mod warnings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335707)

Comment: See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78163/please-add-a-comment-explaining-still-shows-up-when-i-add-a-comment-and-then) on Meta. It won't show once you have enough rep.

Comment: It's indeed a trap. Feel free to _consider_ in the pure sense of the word, but don't feel like you _have_ to comment.

Comment: @CertainPerformance or heated comments, or harassment, or off-site stalking. People want to know why they get downvoted, but when they do, far too many lash out.