# Why lose reputation on downvotes answers despite upvoting a comment?

Tags: discussion, voting

We all have stumbled across a poor StackOverflow answer, and the nature of this site encourages us to downvote it. The SO philosophy is that we *should* cast our downvote *so long as we explain our thinking in a comment*. However, many times, I've come across a low-quality answer that already has someone else's disapproving comment, which I agree with.

If I still comment anyway, I don't lose any reputation, but I'm adding the comment unnecessarily because what I'm saying has already been said.

If I don't comment and decide to upvote the existing comment, then I lose the reputation but am limiting duplicate comments.

These ideas seem conflicting to me, could someone explain why this is the case? Isn't this system encouraging me to say something someone else has already said? I understand it's only 1 reputation, but I'm just curious if I'm misunderstanding something or if there's another argument I'm not seeing.

Comment: "The SO philosophy is that we should cast our downvote so long as we explain our thinking in a comment." -- No, actually this is not SO policy or philosophy. Please search meta on this matter. As for down-voting, it has nothing to do with another's comments. You down-vote if you feel the question or answer warrants it, no more and no less.

Comment: I will add that there is an unfairness in the system, in that it's a lot easier for someone with lots of rep points to down-vote an answer than someone with few, as the *relative* cost to that user is much less, and I'm not sure if this is unfairness is by design or by default.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something.  Everyone loses reputation for downvoting an answer.  You do not have to leave a comment, and even if you do leave a comment, you still lose the 1 rep point.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Could you provide some info that shows otherwise? SO displays a blue message encouraging comments after a downvote. On [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question#comment9497_252740) meta comment it was suggested that a comment should be left unless it has already been said.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That could be the case. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @vqdave: "*SO displays a blue message encouraging comments after a downvote.*" That's true, but it should only be done if there is something fixable and if the question seems worth the effort. "*On this meta comment it was suggested that a comment should be left unless it has already been said.*" Which is just one person's opinion. By the voting on the answer that question is attached to, far more people believe quite the opposite.

Comment: "*If I don't comment and decide to upvote the existing comment, then I lose the reputation*" - you only lose reputation points for downvotes; upvotes cost you nothing.  Commenting is not at all related to reputation when downvoting - only the downvote reduces your reputation, and only then for answers, as downvoting a question doesn't cost any reputation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Reading your question here, I think you have a couple of very significant misunderstandings of the voting system (esp downvoting) and how it relates to commenting.

Firstly, your questions seems to suggest you believe that commenting after downvoting prevents you from losing reputation. This is absolutely not the case.  When you downvote **an answer**, you always lose 1 rep point.  This is true whether you leave a comment, upvote a comment, or do nothing.  Downvoting a question is always free, so maybe that is the source of your confusion.

Secondly, you seem to believe that commenting as to why you downvoted is encouraged.  Actually the opposite is true.  Comments to explain downvotes are strongly discouraged.  Commenting solely because you downvoted and explaining why you downvoted tends to lead to arguments and revenge downvoting more than it leads to constructive discussion.

What is actually encouraged is commenting when you have a suggestion on how to improve the post.  Often this may also be associated with a downvote but it doesn't always coincide.  [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) offers the best explanation of this situation:

> Explaining votes is almost pure noise, meta-conversation and punditry. Your votes are your own to do with as you please; you owe no one an explanation, nor is a discussion of your voting habits likely to be helpful.
>
> What is helpful is constructive feedback:
>
> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Source (and strongly recommended reading): [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not/285777#285777)

Comment: This is so not true. If downvotes mean the answer is bad then how does that help anyone if it's not explained in which way bad? Explaining a downvote is not only a form of constructive feedback becasue the downvoter obviosuly found a reason for casting it but also a warning for other readers about what is wrong with that answer. I downvoted your answer for spreading a false theory.

Comment: @t3chb0t Commenting "I downvoted because the question is missing the error message" will often lead to discussion about the downvote. Just commenting "Please add the error message to your question" is neutral, could be added by anybody (downvoter or not) and might lead to more constructive work on the question, so you should prefer it. That is what the answer is suggesting, not to not comment at all.

Comment: @t3chb0t ModusTollens is exactly right.  Commenting about the downvote tends to be unconstructive because the discussion will end up being about the downvote and not about fixing the post.  Instead explain how the answer (or question) can be fixed, or why the answer is wrong.

Comment: @t3chb0t After rereading my answer, I realized that my choice of wording may have not necessarily said what I wanted it to say.  Commenting about **why** you downvoted is discouraged.  But commenting after downvoting if you have constructive feedback about improving the post is certainly encouraged.

Comment: You mentioned that "When you downvote an answer, you always lose 1 rep point." and then you proceed to mention "Downvoting a question is always free". These 2 statements are slightly contradicting. Can you explain about these? Do we always loose a point when we Downvote? Does that means Downvoting is not encouraged?

Comment: @Gangula The key words here are _"downvote an **answer**"_ and _"downvoting a **question**"_. That is, it only costs reputation to downvote answers. The argument originally made for downvotes to have a reputation penalty was to prevent some forms of misuse. This penalty was eventually [lifted for questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), but some users wouldn't mind seeing it go away when downvoting answers as well, since we do want to [encourage downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537).