# Does my guidance to a new member strike the tone SO is trying to achieve?

Tags: discussion, welcoming

I've started down voting and commenting to provide friendly but firm guidance to new members. Here is an example from [C# Closures in LINQ expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307140/c-sharp-closures-in-linq-expressions#comment87636187_50307140):

> Welcome to StackOverflow. You will receive better responses to your questions if the code compiles. Consider pasting your example in to [dotnetfiddle.net](http://www.dotnetfiddle.net/) to verify that it compiles. This guide too can be helpful: [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Does my comment strike the tone that SO is trying to achieve? If not, what might be a better alternative comment?

Comment: I've been told *You* is wrong. Not being a native speaker myself but I've seen suggestions like *This question contains code that doesn't compile. To receive better answers to the question it helps if the code compilies* and then include those links.

Comment: @rene: "You" is fine.

Comment: @rene I don't know the context, but it is likely they meant that one should criticize the work not the author. "*You* are wrong" vs. "*This code* is wrong".

Comment: "You" is natural as "you"'re speaking to an individual (how else should I say that?). But generalizing is typically best. (her, his, ...) = theirs, (he, she, ... , men, women, ...) = (them, they), your code = the code, and so on.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: That's exactly the kind of _over-thinking_ I'm not a fan of.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I understand that, truly. But I don't find it to be "*over-thinking*". I used to pre-identify when speaking unknowingly. Things like unnecessarily stating race or gender when, as usual, has no significance to the point. I made corrections so it's something I notice all the time. I'm not suggesting anything other than to consider it and maybe notice it.

Comment: On the other hand, people may be assigning too much value to the way someone is writing something, online. There is nothing wrong with: _"The OP needs to fix his syntax errors"_ or _""Your/his code doesn't compile_. That's not _"rude"_ or _"inconsiderate"_, it's just a suggestion to improve the question. _That's all._

Comment: @Cerbrus, true; I'm not arguing that as rude and I wasn't trying to address "rudeness". The og comment was about "*You*" is wrong. I was simply supporting that further not that I'm perfect in doing it *all the time*. But, when  writing, it's a choice that you make.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'd go with something closer to what Increasingly Idiotic has said. If what you are going to say sounds overtly confrontational (eg. "You are wrong") it may be worth it to avoid "you"; in general, though, "you" is fine (and, under the right circumstances, it can even feel friendlier than an impersonal use of the third person).

Comment: Sorry @duplode, I don't read it like that. They were saying, criticize the work meaning instead of "your code" it would be "the code". I don't see that being a decision that's made based on how confrontational the given statement will be but rather a basic approach that doesn't require dynamic determination.

Comment: "But, when writing, it's a choice that you make." but "*you*" said! It's actually a choice that ***I*** make. Subtle, but different.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils [1/2] I intentionally picked a very obvious example, but it can also make sense for "Your code is wrong". Note, though, that the example in this Meta question is not of this kind ("You will receive better responses if [...]").

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils [2/2] On a more general note, I do think "dynamic determination" is often reasonable. Except for extreme cases, hard rules aren't always  necessary for this sort of communication issue.

Comment: Good points. I recall from The Assertiveness Workbook that criticism via "you statements" tends to be more difficult to receive. An alternative is: "Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions tend to receive a better response if the code compiles..."

Comment: I think the text is pretty good. It carries the necessary message, without being confrontational. Minor note: _Stack Overflow_ is two words.

Comment: Passive voice can be even worse than "you statements". I like to focus on me, the narcissistic author of the comment: "I'll have an easier time understanding the question if I can compile and run the code."

Comment: `I've been told You is wrong.` Indeed. Use `thou` for maximum respect.

Comment: Back to the question... I didn’t realize that code compiling was a condition of posting a question. In fact, what led me to Stack Overflow initially (under another account), was the fact that code didn’t compile or operate correctly.

Comment: @vol7ronA minimal, complete, verifiable example is pretty much a requirement. If you're posting code that doesn't compile, and as such, can't reproduce the issues, you're only complicating things.

Comment: No comment is even necessary given that you have close-vote privileges. Once the post is closed, a similar comment is generated by the site, pointing at the MCVE page.

Comment: "Indeed. Use thou for maximum respect." I know you're joking, but "thou" was actually the informal word, and "you" was the more formal, respectful word. (Christians were encouraged to use thee/thou/thy for prayer not because it was respectful, but because it was intimate.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 thou jests?

Comment: @vol7ron When the compiler error is your actual issue, a code example reproducing the error *is*  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In contrast, when the question is not about compiler errors at all, the code *should* compile. This is not a hard requirement. But obviously, code requiring unrelated fixes makes it harder to solve the issue.

Comment: It's like sex with someone for the first time. Do what you want until someone complains - then excuse and change afterwards.

Comment: Just don't write a comment. The people you're writing it to should have read the FAQ and won't pay extra attention now. Cast a close vote then the close reason in the UI will show the required information. What we have now is an incredible amount of comment noise where half the questions posted on the site have almost the entire contents of the FAQ reproduced in comments. This level of spoonfeeding will not help anyone in any meaningful way.

Comment: I've tried to be nicer and not use "you", but "That code is an idiot" just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Tangent, and I know it's kind of a joke, but actually 'thou' and all its counterparts was the familiar, *informal* version of the word, rather than the other way around. 'You' is the formal one.

Comment: @picciano Now I'm not sure whether *you* or *that comment* made me laugh. Doesn't matter. Had a laugh.

Comment: @Ajean yeah, I know! The joke should really have been the other way round. Funny how that evolved, apparently somehow differently than what other European languages ended up using as the formal form; e.g. the third person (in Spanish; antiquated in German) and the plural (current formal form in German). While *thou* is obviously a direct sibling to German *Du*, I know of no German equivalent to *you* even though both are Germanic languages.

Comment: Ah, cool. *you* used indeed to be a plural form, too - just a *very* very long time ago. The German equivalent is "euch" (plural of "you"). TIL! https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you

Comment: The question is a little sloppy, esp the Select() part. But the provided code fragments still add up to an mcve. Asking for compiling code doesn't always make sense, this is an "how to" question, not a "fix it" one.

Comment: I feel quite a lot of meta questions last time are better suited for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 64):

I think we're fine as long as we use ***common sense***.

There will always be new users that find any request / suggestion "rude". You don't need to be excessively nice.
For example, this user has registered 10 months ago. "Welcome" might even be considered rude, since he isn't exactly new to the site.

We all need to find a balance between "niceness" and just commenting like normal human beings.

---

I'd say: Speak as you like to be spoken to. Consider how the comment would come across if it were written for you.

Comment: Looking at a user's registration date does not speak to their use or knowledge of the site. Maybe they're the first person to welcome them. Also, I find the "any request" user to be on the fringe; no reason to be "excessively nice" but nice first; don't assume this is the user about to be rude for no good reason.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: These are just examples, people _can_ take offence to _anything_. There's no point in trying to make it impossible to take offence to what you say. I'm not saying we should _assume_ people will take offence. I'm saying the ___exact opposite___. I'm saying we should just use common sense.

Comment: Good point. I felt a bit of a cringe from "Welcome" too, but I kept it because of the OP's reputation level. On the one hand, it conveys a charitable statement, "Oh, you're new here, so we expect mistakes." On the other hand, someone could easily interpret it as sarcasm.

Comment: It's really not as simple as "I think we're fine as long as we use common sense." *Everyone* thinks they are 'using common sense' - and yet here we are in a situation where we're told that as a community sometimes we're getting it wrong. So each person trusting to their own common sense clearly isn't sufficient.

Comment: @AakashM: I don’t think we can realistically expect more than that. Some users just are rude. They need to be flagged, and that’s that. Yes, common sense is subjective, but throwing more rules at it won’t solve anything.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin - FWIW: The snippets I use for this have "Welcome to Stack Overflow!" at the beginning. I replace it with "Hi!" if the user's account isn't new but hasn't been used much (or sometimes if it has been). Purely to be welcoming/engaging, start out positive.

Comment: We can't rely on "just use common sense" because half the site thinks common sense is to say things that violate the be nice policy, like calling someone's effort garbage.

Comment: Common sense would tell us to flag those comments, @TylerH.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not sure you understand; we can flag the comments but the problem we are trying to address here is the fact that half the site thinks it's okay to make them. Saying "just use common sense" here on Meta is stomping on the bugs when you see them but not fixing the problem of how they are getting in the house in the first place.

Comment: @TylerH: I don't think users that write comments like that are reading meta in the first place. All we ___can___ do is to be more pro-active in dealing with comments like that, harshly.

Comment: @Cerbrus Several active meta users of significantly high reputation (20k+) have taken this position, including one person in particular of quite high reputation who posts the same unhelpful answer on nearly every such meta question of late. And the fact that said answer gets on average 60 to 70 upvotes is troubling. I hope that your suggestion will be enough, though I highly doubt it.

Comment: @TylerH Can I have links? I don't recognise the "one person in particular" you're referring to from the description you've given on them, and I'm a reasonably active Meta user. I'd be interested to see their position in their words, to judge whether I agree with your characterisation of it.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'd rather not name names, to avoid targeted persecution or the appearance of it. Though of the dozen or so threads in the last several days/week I have seen this user post on what feels like, at first gut check, at least half of these with advice ranging from misguided to flat-out wrong. There are typically dozens of comments under each of these answers.

Comment: "Use common sense" and "don't overthink" -- these are ways of passing the buck, or denying anything needs to change. If common sense were enough, we wouldn't have a [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309513/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-especially-marginalized-groups).

Comment: @senderle: Where am I claiming everyone _is_ using common sense? Common sense is disappointingly uncommon. I'm not claiming everything is fine and dandy, but I am claiming we should put _too much_ effort into avoiding offending _everyone_. That's simply not possible.

Comment: But if most people don't have common sense, then in what sense is "use common sense" a viable solution? It's certainly not possible to avoid offending everyone, but it's possible to *minimize* offense. I doubt the guidelines and procedures that will do so will seem natural or commonsensical.

Comment: @senderle: Where am I saying _"most people"_? My point is that adding more and more rules isn't going to help. My point is that people that ___don't care about being nice at all___ should be dealt with accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

[Cerbrus's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367799/1709587) suggests that we should each *"Speak as you like to be spoken to"*. Well, with that in mind...

I would be annoyed to be on the receiving end of your comment, especially as a nervous new user trying to make a good first impression. It's imprecise about what, if anything, I've done wrong, and I'd find that frustrating and stressful. This is a defect that pretty much all boilerplate comments necessarily have, by their nature, and is a reason I'm mostly against the use of boilerplate comments.

The suggestion to paste the code into dotnetfiddle.net and check it compiles hints that maybe my code doesn't compile. But it doesn't outright say it... so maybe it *does* compile, and this is just a generic suggestion that you give to everyone? Have you actually checked before commenting? I can't tell.

The link to mcve.net is worse; you're suggesting that maybe you think I should trim my example down (it's not "minimal") or maybe you think I should add in boilerplate like `using` statements or wrapping methods in a class (it's not "complete") or maybe the code doesn't actually cause the problem I'm asking about or I haven't actually explained what the problem is clearly (it's not "verifiable"). Or maybe actually none of those things are wrong, and you're again just generically suggesting that this would be a nice page to read?

Your comment is essentially equivalent, in terms of its content, to this:

> Welcome! I may or may not be displeased by your question. Maybe the code doesn't compile, or maybe it does. It's possible that you're lacking a clear problem statement, or that your code doesn't actually produce the problem you're asking about, and that this displeases me, or alternatively maybe neither of those things is the case. Additionally, I'd like you to know that you have provided either too much, too little, or exactly the correct amount of code. Have a nice day!

If you received that comment, wouldn't you think that the commenter was being unhelpful, and, honestly, a bit of a dick?

And it's actually worse than that, because you're *actually* sending the user off to read [about 15 paragraphs of prose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in what may not be their native language, just to extract the non-information that your comment contains. (Presumably, while somehow simultaneously reading and responding to comments on the question, since we *also* [ask askers to be available to provide clarification in response to comments](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive).)

No matter how polite or cheerful the tone is, it can't make up for the fact that you're dumping a giant page of prose on the asker and insinuating that *maybe* the asker's question has one of several somewhat-subjectively-defined problems without providing any detail about which of them you think is the issue.

It's not much effort, and much, much more helpful to the asker, to write something like:

> This code doesn't even compile.

or

> There's way more code here than you need to demonstrate the problem. This question would be easier to understand and more useful to future readers if you trimmed it down to a minimal example.

or

> You haven't provided the implementation of the `frobnicate_widget()` method that your sample code calls, and without it, we can't tell what's going on.

or

> Your code works fine and does not produce the error that you say it does.

or

> It's unclear in what way this code "doesn't work"; it does exactly what I'd expect it to. Can you edit your question to indicate what you expected?

<sub>(In the first revision of this answer, these comments began with `-1;` I've removed the -1s to avoid conflating this with [a whole *other* argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081/1709587) about how to express criticism.)</sub>

These sorts of comments - which are unambiguous about the fact that there's a problem with the question and about *what that problem is* - almost certainly *don't* strike the tone that the staff would like us to strike, post-"welcoming" drive. Yours probably does strike that tone. And yet it seems to me that my alternatives are far more respectful to askers than your proposed comment is. I would certainly rather receive a comment in my style, that at least addresses me as an individual, than a boilerplate comment like yours.

Wouldn't you?

Comment: I agree with your comment suggestions but not with the fact that they all unhelpfully start with "-1". I would flag such comments on site as not constructive to get them auto-deleted. You don't need to start off being adversarial by saying "hey, I downvoted you, nah nah nah boo boo". Just say what you have to say, and if you downvoted, let the system indicate that the way it already does.

Comment: If you *really* feel compelled to own up to the downvote, mention it after the fact, or in the context of your comment *and* the site's rules: `It's unclear in what way this code "doesn't work", and the site's rules require you clearly state what part of your code isn't working and how you expect it to work, so I downvoted you. Can you edit your question to indicate that information" etc.

Comment: @TylerH I don't like attributing to the "rules" what are in fact subjective judgement calls about post quality made individually by me; I find it annoying when others do so, especially on the occasions when I *don't* agree with their judgements.

Comment: @TylerH - *"I would flag such comments on site as not constructive to get them auto-deleted"* - holy crap, is that a thing? I knew about the -1 filter, but does including "-1" in a comment make it deletable by any individual user without moderator review?

Comment: 1) the site's rules *do* state you have to add that information... or are you talking about something else? 2) Only if the comment starts with -1 and is of a certain short length (I don't know the exact length) is it unilaterally deletable.

Comment: @TylerH - *"I would flag such comments on site as not constructive ... You don't need to start off being adversarial"* - in what way is acknowledging a downvote "adversarial"? Even Shog9 never tried to make that case when he introduced the -1 filter; it was about avoiding retaliation, not based on an idea that the comments themselves were hostile to anyone. I can see how the downvote itself is adversarial, and how the specific criticism is adversarial, but isn't noting that you are the downvoter (and thus eliminating the mystery about the motive being the downvote) strictly a friendly act?

Comment: passing judgment on someone is inherently adversarial; you are *leading* with "I have negatively judged you for all the world to see and caused you to lose internet points". Losing 2 reputation is not a big deal in the grand scheme of things but if you are a new or new-ish user and you see the first response to your question is someone saying they have done this, it can evoke an emotional response and puts that first in the OP's mind, before they ever read the actual constructive part of your comment. I don't think it's bad to identify that you downvoted them, just that you do it last

Comment: @TylerH *"the site's rules do state you have to add that information"* - I don't agree. The [MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which I guess it what you're referring to?) is *guidance*, not *rules*; it just says that you *"will get much better answers if"* you do the things it suggests, like stating the expected behaviour. That's not the same as "providing every piece of information here is mandatory". And I don't even agree that it's always *useful*; in the right context, "it doesn't work" may have a sufficiently obvious meaning for further clarification to be unnecessary.

Comment: And yet if we close questions as lacking an MCVE it says they should include that information and prevents anyone from answering until the question is reopened, which doesn't happen until it is judged to have that information added in... so it may be just an argument in semantics, but the practical reality is *very* clear.

Comment: @TylerH I've edited to remove the -1s to avoid conflating the point about giving specific criticism with the old argument about whether to disclose downvotes. I still *would* include the -1, but perhaps it's best to keep the two fights separate.

Comment: Thanks for the update; having glanced over that Q&A you linked in the edit, it looks like my stance is in line with Shog's answer there. As before, I agree with the rest of your answer that we should focus on being constructive (and explicit)

Comment: While I agree with your overall sentiments, your comments are rude. "This code doesn't even compile.". Why the *even*? Strip it. "This code does not compile". Is neutral and tells the user what they can fix. "This code does not compile, therefore I can not reproduce your problem" is even better. All of your comments could be made more neutral in similar ways. "Your code works fine and does not produce the error that you say it does." => "I can not reproduce the error with the code as provided", shifts the focus from"you did it wrong" to "I can not reproduce", it says the same, but is nicer.

Comment: @Polygnome This reminds me of a recent conversation I had with Shog9 about whether labelling an answer as "nonsense" was rude; he suggested that "incorrect" would be more polite, and I protested that that wasn't an adequate substitute because it doesn't convey the same meaning. I feel the same here. In cases where I'm sure that my inability to reproduce is the asker's fault and not mine, I don't *want* to shift the focus from "you did it wrong" to "I can not reproduce"; I explicitly want the asker to know that they did something wrong, and not risk having my comment understood differently.

Comment: @MarkAmery But its not about *who* is wrong. Its not about blaming the right person. I don't understand why its important to rub it into the users face. Simply state the facts: It is not reproducible. Don't go into the blame-game. Furthermore, if you tried to reproduce it, then yes, *you* could not reproduce it with the code as provided, you have no information about whether or not someone else could reproduce it. So, even on a factual Level, "*I* can not reproduce it" is arguably more correct. But then again, its completely irrelevant who is to blame, whats important is fixing the Q&A.

Comment: @MarkAmery Furthermore, pretty much every conflict-resolution handbook will tell you not to play the blame-game, and to avoid "You did x" statements.

Comment: @Polygnome *"But its not about who is wrong."* - of course it is. If it's not the asker's fault, then there's no need for them to tweak their question and my comment is just pointless noise that should be deleted, the same as if I'd written *"I'm afraid I don't know the answer to this"*. If I drop the detail that I can't reproduce *because the provided code isn't a working example of the problem*, then I'm no longer giving actionable criticism, or even obviously giving criticism at all.

Comment: @Polygnome By contrast, in a case where I'm *not* confident that the example is broken, I might say *"I can't reproduce on my machine. (FooScript++ 6.4.3, on Ubuntu, running the provided code by pasting it into the FooWhizz REPL without fast frobnication extensions installed.) Perhaps this behaviour is OS-dependent?"* Fudging the distinction between those two completely separate scenarios drops information that shouldn't be dropped.

Comment: @MarkAmery You can provide constructive criticism. I have even given concrete examples. You insisting on *blaming* instead of solving the problem / getting the question fixed is exactly why SO can seem hostile sometimes. Focus on fixing the question/answer, not assigning blame, and its much easier. "The error is not reproducible with the code as given" vs. "Your code does not demonstrate the error you say it has". The latter is from this answer. Its twice bad, because the "... you claim it has" is just rubbing it in, it not even needed after "Your code does not show the error".

Comment: @MarkAmery Furthermore "The error is not reproducible with the code as given" focuses on the *content* of the question (it might not even be OPs code), while "Your code..." focuses on the user. Since we always claim up/downvotes are about *content*, lets make our criticism about *content* as well.

Comment: @Polygnome *"The error is not reproducible with the code as given"* is not the wording you originally suggested, and not what my last comment was arguing against; you've entirely changed your thesis between your previous pair of comments and these ones. As for the idea that identifying the code the asker has posted as "your code" instead of "the code" could somehow be insulting, that seems like a stretch to me.  Eliminating all explicit reference to the question by vaguely saying that *"The code does not produce the error"* without qualification just seems confusing; what code? What error?

Comment: @MarkAmery I am equally fine with "the code as given [...]" or "I can not reproduce [...]", because they both don't try to assign blame. But stay constructive, because if you think "The code" is confusing, when its a *comment* on a question/answer that contains *code*, then you are helpless. by that argument *"Your code" is equally confusing, because it could be code OP has on GitHub, or another browser tab. So yeah, I will not go down that route of argument, we should be able to assume a minimal amount of reading comprehension of the reader.

Comment: @MarkAmery Besides, you are completely missing the point that I originally complained *most* about the unnecessary snarky side remarks contained in the comments, such as "even" and the rubbing in of "what you say it does", which are just unnecessary and rude. Yes, I also think (and most books you can find about conflict-resolution agree with me), that you should refrain from assigning blame, because I think we should focus on the content.

Comment: @Polygnome If, as you say, it's generally completely obvious that *"the error"* and *"the error that you say [the code produces]"* are equal (which I *don't* think is always true; it depends upon the full content of the question and whether there're any errors or bits of code referenced to other than the ones included directly in the question), then how can one of those phrases "assign" more "blame" than the other? Under your premises, they're literally identical in meaning. I don't get it.

Comment: @Polygnome As for *"even"*... is it *superfluous*? Probably. Is it *rude*? I don't think so. Reflect upon the four places you've used it when addressing me: *"even on a factual level"*, *"I have even given concrete examples"*, *"it is not even needed"*, and *"it might not even be OPs code"*. All of these "even"s serve no purpose but emphasis; they could be dropped without fundamentally changing the meaning of your comments. Should I therefore take offence at you "rubbing in" your comments by including the word? Or, perhaps, just ignore such things as a normal habit of speech that people have?

Comment: @MarkAmery Exactly, they add emphasis. Depending on context, that can have very different effects. So yeah, I am saying one should be wary about that and how it can come across. We could also pretend that *nothing* at all *ever* went wrong on So and continue, but that doesn't solve any problem, either. While I disagree with most of what the blog article said, I *do* think that we can improve how SO is experienced, especially for new users, and that we can be mindful of our language, *especially* when we *suggest on meta* how others write their comments (as this answer does).

Comment: @MarkAmery Depending on the comment before that, I don't get it. Like, at all. What are you trying to say? That you do not trust users to understand from context which error is meant? And please show me any question where there is more then one error, and where there *would* be an ambiguity. I can not think of one. When there are multiple error, you can refer to them without "your", e.g. by saying "The StackOverfloError you seeing is ...[...], while the OutOfmemoryException is [...]" or "the first/second/third error mentioned here". No need for "your error" at all to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: @Polygnome So *"the error you are seeing"* is unproblematic but *"your error"* is somehow insulting? Whatever logic is behind this, I don't see it; to me it's like you're just randomly labelling innocuous phrases as offensive.

Comment: @MarkAmery I am sorry if you do not see the difference. I am not saying you should never use the word "you". Its a possessive pronoun and its clearly needed in language. The question is when to use it. Different ways of saying things have different meaning. "Your code does not compile" and "The code in question does not compile" essentially mean the same thing (in this context), but they evoke different feelings.

Comment: @MarkAmery But since you do not seem to want to acknowledge the fact that this might be so, I do not think its constructive to have a further discussion about it. My *main* point was about the unnecessary snarky side comments (even", "*you* say it does"), and you have not said one thing about it and instead gone bike-shedding on an issue that I feel is slightly relevant (and one should be mindful of when engaging in conversation), but not the *major* point here.

Comment: "Actionable and not judgemental" sums up what I believe we should aim for in comments. Your answer does a good job of emphasising the importance of making them actionable. (That, I'd add, is entirely in line with the "welcomingness drive": it is welcoming to give clear directions to new users so that they don't get even get lost.) As for the sample comments, I find them mostly fine, though the first one feels a bit curt (I'd say Polygnome's rephrasing -- "This code does not compile, therefore I can not reproduce your problem" -- is an improvement in that specific case).

Comment: As a pretty new user myself, I have to agree with duplode in particular and Polygnome as well.  The comments are definitely helpful and if I were to see them, I would try and improve my post to fix whatever the issue brought up was. At the same time, I know that some of those comments would make me feel defensive. I'm not going to try and argue why this is, because other users probably understand it better than me, but I do know that the difference in the wording of the comments you give and those Polygnome gives definitely elicits different initial emotional responses on my part.

Comment: Well, I appreciate that data point, then @Chris - it tells me that at least Polygnome's intuitions are correctly grasping *something* that mine aren't about the emotional response some readers will have to these comments.

Comment: @TylerH, "*I downvoted you*" is the worst phrase in this answer and its comment chain. It communicates that downvotes are personal. The user is affected by the action, but the object of the verb *downvote* should always be the post.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree; it was an oversight that I didn't catch until after it was too late to edit the comment. At any rate, it's easy to substitute "your post" for "you" here; best not to let it distract from the bigger problems.

Answer (score 3):

As much as I love Stack Overflow, sometimes I find "helpful" suggestions to be (unintentionally?) judgmental.  Maybe the person posting doesn't know HOW to get the code to compile and that's part of the problem.  Maybe his/her first language isn't English, or they're a beginning CS student and don't even understand the problem well enough yet to know what the problem is.  Remember your first days?

I see a lot of corrective hints/answers/downvotes/comments that in reality are just subjective judgement calls and I don't know think that they're much help.  In this particular case, if the code sample isn't that complex, maybe it'd be more helpful to point out where the compilation error is.

Comment: your inference of malicious intent is more your problem than any one else's if the comment is not empirically abusive it reflects your thinking 100% not the commentor's, think about that before you are *judgmental* about others intent.

Answer (score -6):

Downvoting when you're clearly aware the asker may need assistance crafting a compliant question feels terrible to a new user. I understand bad questions need to be downvoted for the site to work, but in terms of tone, it's not a great experience, particularly if you're not sticking around to help improve the question and then removing your downvote. To a new user, each small amount of rep matters, and driveby downvoting (even with a comment they may find difficult to implement due to language/skill level) essentially says "You suck, and I'm not going to help you, but I am going to take the small measure of value you do have on the site."

NB **I am not at all against downvoting bad questions/answers**. But from the perspective of the new user experience, it's far better receive assistance with question crafting than a bunch of demoralising downvotes. My preference is to flag for closure rather than downvoting, or to give the asker some time to improve the question (preferably after commenting/with assistance), before downvoting.

Comment: I like the idea of flagging for closure instead of downvoting. That never occurred to me as a friendlier option.

Comment: This is paradoxical; you're aware that downvoting is necessary for the site to work, yet you actively *avoid* taking that necessary step in moderation?

Comment: That's not quite what I said. I said I prefer flagging (which will remove poor questions without unhelpful-to-the-newbie downvotes), or at least giving the new user _some time to improve the question (preferably after commenting/with assistance), before downvoting_ - **because receiving lots of downvotes without active assistance is a terrible new user experience**.

Comment: the preconception that down votes are unhelpful to *newbies* is flawed as well. they are helpful to *newbies* that see them and then think *wow, I need to make sure I do not ask low quality questions like this one* and they are the only approved form of feedback to the OP that carries no chance of being *unwelcoming* in the comments. **Vote, Move On** is how the site works now, you acknowledge this yourself, stop supporting the idea that infers malicious intent to someone clicking an arrow on a website, and start teaching the *newbies* what the arrows actually represent.

Comment: I'll assume that with the downvotes and teaching the newbie what they represent, you are taking the time to grapple with both the newbie's difficulty composing a good question, and their actual question/problem. In which case I say ABSOLUTELY! However (having been there) a bunch of downvotes when you felt you asked a decent question DOES feel unwelcoming, however aware a newbie might be as to the meaning of the completely welcoming -10 their question received seconds after being asked. The DVs may be helpful if "-10" is what they're looking for, but I bet few think "wow, I need to...