Suspended for posting a comment disparaging of Discussions
I posted this comment on one of the many Meta questions asked about Discussions:

It's discussions. Nobody cares. Please stop posting questions about it, so that it can die faster.

and shortly later was notified that my account had been suspended for a week, with the reasoning being:

You've voiced your displeasure at Discussions. We get it it. It's frustrating for us all. The rampant cynicism on Meta about it, however, is getting old. Telling people to not post about it isn't helpful in the least.
Your recent interactions cross a line and need to stop because they affect others negatively. We take the Code of Conduct very seriously and encourage you to take a moment now to review it, as further violations will result in increasingly longer suspensions being applied to your profile.

I would like the responsible moderator to publicly explain exactly how this comment of mine is a violation of the CoC.

The two quoted paragraphs at the end belong to the same message? Are the entirety of the message? Could the message be referring to any other action you've taken recently? You are not precisely new to the "suspension corner", so without more information, it wouldn't be a stretch to imagine that some other caustic comment elsewhere was the cause.

That's all I got @yivi.

Is this the only time you voiced your displeasure with discussions? Discussions are currently a feature of Stack Overflow (no matter if we like it or not), and as such questions about it are on-topic on meta. Telling people that they shouldn't post here is certainly not optimal.

"Not optimal" is not a CoC violation, last time I checked.

Let's phrase it differently: I would say that telling someone who is interested in discussions that "Nobody cares. Please stop posting questions", is not treating them with kindness and respect. Which is explicitly asked for by the CoC.

I guess telling people to stop posting about stuff is crossing a line, meta is the one place you should post about such things and we have no right to tell others to stop posting stuff we don't like to read about. Don't read instead. Still, kind of shocking it is moderated this heavily. Which... may be the point.

"... explain exactly how this comment of mine is a violation of the CoC.". You're implying that the single comment alone is a violation of the CoC. However, the mod message explicitly says "... rampant cynicism", which indicates that the cause of the suspension is due to a pattern rather than a single comment.

While I don't like the comment, I don't think it's suspension worthy. Seems a bit heavy-handed to me. And being perennially cynical and a bit annoying, shouldn't be a suspension reason; at least not a week-long suspension, IMO. However, there could be more than what we are seeing at the moment.

@cigien "rampant cynicism" is, again, not a violation of the CoC.

I continue to find moderators here entirely fair, and I've had my fair share of tellings off. I wonder Ian if your tone may be the problem; it is often unkind, or judgemental, and at some point it is going to push someone's buttons. The comment here is hardly a beacon of kindness, but had you posted that with a history of otherwise gentle behaviour, I don't think you'd have received a ban. I'd suggest just letting it go.

@halfer What, exactly, is "unkind" about that comment? Or are you mistaking terseness and directness for unkindness?

I wonder Ian if you are mistaking unkindness for directness.

Example from your comments: "You are part of the problem, and until or unless you accept that we cannot have constructive dialogue".

Another one: "Someone who isn't a raging moron?"

Another one: "And unsolicited, unsourced, untrustworthy, unhelpful speculation like yours".

Another one: "You're missing the forest for the trees with that pedantry".

Another one: "You couldn't be more wrong if you tried".

Another one: "Did you completely ignore the last sentence of my answer?"

Another one: "Please don't play pedantry".

Most of those comments are suspension-worthy or very close to; particularly when taken in aggregate. Maybe the particular example shown in this question wasn't... but all in all, maybe taking it on the chin and moving on might be for the best.

@halfer Were those comments posted recently? Because bad as they are, they would only be relevant if they came before this last suspension, right?

Being cynical isn't a CoC violation. Neither is being happy, angry, sad or mischievous... That said, the way your emotion or mental state affects your communication, does seem to have led to CoC violations. You're free to disagree with people, but telling people "Nobody cares. Please stop posting questions about it" isn't constructive. If you feel that way, downvote and move on.

@Cerbrus but there are no downvotes in Discussions...

Well, then just move on.

@VLAZ the comment was posted under a question on meta regarding "Discussions", not on under a "Discussions" post.

Out of city, do you think that it's likely that SE will agree with you here?

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine They eventually did with documentation, why shouldn't it be the same with discussions?

Suspension feels a bit harsh to me, the Mod could have sent you a personal Msg pointing at that "rampant cynicism" to ask you to refrain from commenting anymore in that way... (... warning you that Suspension would be the next step otherwise...) // Put now the [discussions-space] Tag in your 'Ignored Tags' for 'Meta' and simply ignore Threads about 'Discussions', I would think...

Maybe you deserved to be suspended or maybe not, I dunno, but the questionably applicable boilerplate second paragraph of your quote from the mod message gets my blood up, as the use of vague boilerplate messages to criticise people always does. I don't think this post of yours is especially useful, but I do understand why you, or anyone receiving it, would find that second paragraph offensive. (Closely related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336485/200582. Vaguely related, but regarding critical comments on posts by normal users: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367861/1709587.)

So, all of those comments @halfer quoted are (way) over a year old. They can't possibly be relevant to this suspension.

My assumption would be that the comments the moderator is alluding to are likely deleted, meaning that it could be difficult/impossible for curators to get further examples. There is a deleted comment that swore, posted about a month ago, but that's all I can find with the tools I have access to.

@ThomA How are you able to find deleted comments at all

There are/were archives, @Starship . There was a Chat Archive for comments, but that's dead due to [so]'s "choices", but they are now archived in Discord.


explain exactly how this comment of mine is a violation of the CoC

Well I'm not the responsible moderator, or a moderator at all, but being upset that someone posted a question about something that is, whether you like it or not (and I don't like it either), a feature of this site, in the location that they are supposed to post about it, is unreasonable. The user did nothing wrong. What do you expect the user to do here?
As for the Code of Conduct, it expects you to treat users with "kindness and respect". Attacking someone and telling them "Nobody cares. Please stop posting questions", not because they did anything wrong but simply because you dislike a feature they had nothing to do with, is neither kind nor respectful.
I'd also like to note that I seriously doubt that ignoring a feature will cause it to be removed. Asking for it to be removed (that's already been done, don't go make a post about that) is a much better idea (and upvoting that request) if you actually want it to go away.
Also, the mod message mentioned "rampant cynicism", which certainly implies that you have a pattern of bad comments. Halfer has compiled some of your comments and I've added 1 to the list as well, and I seriously doubt that they were not also part of the reason you were suspended. In case/for when they get deleted from the comments, here they are. I'm pretty sure just about every single one is not kind and respectful (1 or 2 of them could potentially be okay in the right context, but in most contexts still not okay):

You are part of the problem, and until or unless you accept that we cannot have constructive dialogue


Someone who isn't a raging moron?


And unsolicited, unsourced, untrustworthy, unhelpful speculation like yours


You're missing the forest for the trees with that pedantry


You couldn't be more wrong if you tried


Did you completely ignore the last sentence of my answer?


Please don't play pedantry


Thank you for bringing down the overall quality of the site by rewarding bad questions with answers, ensuring that the users who ask those questions have zero incentive to write good questions, thus setting them up for future failure. It's almost like the people who came up with the quality guidelines thought about this more than you evidently have.

This is pretty large fraction of your (undeleted) comments, and frankly I'd say many of your comments that I decided not to include in this list were also borderline.

Most of that goes into inflammatory territory though, it would be strange to moderate a bit of cynicism instead of all that. Out of context of course, it's a little unfair to only post those comments and not what the comments are responding too. A lot of that read like the end station of an already toxic discussion where multiple parties are involved.

@Gimby Well I admittedly don't have access to the full conversations, but honestly outside of 1-2 of these comments, there is no context that would justify them. And my guess is that this comment was the final straw.

Do you have any idea when or where were these quoted comments posted? Because without that, offering them as some sort of "smoking gun" evidence for a suspension is a wild guess at best, or simply an unfair pile on. These comments could be older and already been dealt by a former suspension, or they could be newer and then completely unrelated to this specific suspension. While piling on is fun and all, I'd prefer we'd left the answer box for users with actual information about the situation. They usually have a diamond besides their usernames.

@yivi There is no requirement that only diamonds answer. And frankly I'd say that a user with a history of rude comments probably has a lower threshold for being suspended a second time if they have a history of committing the offense then a first time offender. Also, ask halfer, they will probably know. I just copied the comments they said were posted.

Frankly, I find it unfair to provide something like this that you didn't even source yourself, that you know nothing of the context (or even veracity, because as much as I like halfer, they are your only source for this). If you do not know where these comments come from, providing as an answer is little more than uninformed piling on. I don't like how Ian behaves a lot of the time, but posting a question about his suspension is valid. If you are going to bother replying, use facts you can vouch for to inform your opinion.

@yivi FYI those comments of Ian's are still up. their IDs are 979521, 962782, 960279, 940410, 921593, 881073, 867943 if you want to find them. even if they get removed, you could probably find them again later in the comment archive

@starball Can't seem to find them in either the comment archive chat or discord. How does one search for a comment by ID.

@Starship https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/ID_GOES_HERE. So that's 979521, 962782, 960279, 940410, 921593, 881073, 867943 (copied from starball's comment without individually checking).

Starship and @yivi, the comments were sourced from the OP's public Meta profile.

@RyanM Would you mind checking those comments over seeing if you think any should be deleted?

@Starship You apparently can't search for comment IDs. They're awkwardly shoehorned into the link (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432163/suspended-for-posting-a-comment-disparaging-of-discussions/432165#comment1011047_432165; the comment ID is 1011047, but because it's within the URL in the way it is, it can't be searched). SE chat allows search by question or answer ID, but Discord apparently doesn't. Will shoehorn in IDs, but this won't help with existing comments. Checking the dates though, all those comments are prior to SE killing the comment archive, so (1/2)

they should be in the chat.SO archive, and as long as the /posts/comments/{comment ID} links works with deleted comments, you should be able to extract the post ID from there and search by post ID for any deleted comments

Regardless, just putting some random comments which someone else collected and placed out of context in a nice visible list makes a person look a lot worse than necessary. I consider this answer, or the train of comments it was copied from, to be dangerously close to breaking the CoC in my honest opinion. Don't fight fire with fire.

@Starship a request to check comments over and see if any should be deleted would be a good use for a custom moderator flag, as it's a case where the request can be done by any moderator, not just a specific one.  (that said, I'll go ahead and raise such a flag myself, as some definitely should be deleted, but it requires a bit of looking at context to judge how to handle them, exactly).
