# Can't delete the question. Can't fix the question. What are my options here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvote-reason

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814637/can-i-build-a-linux-path-in-java-running-on-windows-without-hard-coding) recently which attracted two answers, and also two downvotes.

The downvoters (as seems to be customary) made no comments on their reasons.  So presumably whatever made it a bad question (I have no idea) is still there, with the potential to attract more downvotes in the future.

And it appears there's nothing I can do about it.

- I can't delete the question, because it has two answers (both of which showed effort, but to be honest, didn't answer the question).
- I can't fix whatever's wrong with the question because I don't know what's wrong with it, and the downvoters didn't comment.

This seems an odd state of affairs.

Should there be an exception to the "no delete after 2+ answers" rule for, say, questions that have downvotes and no upvotes?

Or at least, is there someone who can enlighten me as to what was wrong with the question?

Comment: You can always file a disassociation request, if it bugs you too much.

Comment: There is always the option to *shrug* and move on ....

Comment: @rene, well, yes, in every area of life, from SO questions to separated families at the border, one does indeed always have the option to shrug and move on.  *sigh*

Comment: Two downvotes can just be random. There might just be nothing wrong with the question, and no increased chance of future downvotes. I wouldn't worry about future votes until they happen.

Comment: 'downvoters (as seems to be customary) made no comments' it's not a custom, it's recommended and prudent.   I don't know what the problem/s are with the question - I don't have skills in that area, so would not vote either way.

Comment: @MartinJames [citation needed]

Comment: @RyanLundy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/758133

Comment: @RyanLundy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/1426539

Comment: title of the question looks rather poor, see eg [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260) I'd use something like "Paths.get produces Windows style path when Linux style is needed". Research also [seems missing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/839601), I'd expect a note like "checked Paths.get javadoc and <...>". Somewhat minor but note of hard-coding workaround being ugly would look more compelling if you provided its code

Comment: ...an option worth considering is to find a duplicate, close it (as asker with > 15 rep you can do this [single-handedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773)) and cast a delete vote two days later (rep over 10K lets you do this). If there is no dupe then question looks very worth keeping to me (preferably edited to address issues mentioned in my prior comment), and you simply should ignore downvotes

Comment: "but is there a more elegant way?" - Woof, elegant is a word that should never be used in a question, you're asking (mostly) programmers here, every solution is elegant to someone. You want to know if there is a way to do it using the standard API, I think. So just ask that.

Comment: @Gimby, I'm working in a Java shop after many years of C#, so the thought "There must be a more elegant way to do XYZ" occurs to me often.  I only wish there more often _were_ such a way.

Comment: I should ask Jon Skeet.  I bet he knows how to write Java that looks as good as C#.

Comment: 1) I agree with @Gimby that "is there a more elegant way?" makes it sound like you're asking for opinions. 2) The comments you made on the answer sound like they would make good additions to the question.

Comment: I'll be honest; I still don't get what's wrong with "Is there a more elegant way?"  The point is that hard-coding works, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve hard-coding.  Anything would be more elegant than hard-coding.  I would hope, @Gimby, that there isn't any programmer to whom hard-coding the path is an elegant solution.