# Unsatisfied with partial serial downvote reversal

Tags: discussion, moderation, serial-voting

I don't understand the rationale behind a partial reversal of serial downvoting of my posts.  All of the 7:07 posts were reversed, but the 7:08 was not.  For me, this is clearly part of the same abuse.

[image]

When I asked for clarification, I received:

> declined - we don't control the whys of voting reversal, nor why the community team decides what to reverse. It's out of our hands.

So the "hands" have no accountability and don't need to justify their actions?  This doesn't seem like good governance to me.  I don't think I am out of line in challenging this decision.  The 7:08 post was the only one with a negative vote tally, but this was solely because of no-comment revenge voting and on multiple occasions, one of a string of downvote attacks.

I don't personally care about the loss of a couple of points, but unmerited downvotes on posts DOES hurt this site/community.  I would like it if moderators would protect my questions from being used as pincushions when other users don't like ME.  It feels like bias is being factored in despite the clear evidence of serial voting withing 60 seconds.

p.s. I would like a mechanism to be put in place whereby after a downvote on a specific post has been rolled back, then the abusing user was unable to re-inflict the downvote.  ...because this has happened in the past.  In fact one time, a series of downvotes were reversed, then the user came back with a friend and placed 2 downvotes on just one of posts earlier downvoted. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WheUv.jpg I have a feeling this cannot be done and that I am not the first person to have this notion because if it was possible, it probably would have already been enabled.

Comment: I've seen the reversal script _"hanging"_ another single DV several times. The DV might have been placed not by the same user, or whatever. You cannot know.

Comment: I didn't get the feeling that this was a reversal conducted by a bot, but rather by a human because it came days later after I flagged.

Comment: There are some individuals who seem to grasp the serial voting detection, and trick the system in a way. If you have a certain feeling such thing happens with a articular user in former disclosed contact with you, feel free to flag for mod attention.

Comment: The `7:08` downvote came on a post that already had 5 downvotes. (And four upvotes) I don't think it's fair to lump this with all the other serial downvotes.

Comment: This is the "snowball" effect.  It is an obscurely titled post so people are not likely to be "stumbling" upon it.  And when they do, it is my opinion that there is nothing downvote worthy about the question (if there was I would like a comment from ANY of the downvoters so that I could improve the question)  You will notice that there are no downs on my answer (because that would cost the downvoters rep points).  When users don't like me, they pile on that post (and others).

Comment: For a bit of context, I hadn't received a downvote for 2 months since these.

Comment: I didn't handle this one, but your flag wasn't asking to have the votes reversed, it was "Please explain why only 3 of the 4 serial downvotes were reversed". We're not able to answer that, as we're not privy to that information. If you *actually* wanted a mod to look into having the last vote reversed, why not say that?

Comment: This was the second flag that I raised.  The first flag asked for removal. I thought wishing the 4th flag to be removed would have been inferred and I did actually want to understand the workings.  @Rob are you saying that this was handled by software? or by humans?

Comment: @mickmackusa Which was marked helpful, with the response to wait for 36 hours to see if the automated script fixed it. If not, then re-flag and request reversal.

Comment: @mickmackusa This was handled automatically

Comment: @mickmackusa: mind if I ask you, how many questions have you posted on meta?

Comment: I worry that this is a baiting question, @Hovercraft because my profile shows just one other post on meta.

Comment: But also on meta down-voting 1) does not affect your reputation and 2) often has a different meaning, and can be often used to simply signify that the voter disagrees with the poster's premise. I'm more taken aback about your being upset with the voting here than with the voting itself. There. I engaged when I tried not to.

Comment: No, nothing baiting about this, but you appear to not fully understand meta voting and appear to be taking things *far* too personal.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was not complaining about downvotes on THIS question, but rather my SO question "in question".  Yes, I realize that meta downvotes don't have any impact on my account.

Comment: Ah, then surely you're aware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention. If the voting goes either way, you have only one person to blame -- yourself.

Comment: @GBlodgett So should my new voting philosophy be "never comment with a downvote"?  That doesn't seem like Good StackOverflow Citizenship to me.  I am trying to do the right thing for the site when I explain my downvotes.

Comment: @mickmackusa https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/8534008

Comment: @GBlodgett well, I guess I fundamentally disagree there.  The comments that I leave offer feedback that prompts the poster to edit/delete their content and if they don't, it explains to future researchers what is "bad/ill-advised" about the post.  These mission critical messages improve the site and prevent the echoing of bad content by the poster/readers in the future.

Comment: @mickmackusa Then I fully agree with you commenting with your downvote. I was simply saying many users choose to not comment for the reasons mentioned in the article, and to avoid a user taking their anger out on them simply because their comment gave a face to the downvotes

Comment: @mickmackusa If you have good experiences with your DV comments then by all means keep doing it. Just don't expect everyone else to, because many of us have had the exact opposite experience including getting "feedback" through other publicily visible communication channels.

Comment: Do be careful with the comments you post on other people's answers.  Being so critical of their contributions does inspire them to have a look at yours.

Comment: If only their criticisms were insightful.  The no comment downvotes tell me nothing of value.

Comment: (I guess I'll clarify that I received an additional downvote on my SO question since posting this meta question, I then comment that it occurred, then Hover said "Must.Not.Engage.".  I thought he was giving me advice to not give the new downvoter "the satisfaction", so I deleted my comment.  Turns out, he was only speaking to himself.)

Comment: " You couldn't have read the question in that amount of time. " I've heard this accusation many times... Yes some people can in fact read that entire post in under 60 seconds, or in that time at least read enough to know that the rest isn't worth reading because the post is not useful.

Comment: I have to assume that the downvoters on this question are swiftly placing it in the "oh boy, here's another whingey post about not getting what is expected". Imagine for a second that I am one of the volunteers that is trying to help this place before I become jaded/burned out like so many before me.  I am only seeking a little bit of justice/decency/clarity when I feel it is due.  Do I just delete this question now?  Is this the take away?

Comment: Ask him, not me

Answer (score 14):

> For me, this is clearly part of the same abuse.

But you aren't the one that matters. The serial voting detection and reversal script is what matters.

You cannot see who cast those votes or the ones that were reversed. Therefore, your statement is an *assumption*, not a *fact*.

The serial voting script *can* see who voted. It *knows* whether those four votes were cast by the same person as the ones which were reversed.

It is at least theoretically possible that you were hit with two independent sets of serial voting at nearly the same time. It is also possible that there were two parties who colluded in their serial voting of you, but one of them didn't trigger the serial voting script for whatever reason. Or maybe... it just hasn't gotten around to it yet.

You do not have enough information to be able to rule those possibilities out.

> I would like it if moderators would protect my questions from being used as pincushions when other users don't like ME.

Well, they don't. They *can't*. Elected moderators cannot see who voted for what; only actual SO employees can do that. They're the ones who wrote the serial voting script.

Elected moderators should not be able to deanonymize voting. They're trusted, but they shouldn't be trusted *that much*.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful answer.  I didn't realize that the serial voting script _can_ see the voters.  I thought everyone and everything was in the dark.

Comment: Just to expand on this answer, the script isn't fool proof... and is by design pretty strict on what it'll reverse so as to not reverse legitimate votes. If you believe targeted votes were not fully reversed (whether up or down), feel free to flag it and ask for further investigation. Unless the flag is completely baseless, we'll forward it onto the CMs to take a closer look. In this case, I've forwarded this on for you, @mickmackusa. But in the future, please be a bit more specific with your flags as to what you'd like us to do.

Comment: I agree in principle with this, but votes not getting caught by the script is by no means a surefire way to tell they're not serial. Sometimes the script partially reverts, too.

Comment: @Magisch yes, I 've seen this too. I've had downvote-reversals and, a couple times, there is a small group 2/3 that is not reversed.  Imma guessing they are from a different account than the rest of the reversed votes, but the other factors, timing etc, overwhelmingly point to the little group also being fraudulent.  If you have socks, or voting-ring accomplices, serial voting is much easier:(

Comment: @Nicol So what do I do now that I have received an overwhelming lack of support/agreement from the meta community? Am I to trash this page? You have nailed the focus of my concern -- I was concerned that the reversal judgment was human-controlled and potentially held some kind of bias against a particular post, but now I know it was not. Is it an insult to you for me to delete? I think so, but I want to check first.