# What's wrong with this comment?

Tags: discussion, bug

StackOverflow's policing of my comments is really getting on my nerves.

Could someone explain why this comment is banned?

[image]

Comment: You aren't supposed to be using +1/-1 in comments any more. Just remove that.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: We're not supposed to tell people why we downvoted...?

Comment: You can say why, but the theory is that people include the -1 and get revenge downvotes without realizing that revealing your vote is usually a bad idea. The filter is to protect against that (among other things)

Comment: @Mehrdad You can get around it if you really want to. For example just say *"-1"* at the end.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Revenge downvotes? So it's supposed to *protect **me***?

Comment: Yep, something like that. Read the post in the answer.

Comment: The idea is: comment about the post, not the vote. Good impetus, weird choice of implementation.

Comment: You might want to also consider not bothering to leave a comment on a two-year-old answer to a closed question. There's a longer explanation that'll pop up if you hit this while *posting* the comment, but apparently not when editing.

Comment: @Shog9: Uhm, the reason I left that comment was that I was exactly looking for the answer to that question and the answer specifically did **NOT** answer my question. It shouldn't have even been closed. I can't find the answer to my question anywhere now either, because if I post a new one it'll get closed as a duplicate of the question that didn't actually get answered.

Comment: So explain **how/why** it doesn't answer your question then. If you don't do that, what's the author supposed to do - *guess?* Or just post a new question, since apparently it *did* suffice for the author of that particular question. I deleted the question, so no one's going to be using it as a dup target.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Thanks for the info. This must be one of the stupidest things I've seen the SO team implement... I really don't care if someone goes and revenge downvotes me.

Comment: @Shog9: If the problem is the leading -1 then I don't see how redundantly explaining the how/why would help...? I'd still get the same error.

Comment: The problem is that your entire comment was worthless. -1 triggered the block, but that's a symptom not the root problem here. If you'd included enough information in your comment to make it worthwhile, then -1 wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: @Shog9: Well then pretend I explain the reason afterwards? Now is it useful?

Comment: Why pretend? Just do it.

Comment: @Shog9 because you just deleted the question?

Comment: I deleted it because you were afraid to ask your own question. Now you don't have to worry about it being seen as a duplicate, so... just go do it.

Comment: @Shog9 actually no a comment that says somebody doesn't answer the question, is not worthless at all. Sometimes they know they didn't answer it and they think it didn't matter and so such a comment indicates to them that it does matter. And sometimes they read the question again and see they didn't answer it

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of those contexts @barlop, and in fact wrote several canned comments for such situations that are available in review, 3rd-party scripts, etc. The critical factor here is that a comment should strive to *convey information*, not express an emotion; we don't have Slack's / GitHub's "reactions".

Comment: @Shog9 Then you agree that a comment saying `-1 you haven't answered the question` isn't necessarily insufficient information and even is very often sufficient information. So when you said here that his comment in question had insufficient information perhaps you should've added some context as to why?

Comment: no, I think it explains nothing @barlop. If the author already knew they weren't answering the question, then you've told them nothing; if they didn't, then you've still told them nothing.

Comment: @Shog9: if they didn't already know then you've told them they should re-read the question in case they missed something or can answer it directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your comment was affected by the filter described in this post:

[Should we discourage leading +/-1 on comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments)