# Suggestion for when content is programmatically blocked by content filters

Tags: feature-request

I recently tried to post a comment, and I had 
[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284796/289296) happen to me. I was very confused by the message.

Minimum Suggestion: In the red-block popup, link to the current policies page. Hopefully there's a "most recent changes" entry that will show that +1/-1 is no longer allowed.

Bigger Suggestion: Since it's already been detected, put what was detected in the red-block popup so that it says something like

```
Comments can't contain that content: "+1"
Please see the current comment guidelines at [link].
```

I don't really care what the policy is, it would just be nice to know what rule the content filter is trying to uphold.

Comment: Were you posting a comment or editing one? The longer explanation appears when you try to post, but looks like it gets shortened when you're editing.

Comment: As you might have noticed, this feature isn't very smart.  Not nearly smart enough to give you a specific message like this.  The SE community leads just type in a regex string and if your comment matches it you get the "we don't like emails" box.  Well, I suppose they could show the regex on a programmer's site :)  But they won't, the policy here is to stop emails with complaints so telling programmers how to work around it is unproductive.  Likewise, telling users to stop complaining in the help center is never going to happen.  This will be [status-ignored].