# Invisible character is taken as valid in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

We need at least 15 characters to post a comment, blank spaces and   (alt+255) are not counted and Stack Overflow doesn't let you post your comment if it ends with a sequence of these characters. Well, shouldn't Stack Overflow block­ `alt+0173` too? I've tried to post a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926909/batch-file-to-rename-files-based-on-a-part-of-their-parent-folder-name#comment49890743_30926909) that shows only "Yes" and it works fine.

Comment: How about you just don't do that, so we won't have to warn you about abusing the system, and we'll call it quits. We can put all sorts of blocks in place, but that'd be a waste of developer time if there are but few people that abuse such things. Moderators can deal with those few people instead.

Comment: S​t​o​p ​t​hat.

Comment: ^ Which is to say, there's all sorts of ways to reach the character limit with invisible characters, and not all of them can be considered really. People will just find new funky characters. It's a cat and mouse game to some extent, and it's not a very big deal in the grant scheme of things... ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone wants to post a short comment, it is meaningless to block all invisible characters. Even if these characters are all blocked they can still find a way to post their comment. For example:

> Comment. (Meaningless sentence to bypass character limit)

Or, like I shamelessly did on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15610/peaks-valleys-and-slopes#comment48455_15610):

> Waves?.........

I can also imagine people in Math.SE or Physics.SE doing something like:

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$

There are always many ways to circumvent filters and blocks. Hence, it is not practical (and essentially useless) to create such a filter. On the other hand, we already have flags that handle comments which are not constructive, obsolete or too chatty.

I might be going off a tangent here, but in fact I think at times such short comments may be useful. For example, when you ask a question and someone asks for clarification in the comments. Consider this hypothetical dialog:

> ace: Which version of Perl are you using?
>
> OP: @ace Perl 6.

Here the OP's comment is only 12 characters long and hence will not be accepted by the system. Of course, such a comment will be obsolete very soon (right after the information is edited into the question). However, I still believe it is a nice way of notifying the commentator. And in order to do that, the OP must use some workaround.

See also [the +1/-1 comment filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/3488231), in which you can work around the filter simply by moving the "+1"/"-1" to the end of the comment.