# Comments cannot contain that content: Don't comment on your downvote

Tags: discussion

[image]

Please put aside whether or not my comment was actually useful, but `-1` is a number that comes up a lot when programming. I should be allowed to talk about it without the system assuming I'm talking about downvotes.

Also, was this put into place in the last 3 hours? The previous commenter mentioned `-1` too.

Comment: This was put in place a year ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments  There are work arounds for the `-1`

Comment: Comments can't *start* with +1/-1...other than that I think they are fine.

Comment: This has been in effect for a while now, and it only affects comments that are short and start with +/-1 in several forms.

Comment: You can't start a comment with `-1` because the vast majority of those were explaining a downvote. You can have it elsewhere in your comment.

Comment: Can the tooltip be clarified then? There's no way I can be expected to know *where* in my comment that's not allowed.

Comment: Then people would just go "I gave -1 because...", defeating the purpose of the filter altogether. But *that's* why I think having a filter is stupid.

Comment: Hmm, I do feel this is pretty strong reason to make this `-1` block a little smarter .   I dunno how though

Comment: @BoltClock -  Agreed, it's micro-management really.

Comment: Right... so why is Shog9 making these big changes without talking to the other mods/site-runners? There's a ton of downvotes on his 'question'.

Comment: @Coffee: I mean, how smart can you get? If the purpose of the filter is to shut people up about their votes, why not make it so that you *cannot comment* on posts that you have voted on?

Comment: @mpen: good question.

Comment: @BoltClock - Ha, pretty much.  I propose  an auto pop-up that comes along with `-1` comments that says "Please grow thicker skin, we're online"

Comment: @BoltClock Because people might leave constructive criticism that isn't about their vote at all. Filters like this are impossible to make perfect. If this one is blocking 100 "-1 your question sux" for every good comment like mpen's example, then I think it's performing pretty well.

Comment: @Coffee Updated. I'm not too worried about downvotes on meta though :D Oh crap, should this comment be flagged? I'm talking about downvotes again. But, on a question about downvotes...does that make it appropriate or not?!?! So confused!

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Why not make it so that a single flag causes such comments to be deleted? Like we have with naughty words and the word "accept". You don't see the filter blocking comments containing the word "accept".

Comment: @BoltClock That seems like a pretty fair solution. I don't know if it was considered or not, but it might be that people weren't flagging these enough, and opted to start arguing over downvotes instead.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: And honestly I can't recall the last time I left a comment on a post that I voted on that wasn't connected to my vote somehow.

Comment: @BoltClock I normally don't comment on posts that I downvote, and vice-versa. I'd rather let the comment (or answer) stand in place of a vote, just to avoid the aforementioned voting arguments.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: And how often has that worked on posts that have had at least 1 downvote by someone else?

Comment: @BoltClock It's worked perfectly well for me so far. If you don't initiate discussion about how you voted, I think people are less likely to focus on it.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Lucky you. I've had more than a few opportunities to be someone else's scapegoat.

Comment: Me too. I often comment on downvoted answers pointing out what problems they might have which most of the time ends up looking like I was the one that downvoted the question although I didn’t vote at all.

Comment: I didn't realize the system actively discourages you from explaining why you down-voted. I'm surprised I've never seen this on the multitude of feature-requests asking that a comment explaining a down vote be required.

Comment: Explain the problem with the post all you want, @bsmp. Please! Just don't talk about how you voted. It doesn't end well.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, OK. Got it. On a related note, should I also avoid saying whether I flagged a post? While I don't say how I voted I have left comments saying I left a flag because I wanted the user to be aware that the problem(s) with their post could get it closed.

Comment: @BSMP: *Definitely* avoid saying you flagged the post. That's like telling someone straight to their face you called the cops or told their parents or the teacher on them. (It is my opinion that the "I'm voting to close..." boilerplate in custom close reasons falls under that category as well.)