# Why not solve the thanks a lot problem by prompting the user to upvote the question?

Tags: feature-request, comments

There seem to be a large number of people that worry about things on Stack Overflow, but newbies are going to do what feels normal to them (thanking someone), and there will always be newbies. Why not put a little front end magic on this problem and when you see "Thanks", or "Thx" or other such phrases in a comment, pop a dialog to ask the user to upvote the question or the answer instead, and explain to the user that the way we show thanks on Stack Overflow is with those upvotes?

You might want to skip the check altogether if the character count is above a threshold, etc....

It is instantaneous positive reinforcement that won't be met with TL;DR. You could allow the user to post anyway if they insist and autoflag the comment for moderator review. If you never put thanks in a comment, then it won't trigger for you, and it saves the humans time reviewing comments. Plus it encourages the behavior you want to see.

Comment: Most of the <10 rep guys aren't even able to upvote.

Comment: Too much chance of false positive here for an autoflag, I think. But the prompt is not a bad idea, although I thought that something like that already happened...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, commenting anywhere is a 50 rep privilege.

Comment: @Braiam Not on your own posts.

Comment: One would have to weigh the benefit (less _"Thanks"_ comments) with the cost (RegExp-based popup for everyone). A diamond input indicating how many such comments were flagged and deleted in the past month and how much of a hassle it is to delete them would be useful for the purpose of this suggestion.

Comment: Begging for votes is pretty *gauche*, it annoys lots of SO users.  Doesn't get any better when a machine does it.  Makes it *worse* actually, we don't want to teach new users that begging is okay.  Meh, it is *just* a comment.  I personally don't even flag them.

Comment: _prompting the user to upvote the question_ presumably if the user is saying "thanks" it's on an answer? Did you mean prompt the user to upvote the _answer_?

Comment: It's one thing to not allow "Thanks" in question, do we really need to concern ourselves with people thanking people in the comments - sheesh! Let it be!

Comment: I don't really care about a comment saying thanks, and it's not like I ever saw a thread with 10 "thanks" comment. If the comment don't add value, I don't think it adds noise either way. And if someone thanks me but don't accept the answer or another, I just reply him "accept the answer so people will know that this answer solved your problem". It take what .. 10s of my time ? Even if It'd happen quite some time in  a day this cost nothing.

Comment: Last time I did this, it was... Not popular. In fact, it was literally the least popular thing I've ever done here. Not that that's *necessarily* a reason not to do more of it, but...

Comment: It would also need to detect if the user already did upvote the answer. Silly to prompt them if they already did so. A user with a rep less than ten, presumably commenting on an answer to their own question, could be prompted to accept the answer instead, again, unless they already accepted one. Not saying I agree/disagree with the idea though.

Comment: I saw several cases where the "thanks a lot" also included details about saving someone from despair, alcohol drinking, etc. I also saw one invitation to a pint in a pub. We don't have to automate everything.

Comment: @Braiam: Actually when it comes to decisions affecting users directly, he probably should. Listening to its community is one of SO's main characteristics.

Comment: @Braiam You put PHP in the same list as Trump and Bieber? I am officially offended.

Comment: @IvanSchwarz SE has a history of very rarely listening to its community...

Comment: @Shog9 What did you do that was not popular? It seems that some people know what you're talking about, while I (and maybe others) have no idea. Also, maybe you can say it in the "answer" box.

Comment: @IvanSchwarz https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-repeat-do-not-listen-to-your-users/ yeah... right.

Comment: @anatolyg probably this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277314/792066

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ While it's true that users with <15 rep can't upvote, users with <50 rep can't comment on other people's posts, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @ayhan If a user is replying "Thanks" to their own posts, they need help that's well beyond our means.

Comment: @Brian New users can comment on their own questions, and on answers to their questions. That's what I meant.

Comment: @ayhan Ok, that makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking.

Comment: I rarely see people posting just to say thanks. Usually, it's coupled with something else: "thanks, I was doing...", "thanks, now I get...", "thanks, now I can do...", etc. This won't help with that case, so the number of people purely saying thanks won't drop much because there isn't a lot to begin with.

Comment: Potential false positives: "Thanks, but no thanks." "Thanks for nothing." "Thanks for mutton." "I solved my issue, no thanks to you."

Comment: It's already recommending that as a placeholder - do you think any more noise would solve the problem?

Answer (score 171):

Why not give them some help with some nostalgia :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    clippy.load('Clippy', function(agent) {
        // Do anything with the loaded agent
        agent.show();
        
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            agent.moveTo(100, 0);
        }, 100);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            agent.speak("It seems like you're trying to thank someone for a great answer. Would you like to have help with upvoting?");
        },  500);
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.smore.com/css/clippyjs.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.smore.com/js/clippyjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice try, but this answer could use some explanation.

Comment: Tremendous! I shall use this on every one of my sites from now on

Comment: @Glorfindel: Sometimes saying less is better, especially when there's a working **Run code snippet** button to punctuate the joke perfectly.

Comment: This is fantastic.

Comment: One measly upvote is not enough! I actually worked at Microsoft on the Word team when Clippy and friends came out. :)

Comment: Thank you for this great answer!

Comment: Cool @JeffC. I'm quite happy with clippy-js for cases just like this :-) clippy was annoying as hell in word after the 20.000th question if i want help writing a letter, but now years after the fact he fills with a sort of nostalgia of times long past.

Comment: @FredLarson - Don't you want to upvote the answer instead of leave a thank you comment --- Clippy

Comment: I am not just bookmarking this answer, I also copied it and saved it in my email drafts :D

Comment: This makes me so uncomfortable

Comment: reminds those good old days

Comment: There are 2 clippys on Firefox 50.0.1

Comment: yea, same here on chrome, not sure how to solve that, i didn't delve that deep into the library to see how to solve that :-)

Comment: *some nostalgia* More like flashbacks.  Years later and it still makes me reach for a heavy object to "crush, kill, destroy... the clippy" ;-)

Answer (score 10):

This is a common source of frustration, so I did a bit of research into potentially blocking these comments with a message encouraging the commenter to upvote or accept the answer.

Unfortunately, over half the comments that would match a simple expression (short comment that contains "thanks / thank you") are posted by someone other than the asker - often by the author of the answer themselves as part of a conversation.

For such comments posted by someone other than the author of the post itself, the commenter *already* votes about 62% of the time; for comments expressing gratitude posted by the *asker*, that jumps to 72%.

Given the limitations of the current system, that means a naive implementation of this would stand to annoy a lot more people than it would help... Though I must say, I'm tempted to just turn it on anyway simply to try to reduce comment noise.

But with a bit more work, such a prompt could be far more effective. If it were possible to trigger a message to the author *only* in situations where A) the commenter wasn't an answerer and B) the commenter handn't already voted on the answer, it could be a boon to both frustrated answerers and confused askers *without* becoming an annoyance to others.