# Has "Comments can't contain that content" been re-activated?

Tags: discussion, comments

For the first time ever, I got a "Comments can't contain that content" message.   Having never seen or heard of this filtering before, I was curious learn more about it.  I searched MetaSO and started following "duplicate" and "update" links and arrived at an answer that seemed to say this was a failed experiment that was being rolled back.  And that was a couple years ago.

So, is there a new experiment going on?  Are there new comment guidelines posted somewhere to help us avoid offending this new filter?

Comment: What content were you trying to make it contain?

Comment: I don't recall the original wording precisely.  I was suggesting to the person posing a Windows API question to include the return value of GetLastError in the question.

Comment: there's definitely still some restrictions in place (such as starting with +1 and -1 not being allowed unless it's a substantial comment.) so.... we'd have to know what specifically you were trying to post to really know which one you hit.

Comment: You may have come across a meta question indicating that *a particular word/phrase* is no longer one of the filters being checked, there have certainly been changes (both additions and removals) of content that a comment can not contain.  I've never seen anything indicating that *all* filters were being removed; you should provide a source if that's what you saw.

Comment: I was completely unaware there was a comment filtering system even existed, so I thought it was a brand new thing.  Like I said, this is the first time I'd ever seen or heard of it.  Next time I'll know to snapshot the rejected comment so I can ask a more specific question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy were you using any link shorteners or a LMGTFY type link?  Or did you preface your comment with a +1 or -1?

Comment: +1​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍ odd

Comment: I guess it's a secret.

Comment: @psubsee2003:  No shortening link.  It was a -1 followed by two complete, polite sentences explaining how to improve the question, as I've probably done in scores of other comments over the years.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy you can't have used that format inthe fhe last 3 years. Adding +1 or -1 to the beginning has been banned since Nov 2014. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments/278195

Comment: There is never a good reason to admit that you've downvoted in a comment. It just leads to hurt feelings and drama. The message is meant to remind you of that, although it does a rather poor job of explaining itself. Simply delete the leading "-1" or "I downvoted this because..." and leave a comment consisting strictly of your technical advice/criticism.

Comment: @Cody Gray:  I think "never" is too strong there, but I agree with the general sentiment.  I'd argue that there are occasionally appropriate times to indicate that you downvoted.  "-1" is a very concise way to say so, leaving lots of room for constructive comments and making it obvious to the poster that they can improve their score and rep by addressing the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They weren't re-activated because they were never disabled. There are many things which comments cannot contain. Some are phrases, some are websites.

Some of this content can also be removed with a single flag when it is similar enough to banned content. There is not a list of the exact regex used to ban such content in comments though as it would lead to gaming the bans. As a result, all you are going to find are tidbits of what is banned, such as whathaveyoutried.com or starting a comment with +1 or -1 (in certain circumstances).

If you are receiving the "comments cannot contain that content" message, then perhaps address the specific issue you wish to discuss instead of the broader issue of comment content bans. Some content has been rather abused, or led to abuse, in comments.