# Concern: "-1" filter discourages people from explaining their downvote

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I was recently downvoted without comment and dared to rant about it by asking nobody in particular "-1 for what? Supporting Windows correctly?"

The comment was blocked:

> Comments cannot contain that content.
>
> Don't comment on your downvote. If you think this post can be *improved*, please offer **specific guidance.** See: **[The Comment Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)**.

Given how it is worded, I *think* it was intended to be seen by people commenting on a downvote they *gave*, not *received*. The linked page gives the example of "-1, see previous comments you scallywag!" which also may suggest that the filter was intended to catch unconstructive comments that start with "-1".

A quick experiment suggests any comment starting with "-1" is blocked, and
I'm concerned this might discourage people from leaving a *constructive* comment with their downvote, you know, like "-1 because it doesn't answer the question that was asked".

**Scenario**: SO user is fairly new and writes comment explaining downvote. Comment is blocked. User gives up and decides to downvote without comment in the future. How likely is this scenario? Unsure.

Not sure if this should be "discussion" or "bug".

Comment: Discouraging users from explaining their vote or commenting on somebody else's vote is entirely intentional.

Comment: "Downvoted  because it doesn't answer the question that was asked".

Comment: True, the word "downvoted" is not banned. @HansPassant, [most people seem to think downvoters should explain their vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: Why does one even have to mention -1 or downvoting at all... Just leave a neutral constructive comment. Something like: "The OP asked for X... this seems to be close but does Y instead"... then if you can/want to suggest it, then also maybe... "If you change to using float division instead of integer division you'll get the desired results" (just making that example up for demonstration purposes)

Comment: Many people *say* they want downvoters to explain.  In reality, the vast majority just want to argue with those that do.  Even less actually accept said constructive criticism.  That barrier is status-by-design.

Comment: Any comment about any vote at all is not constructive. A constructive comment would tell the asker how to fix their post, not tell the asker that they downvoted.

Comment: This post shows staggering amount of research about downvotes on SO and I voted appropriately.

Comment: Why do you need to go 'I downvoted this and here's why'.... Why can't you go 'here is an opportunity for improvement I see in this question'?

Comment: 'SO user is fairly new' but by the time they can downvote, they are at least at 125 rep, which means we can assume they know a bit about how the site works... Enough to know how to leave constructive comments...

Comment: You said yourself that you wanted to "*rant*" for it. The system doesn't allow you to do it, of course.

Comment: −1, The main thing that is discouraging people from explaining downvotes is the reaction they get when they do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not)

Comment: This is not a bug. It's a feature.

Comment: I've found that people tend to be a whole lot less receptive to comments stating something along the lines of "I downvoted because" (which is implicit in "-1") versus those that simply asking for clarification in a neutral manner. The former comes across as fairly egotistical and is a "closed" statement - it makes a statement rather than making a request or asking a question, which isn't actionable. It also focuses on what's *wrong*, rather than how to fix it. This is the same reason I think we should ban http://idownvotedbecau.se/ (if we haven't done so yet).

Answer (score 15):

You can write out "I downvoted because X"; you don't *have* to use the shorthand "-1: X".

Furthermore, it's better that way. We really don't want "I downvoted because" to begin with. If you have a problem with the post, explain the problem with the post. That is, instead of "I downvoted because X", just comment "X". Whether you downvoted or not is *irrelevant*; the main point is "X".

In your example case, "-1 because it doesn't answer the question that was asked," becomes "This doesn't answer the question that was asked." Isn't that simpler?

Answer (score -9):

Saying explicitly that you downvoted someone creates the risk of "revenge downvoting" where the person will go around downvoting your other posts. So it could be argued that the "-1" block is good for the protection it offers.

Better to tactfully suggest ways that the answer could be improved, or point out why it doesn't answer the question, etc.

Comment: +1, looks pretty accurate to me :)  The feature is widely despised for its habit of producing false warnings.  The [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments) was the most downvoted meta question for a while, sadly it lost its lead.

Comment: downvoted because there are protections in place against serial voting, and even if there weren't, this shouldn't be a real concern given the positive (possible) outcomes. *p.s.* please don't go around downvoting my posts.